# When should I "Recommend deletion" in Late Answers?

Tags: support, review-queues, late-answers

Some context: On September 5, I was suspended from reviewing for 3 days (long expired) for [a failed audit in Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29749502) [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isJac.png) and later asked about it [in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52968995#52968995), though I still don't really understand what I should have done here.

The answer from that audit, to my eyes, was *an answer* to a question that was too broad. So I flagged the question in a new tab as too broad and pressed "Looks OK" on the answer.

The problem isn't that I was suspended, the problem here is: **I would do it again.**

You see, for Low Quality Answers, there is [very clear guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) that makes sense to me regarding what to delete and what to keep. Based on that this should not be deleted but downvoted, it answers the question (even though it's bad) and is comprehensible.

But can I use those guidelines for Late Answers the same way or is there something else to be aware of in Low Quality Answers specifically? In some way it feels like Late Answers Reviews (from looking at some other reviews, I don't have real data on this) tend to delete Code-only answers more often than Low Quality Answers would.

I did look at the proposed duplicate target [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/8517948), however that question appears to be outdated from the time before Late Answers had that Delete option, and as such doesn't explain when to use that. While since that audit [I'm done/Other action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369037#369037) *was* added to the queue, when to use the "Delete" option still is not really documented anywhere yet.

Some more opinions/bits:

- This is not about the suspension or what caused it, the [other audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29731987) I failed was actually me missing a duplicate answer so that's not really up for debate.
- Yes, I could have spotted that being an audit in many ways (Visiting the question page and scrolling down to see the answer being gone, other quirks of the audit system) but I didn't, looking for audits in my opinion feels like it misses their point.
- The question flag I raised on that question was marked as "helpful" but nothing (I could tell) happened to the question.

Comment: I see you're reviewing an answer that says 'use selenium'. You should drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: @yivi But that doesn't include deletions..

Comment: I'm not sure if the deletions of Answers in that queue is actually intended. I'd expect that the same rules as for Low Quality Answers apply. It makes no sense that posts are getting deleted depending on the queue they're in. It'd would be like saying (for a Question) "If it lands in Triage, it will get closed, but it it lands in First Questions, then your Question is fine".. that can't be right.

Comment: @Scratte The canonical guide should probably be updated to include the guidance, or to at least link to the guidance, of LQP.

Comment: That answer is not better than a link only answer. I agree with the deletion, and I believe you should fine tune your turd-radar so you are not clicking "looks ok" on useless content. The guidance on [the highest voted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287565/1426539) on the linked LQP guidance applies.. "Use Some Library" is not an answer to the question.

Comment: You can spot from the visible comments that this was not an answer, but a conversation opener. The author wanted to lend assistance rather than answer the question. Commendable, but it's still not an answer.

Comment: @yivi Could you elaborate on what part of the linked answer you mean? I see "Sometimes, even though an answer could, theoretically, be a comment, it does answer the question, and that's okay. (Usually that's indicative of a poor question, but that does not usually warrant punishing the answer.)", which I think was the case here? Also as mentioned I've seen the duplicate target and it doesn't mention when to delete in those queues. If that is updated to include the new "Delete" options (or it's said that the LQP guidance applies here) I'll be able to better understand what to do.

Comment: @Gimby I'm not sure whether I could see those comments in the audit but honestly I don't think whether that comment was there or not would change whether the answer is acceptable? Maybe if they're willing to help the OP commenting to ask them to do that as an answer edit would make it more likely for them to improve the answer but the question still stands whether that answer (had that comment not been there; it wasn't posted until 2 hours after the answer) should have been deleted.

Comment: _The question flag I raised on that question was marked as "helpful" but nothing (I could tell) happened to the question._ Meanwhile the question has been closed.

Comment: The duplicate covers your audit with the point *"Is wrong, generally a lousy hack, barely addresses the question, or otherwise well below par: "* and tells you that you should at least consider downvoting and/or commenting that post. You could also consider deleting it, but it should be clear that "Looks ok" is not the correct option for such an answer when reviewed in the Late Answers queue. Stack Overflow is very lenient on what is considered an answer and that post would pass it normally, so an NAA flag wouldn't work, but we expect more from an answer when it is reviewed in the LA queue.

Comment: So if it's "otherwise below par" (does that have any specific requirements or is it mostly subjective?) I should leave a comment or downvote then. The reason I used "Looks OK" was because at the time "I'm done" wasn't an option and I had dealt with the question, that might have saved me (unless commenting still fails an audit automatically?). Is there any practical use to downvoting the answer here though? It might help the Roomba but I'd feel somewhat bad for slapping a downvote on an answer just because the question was garbage...

Comment: That answer is bad as well, independent of the quality of the question.

Comment: @LW001 Thankfully, at least the "'I'm Done' is missing" problem [has been addressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369538) in the meantime.