# What does "incomprehensible" mean?

Tags: support, review-queues, late-answers

The "Late Answers" queue says:

> - Consider leaving a comment when appropriate.
> - Choose Looks OK if the post is fine as-is.
> - Edit the answer if you think you can improve it.
> - Delete answers that do not address the question at all, are link-only, or are
>   incomprehensible.
> - Skip the task if you aren't sure which action to take.

What does "incomprehensible" mean?

I once got review-banned for Looks Ok'ing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29986201). It was understandable, but it wasn't quite correct. But we have the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-the-late-answers-and-first-questions-answers) which says "Recommend Deletion" is only for *irredeemable* answers.

Comment: That seems to be a poor audit. The answer definitely looks ok to me. It's completely wrong, but that requires subject matter expertise to know. I don't think that's supposed to be deleted from this queue anyway.

Comment: Now I'll spend the rest of my night wondering what outcomprehensible would be.

Comment: Justifiably deleted, but yes, it's comprehensible

Comment: If you can comprehend that, maybe you can explain to me what it means? Because I have no idea.

Comment: That answer at least looks comprehensible. [This](https://stackapps.com/questions/306/flack-overstow-generate-spam-from-stack-exchange-posts) one probably doesn't.

Comment: Now can anyone please enlighten me: if a question is asked at Oct 1st 7:36 and answered Oct 1st 7:43 how on earth did that answer end up in _late answers_ review audit?

Comment: @Lundin It was an *audit*. It was never actually in the "Late Answers" queue for legitimate reviewing. If you noticed that the post should never have ended up in the queue, then you'd have already passed the audit, because you are paying attention and noticing details.

Comment: @CodyGray I can comprehend the answer. The author of this answer seems to be saying that the constructor is *named* twice in the code, so it is *called* twice in the code. That is, I think the author has a misconception that "called" is a synonym for "named" in this context. That's somewhat understandable since in colloquial English you can say "he's called John" to mean "his name is John".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a kind of an answer, but to understand that it is nonsense you might need domain knowledge of C++ in this case.

For strange answers like this I would always open up the post to see the context. Then if one has basic C++ knowledge, one can tell that this answer is nonsense in general, and in particular to the answer to a question why two different constructors get called.

If you don't know C++ the correct action here is probably **Skip**. Always skip if you are uncertain, skipping a review is never a bad thing.

If you know C++ then the correct action is delete - the answer doesn't make any sense, doesn't answer the question and cannot be salvaged.

Comment: Notably some meta folk of the "crap hugging" variety thinks that all answers that seem like an attempt to answer a question are worth preserving. This can be argued endlessly, but personally I think that blatantly incorrect answers to beginner-level questions hold no value to any reader and should just be swiftly deleted from the site - not polished and preserved.

Comment: I think... the folk who say this are just trying to explain that a NAA flag will not necessarily be accepted by moderators on such answers (because, as you mention, properly assessing this may require some minimal C++ knowledge, and it's not guaranteed that the moderator who reviews your flag has that knowledge), rather than implying that blatantly incorrect answers to beginner-level questions or other answers which hold no value whatsoever ought to be preserved.

Comment: @Lundin that's not fair. I do believe the NAA flag should be interpreted like that because that is how it is intended by the site designers/owners. I don't agree with it though.

Comment: @CodyGray Except (correct me if I'm wrong) posts don't end up in late answers review by flagging but are placed there automatically by the site. Main things to look for are spam and plagiarism, but also some random new user posting low quality answers to famous questions just for the sake of it - even though their answer adds nothing.

Comment: I am honestly not sure the details of how the review queues work. But I don't understand what that has to do with any of this.