# Is there a place where reviewers share comment templates?

Tags: support

I'm thinking about a default answer for link-only answers (often posted by new users which might appreciate a bit of (good/best) explanation right in the comment).

Comment: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116)

Answer (score 8):

[Yes, there is such a place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136609/274165), although it doesn't currently have any such template. (I might add [my own list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287278/4099598) there too, actually, and it actually does have a link-only template.)

Answer (score 0):

DavidPostill's link is very good.

It would be nice to simply have a place to copy and paste something like:

```
Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation). Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What do I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
```

To look like:

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation). Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What do I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)