# Could reviewers get linked to guidelines / best practices on the review queues pages?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, comments, welcoming, code-of-conduct

I recently got access to review queues on SO (for Triage, First Posts, Late Answers) and have since reviewed around ~100 submissions in Triage and First Posts, each.

When someone called me out on a brief "Please check [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" comment today, which I'd left on a first post after upvoting another person's "we need more information" comment, I thought **it would be helpful if the review queue pages linked to official (help) pages, including examples for "appropriate" comments and edits** for reviewers.

---

#### To recap my experiences as a (new) reviewer so far, for context:

The info box for reviewers at the top of each review queue gives some basic pointers (and actually also got in my way thanks to its placement, but that's another issue), but I still felt somewhat lost when I started reviewing. In fact after reviewing my first post, I skipped the next ten because I felt I didn't know enough about the "day-to-day business" of how it's done. So I did what I usually do in such situations: I looked at how other, presumably more seasoned reviewers handle first posts and then tried to emulate their comments and tone.

(I feel comments are more helpful than just downvotes, and also didn't really downvote until I googled for more help about reviewing as I'd been under the impression *all* downvotes cost reputation.)

I've meanwhile also learned there are *lots* of first posts written by people who seemingly never had a look at any of the How-Tos, or the sidebar with hints when you ask a new question. So I get when many of the comments by reviewers linking to any of the Help pages are brief, so much so they don't include any "Welcome to SO" or similar intros. It made sense to me when I realised having to find and format the same links over and over again to be really repetetive (... I only now discovered [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments) via [Is there a place where reviewers share comment templates?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289455/is-there-a-place-where-reviewers-share-comment-templates)). Previously, I'd admittedly often found these comments somewhat "rude" (in a "not welcoming" sense) but I had had no idea of reviewing and the (frustrating lack of) quality of many first posts.

---

Now with the updated CoC, it could indeed be argued such brief comments, while not *outright unfriendly*, aren't particularly welcoming. But I'm assuming existing reviewers won't all change their habits and wordings overnight – unless, that is, they get called out via comments or flags –, and new reviewers will go on to copy existing reviewers' behaviour.

So, could we please get official resources on (how to do good) reviews/comments, incl. examples, linked directly from the review queues pages? They could be part of the info boxes that can be "folded close", though maybe it'd be better if the resources were always accessible. Something like the comment templates I linked earlier would also help (if they match the current expectations for comments).

Comment: I for one don't see how encouraging someone to read the help center's guidance on how to ask a good question is in conflict with the new Code of Conduct, as long as it's done so in a polite and respectful tone. That documented guidance exists for a reason! Did someone really tell you that this sort of comment is unequivocally bad?

Comment: @SamHanley I think pretty much everybody agrees with you - I think that most of the kerfuffle is because *what* people deem "polite and respectful" is actually very variable.  Culture in America can often interpret brevity as rudeness (which I personally think is hogwash) whereas in other countries it's generally just considered brevity.

Comment: It all boils down to language, and what is required to convey a thought, critique or helpful advise in a way that isn't subject to interpretation or ambiguity, and so the comment conveys the intent of the commentor, and is received with the same intent it was conveyed and not in some other, potentially unintended manner. Is this comment short (not necessarily), but does it accurately convey and it is received in the manner intended? (hopefully so). It all boils down to language, and what is required.

Comment: I don't think anything beyond usual good judgement is necessary. Ideally people who review these soul-sucking queues want to help, which in itself orients how reviewers behave.