# Is it impossible to answer this (good) question?

Tags: discussion

At the moment [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608748/are-there-any-coding-examples-of-a-full-application-in-a-microservice-style) question has 20 upvotes. So I'd consider it valuable.

You may notice that I reviewed one of the answer as "link only". The author of the answer replied in the comments that (roughly) these kind of answers are OK here. And indeed: It is impossible to post the code of a *whole project* (that uses microservices) here.

Does that mean the question is too broad? Or off-topic? Still 20 upvotes ... I can't get my mind around that.

Comment: its a bad question - it shouldn't be. it is too broad and bluefeet has it correct.

Comment: Don't worry about the upvotes on that question. They're falling away rapidly after you asked this question (meta effect).

Comment: *popular* does not mean anything on SO, it should but it just means a bunch of anonymous people clicked something on the screen.

Comment: Since you posted it has a reputation of 9 because of the downvotes :(

Comment: @JaredBurrows, BillWoodger Yeah, the meta effect. This effect makes me sad. On the other hand: Is this question off-topic or is it not? What do you think? And mind you, since my post above the question has received three upvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

17 minutes before you posted this question it was closed using the reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Which is exactly the correct reason to close it.

Comment: Well, indeed I needed some time to write the question.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity's sake: Servy is correct that the *question* is off-topic.

But that **does not mean** that the *answer* should be deleted or flagged as link-only! Answers can, at times, reasonably recommend some "book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource" without being VLQ or NAA, as long as they at least explain what about the linked resource makes it relevant so it's not just a link. I see a lot of reviewers (and flaggers) that don't understand this distinction, even though [it was laid out quite a while ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/4099598).

Comment: It may be the case that such answers are not worthless, but there are good reasons why (book) recomendations do not work:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations/131432#131432

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: That's merely arguing (again) that book recommendation *questions* do not work. I do not disagree, but that is in no possible way relevant to my post.

Comment: I view it more of why the **answers** to those questions do not work, and by extension why answers that simply recommend some "off-site resource" are lacking.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: But that's not how that post argues. It argues that (for example) it's impossible to create a canonical list of good resources. True, but irrelevant: that means a question looking for such a list is close-on-sight, but an answer that recommends *one* good resource in order to address a specific problem is in no sense bad. It's a good recommendation and if it completely answers *the actual question*, there you go, done.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: Similarly, those questions are barred because they lead to lots of spam and opinion-filled answers. An answer that is verifiably not spam and is good-subjective as well does not fit either problem and need not be deleted, even though the question reasonably fits the pattern by attracting potential future problematic answers.

Comment: But what is the _one_ good resource for me may be nearly useless to someone else.  Personally I liked _Why's (poignant) Guide to Ruby_, even though I never got much Ruby out of it.  But another visitor may feel that chunky bacon does not belong in a programming text.  The result for the next user is the same if we are talking a book recommendation or the best CSS tutorial.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: That's what up- and down-votes are for. "This is not useful to me" does not map to "this is not useful to anyone", and it is *only* in the context of a question that you can reasonably talk about The One True Canonical Resource That Will Help Everyone Learn Ruby The Best. That's not in scope here; rather, "here is a good way to understand your particular problem with Ruby blocks; look especially in Chapter whatever-it-was".

Comment: I don't see how "Travis CI uses a microservice architecture." is helpful to anyone, except maybe those trying to understand Travis CI... but I can see your point, I believe, in the other answer on the question.  Thank you for chatting it out.