# What comment should I add to try-this-tool-only answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, quality-improvement

While [try-this-tool-only answers should not be deleted as link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), I would like to add a comment for the user explaining how they can improve their post.

There are two similar subtypes of this kind of answers:

1. Try this tool/library.
2. Use this class/method.

I'm seeking input and discussions from the community to best write it.

These are my thoughts. You can use italic formatting to highlight specific keywords.
Feel free to propose something completely different.

1. > While this library/class/method may help in answering the question, it would be better to include an *example* of how it works with some *explanation*.
2. > While this library/class/method may solve the problem in the question, it would be better to include an *example* and explain *how* it works and *when* to use it.

Comment: Can you post an example of the question and answer that got this?  If you are worried about a meta effect you can just quote the the text of the question and answer instead of linking to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I find [these](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9106506) while reviewing Low Quality Posts.

Comment: Also helpful is a short summary about pros and cons of the tool/library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are the two [auto-comments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) I use for this at present.
They're still being tweaked a bit from time to time.

If the answer *doesn't have enough information* and should therefore be deleted:

> While this tool or library may help answer the question, [you should at least explain why it does so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).

On the other hand, if it's *not* NAA (and I will therefore either be hitting <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> or even <kbd>Edit</kbd>) but it could still use a lot of love before it deserves an upvote, I use this:

> Links to a tool or library should include a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and ideally [also be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).

Here is a generic version which may address every situation:

> While this library may help answer the question, it would be better to include an _example_ of how it is applicable to the problem with some _explanation_ regarding how it works. [Learn more](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605)

I don't generally lump "use this method" answers in, possibly because I just don't see that many.

Comment: When doesn't a try-this-tool-only answer have enough information and should therefore be deleted?

Comment: @Francesco: If it doesn't even say why it's being recommended in the first place. For example, if it just says "[X](//example.com) is great!", that gets deleted. If it says "[Y](//example.net) does <specific thing from question>", that's fine.