# Answer deleted for which I wanted to award a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty, deleted-answers, moderation

I opened a bounty of 500 points to reward an existing answer to [Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1023306/946850). The answer (with 17 upvotes already) has been deleted (by a moderator) during that bounty period, without explanation. Link to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793556/946850.

For context: the question is about solving an obscure problem in a portable way. Existing answers provide a ton of detail. This is great, except *sometimes* it is more appropriate to use a well-reputed library that just solves the problem, instead of understanding 50 years of computer history first. The deleted answer links to that library.

Is this a misplaced click, or is something else going on here? Why are answers with nontrivial upvotes deleted by a moderator without explanantion? Wouldn't a comment ("this answer could be improved by ...") more appropriate?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer seems to be pretty much *only* the library's name plus a link to the library. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302223 Also note that when it went through [LQP](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9642262), 5 of 6 reviewers recommended deletion.

Comment: Ironically, if you hadn't started the bounty and given the question more attention, the answer probably wouldn't have been deleted. Also, you had about 6 days to award the bounty before the answer was deleted. Why didn't you award it then?

Comment: @41686d6564 I'd usually wait and do the same, letting a bounty run its course draws more attention to the question and its answers, which is often what one's interested in

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Thanks for the link. How much time did the reviewers spend skimming over the answer? Three seconds? Five? Did they look at it in the broader context?

Comment: @41686d6564: I tend to keep the bounty open as long as possible so that it attracts views. Are answers with a bounty on them protected from deletion? I'm happy to apply the bounty if the question were undeleted.

Comment: @krlmlr if it's a link-only answer, maybe 250ms.

Comment: @krlmlr No, they're not protected. An answer that has been awarded a bounty could still be deleted and the author would still lose the rep. I was just curious why you didn't award the bounty if you wanted to give it to that specific answer. Your reasoning makes sense though.

Comment: Why don’t you edit the answer so it’s sufficiently useful and informative (e.g instructions on how to use that library, etc), and then flag for moderator attention to be un deleted?

Comment: @yivi: Edited and flagged.

Answer (score 2):

Link-only answers are frowned upon, even if they have attracted 17 upvotes -- likely a sign that the answer helped people.

Link-only answers can be improved by including examples and additional information.

In this particular situation, the bounty attracted the attention of users and reviewers who really dislike link-only answers. Fortunately, the process is reversible: I could edit and flag the answer as suggested by @yivi, and it was restored by a moderator. The bounty is gone.

Lesson learned:

- Helpful answers can be deleted if they don't fit the format of the site (WTF?)
- Bounties attract attention
- Nothing is cast in stone (a good thing!)