# Do we need better safeguards for deleting answers with "enough" upvotes?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, upvotes

An answer with 17 upvotes has been deleted, apparently because it was a link-only answer. See [Answer deleted for which I wanted to award a bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401276/946850) for context.

Still, the answer is very helpful, also for the foreseeable time:

- The link points to a GitHub repo with hundreds of stars
- The answer contains the library name and the name of its author, so even in case of a dead link it would have remained recoverable

Should we postpone deletion in such cases and ask the answerer (or the community) to improve the answer?

Comment: Tell yourself it's useful again when you want to scream at the answer because the link is dead.

Comment: I agree in general. In this particular situation the link points to a GitHub repo with hundreds of stars, and provided enough context to recover from a dead link situation (library name, author of the library, GitHub link). I'm rephrasing the question.

Comment: @krlmlr well, GitHub repo can also disappear, just like [the node.js' left-pad](https://www.theregister.com/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/)....

Comment: Links can die half a billion ways, even ways that don't involve the service doing anything. The owner can make it private or outright delete it. Deletion can be triggered by leaving the platform, or just wishing to migrate it somewhere else to repurpose the account it was originally linked to, renaming and having the relink expire... There's so many ways links can die that links dying isn't a question of if, but when.                                                              Just containing an author and library name doesn't make it recoverable -

Comment: the creator could've also taken it down and DMCA'd all remaining instances of it. Deletion usually comes with a comment telling the answerer that there is a problem, to which the answerer may respond by fixing the issue, or choosing not to. Also, linking to a resource doesn't make it an answer. It being a code project means it can change over time, even to have its documentation removed. If you still don't see the problem, visit a normal forum post that's old some time. Finding potential answers with dead or useless links is painful when you've been stuck on a problem for a while. xkcd.com/979

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was deleted by a moderator, so in this case votes are irrelevant. Nor would I want to limit the ability of mods to delete, since we can always undelete later (protip: fix the answer and mod flag). It should also be noted that this particular answer was 5 years old. I would have voted to delete it myself.

[Trusted Users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) cannot vote to delete answers with a positive score. NAA flags on positive score answers must be reviewed by a moderator.

Comment: Thanks for the context. The question is not about limiting privilege or permission, merely about asking for a grace period in these situations.

Comment: The answer was 5 years old. How much more grace period does it need?

Comment: @krlmlr For the record, that answer had almost been deleted 5 years ago from the LQ review, if only the review was not invalidated due to the OP's edit...

Comment: @krlmlr in this particular case you personally had plenty of time to improve answer before starting bounty... and you have at 20K ability to edit answers just fine... Even one with 1 rep should be able to improve that particular answer - providing summary of a link is a valid edit.