# Question about Eclipse setting OR plugin on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I want to ask if there is either a setting or a plugin that makes Eclipse show me a warning when I have recursion (because it's often unintended, especially for someone like me who doesn't like recursion very much). And as a nice little Stack Overflow user I of course first asked myself the question if this would be on-topic on Stack Overflow or rather on Super User.

The close reason of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616521/how-can-i-connect-to-sqlserver-running-on-virtualbox-from-my-host-macbook) makes me think that that should be on-topic here, but would be ok on Super User, too. On the other hand, the close reason of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059258/getting-eclipse-to-warn-about-performance-bugs) makes me think that this is off-topic here and can only go onto Super User.

So which one is it? Where do I ask questions about programming environments?

Comment: The problem here is less that your question is about a development environment, and more that it's asking about an off-site resource.That is what will make this off-topic

Comment: _The close reason of this question makes me think that that should be on-topic here_ What? The close reason specifying that it's off topic on Stack Overflow and should be asked on Superuser makes you think it's on topic for Stack Overflow? Did you confuse the links?

Comment: No, I didn't confuse the links. It says: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.**" So apparently tools for programming are on-topic.

Comment: @Patrice "off-site resource"? What site do you mean? And if it is indeed a setting, it is included in the program. Or do you mean I should first ask the question about the setting here and if the answer is no, I should ask about the plugin on SU?

Comment: @fabian no, I meant about the plugin here. on SU OR on Stack, Off site resources are off-topic. So the plugin question wouldn't fly on either.

Comment: What does "off-site" mean?

Comment: Anything that isn't on the site, like tutorials, programs, etc.

Comment: Which site? ! ?

Comment: @Fabian you are on Stack Overflow here. Anything NOT hosted on Stack Overflow is an off-site resource. (same with SU)

Comment: Ok, please explain longer, I think I'm missing some context here. What is "hosted" on the site? Just text and a few pictures, right? Or are you not using the word "hosted" in the meaning of servers, but some other way? Are you just saying "anything not on-topic is off-topic"?

Comment: Asking for "please find me a link to another website where I'll find what I want" isn't on topic. going with "I need a plugin to do X" will get you answers that are just links to other sites. Since we aim to be a long lasting repo of knowledge, the value of links (that often go stale) isn't very high for that.

Comment: Hm, ok. Is there any other way I can get an answer to my question then?

Comment: You can try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com if you want a recommendation for a specific plugin, but I'm not that familiar with the site. You will have to check and make sure your question meets their standards.

Comment: And the setting question here first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about tools specifically used by programmers for developing software *are* on-topic for Stack Overflow. That would include IDEs like Eclipse, and plug-ins for those IDEs.

However, Stack Overflow does *not* accept questions that solicit resources. We don't do polls, and we don't do software recommendations. [Questions like that are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

That holds true for most other sites in [the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), including [Super User](https://superuser.com). They don't do resource recommendations, either.

There *is* a Stack Exchange site that does: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). However, they have very strict requirements for the types of recommendation questions that they accept, in order to keep their standards up. You'll have to read their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) first, to make sure that your question would be suitable there before asking it.

Note that there is sometimes an alternative way to phrase questions that will ensure they are on-topic while still getting the answer you want. That is to *describe the problem* you are attempting to solve, and tell us what has been done to solve it, rather than simply dumping a list of requirements. See [this answer for more detailed advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605).

Comment: Here it is: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46762/eclipse-plugin-to-warn-about-recursion I've just assumed that there is no such setting. I went through them all, I may have missed something, but probably not, so I didn't ask for the setting on SO. The `eclipse` tag explicitly mentions plugins, it's probably on-topic there.