# How to answer a question where the answer is really just a link to a software?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I stumbled upon this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562655/display-icons-instead-of-words-in-visual-studio-tool-window-tabs) which asks how to change the appearance of tabs in Visual Studio itself. I answered with a link to a Visual Studio extension that does exactly what the question was asking. I'm not affiliated with the extension, I just happen to use it as well.

However the answer was shortly deleted because it probably is a link-only answer. Ok, I get that, but there is really no way to expand on that answer, is it? How could I have made that answer sustainable?

Answer (score 4):

Another moderator posted a comment on your answer a few minutes ago:

> Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by install/usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, some sample code, screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.