# Question and self answers (not canonical) that start with an off-topic question

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, vote-to-close

I recently wrote a [Q&A on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894585/mcve-test-harness-to-start-real-mode-code-from-legacy-bios-boot-sector). This question and answer pair were not actually intended to be canonical (at least not as a dupe target). [Questions and self answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) are encouraged on Stack Overflow.

What happens when the question is very specific and effectively asks for an external type resource or tutorial, but the self answer is intended to be the resource? Should such questions be closed as off-topic?

When I originally wrote this Q&A I happened to add this to the bottom of the question:

> This would help facilitate creating minimal complete verifiable examples using boilerplate code so that Stack Overflow users wishing to test the code can do so with a limited amount of fuss.

It didn't take long for someone to vote to close. The intent of this particular Q&A was to provide the resource being asked for in the self-answer so that the information can be referenced from other Stack Overflow questions (and answers) in the future. I agree that by itself the question is technically off-topic because:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. 1

**But** I believe the Q&A pair is on topic given the answer that was provided at the same time.

Comment: Related: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/7795130)

Comment: Seems like the easiest thing to do would be to change the end of the question so you're asking how to do it instead of asking for a pre-existing resource.

Comment: The first guidance that is always given for self answers is 'make sure that, even without your answer, the question is high quality and would make sense on the site as a standalone'. Your entire premise seems to be different...

Comment: @BSMP : I considered it, then problem then is that if you ask how to do it, then the question is seen as too broad and it becomes a  potential _write me the code_ question (those usually get downvotes and close votes) because what my question asks doesn't really narrow it down to a specific problem in existing code .I even considered putting in some fake pseudo code as a bad attempt but then thought that would muddy the waters on the type of answer I wanted to provide.

Comment: also, maybe this question will have better reception/less fuss about on retrocomputing.

Comment: I just came across this as a First Post Review https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22514772   I picked up that it was a test review and chose No Action, but in reality I would have though this question was too broad and deserved to be closed, and I'm sure a few people would fail on this review.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> This question and answer pair were not actually intended to be Canonical (at least not as a dupe target).

Why not? Seems like a good plan to me.

As you know even better than me, we get a number of messy "plz halp me 2 write muh bootloader" questions. Rather than closing them all as "unclear", "too broad", or "lacks MCVE", it would be more efficient for us and more helpful to the asker if we marked them as duplicates of a high-quality canonical.

It would also keep one of our top answerers on this subject from burning out too quickly.

> What happens when the question is very specific and effectively asks for an external type resource or tutorial, but the self answer is intended to be the resource? Should such questions be closed as off-topic?

Unfortunately, yes. The *intention* of the asker is not relevant, and neither is the *purpose* of the question. It doesn't matter whether you are self-answering, intending it to be a canonical, or whatever. The question itself still has to meet our guidelines, or it is subject to being closed.

Part of the logic here is just consistency, which is a good approximation of fairness.

The other rationale is exactly why we close "recommendation" questions as off-topic in the first place: because they tend to attract low-quality and spam answers. Your self-answer might be fantastic, but as long as the question is open, more answers can come in, and history tells us to expect these to be low-quality on recommendation-style questions.

But, all is not lost. The content is excellent, and the central core of the question *is* on-topic, as you mentioned. So, the challenge is just writing the question such that it fits within our guidelines.

For typical self-answered questions, this is just a matter of [pretending you are on Jeopardy!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and phrasing it in the form of a question.

For recommendation-style questions, we have a lot of guidance here on Meta already about the right way to ask them. Basically, you ask about what you want to accomplish, rather than asking for a recommendation on how to accomplish what you want to accomplish. [Answers that recommend a tool are completely fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605); the problem is just questions that ask for them. The close reason itself attempts to give specific guidance on how you *should* ask these questions: *"Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* I see this as really just being a special-case of the X-Y problem. You should not decide in advance that what you need is a library, and then go asking for someone to recommend one to you. Instead, you should ask about what you are actually trying to do, giving all the necessary context, details, and constraints. Then, let the experts who answer your question decide what solution is most appropriate.

In this specific case, I can think of a number of ways you could remix the question to ensure it is a good, on-topic question for Stack Overflow. One simple solution would be to present some partially-working code, and ask how to make it comply with the requirements. But that risks making the question too specific, and it is probably an unnecessary amount of work when you're planning on self-answering. I think you would be fine to just remove that last paragraph:

> Does such a test harness exist that could do this? Does someone have one?

I strongly suspect that is what's making people's trigger fingers itchy. Rephrase to something simpler, like:

> How would I build such a bootloader?

The only possible objection to this is that the question becomes more of a requirements dump. On the other hand, the reason our users retch at these is because of their characteristically *low quality* and aura of sheer laziness. Neither of those two things are a problem here, or with any good canonical.

Comment: I think reconsidering the  last part of the question is a good idea. Under the comments to this meta question I suggested the idea I considered bad pseudo code and felt that just muddied the waters. Sometimes writing a Q&A canonical question (like I did here https://stackoverflow.com/q/54845547/3857942 ) is easy to produce bad code in the question that someone might actually have tried in real life - and then you work from there in the answer (yes that canonical answer was a dupe target for another related question)

Comment: I made a few modifications to the question, mostly in the vein of pretending that I'm on Jeopardy and don't already know the answer. It may not be the best question in the world, but we're [optimizing for pearls, not sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). In other words, good answers are more valuable than good questions, as long as the minimum requirements are met. I think they are certainly met here. @Michael

Comment: Thanks, I responded to the edit on the question