# What about programming questions where the accepted answer is a library?

Tags: discussion

I find this frustrating. I asked a question of [is there a way to do something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730971/ms-dynamics-trigger-on-data-change). And I got a spot on answer (in a comment). But, the answer was use a part of the Microsoft stack (to work off another part of the Microsoft stack).

The thing is, this isn't a which is best issue. And there are most likely no other answers to this question. This is probably the only way to accomplish this task.

Asking which Java IDE is best - I agree should not be here. But asking a question where 100% of people who know this would suggest the same approach, and that approach is a specific library, should be allowed.

As it stands, questions where the answer is use the library built for that task get disallowed. And that helps no one.

Comment: Answers suggesting a library are perfectly acceptable. It's questions explicitly asking for a library that's the problem.

Comment: "There is absolutely nothing wrong with tool recommendation answers when done correctly. " -> [psubsee2003's answer to "Recommending off-site resources when questions don't ask for it"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/7795130)

Comment: Dynamics is big... It is not really clear if you wanted to limit to just CRM or interested in other parts like [F&O business events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/business-events/home-page). Also comment that you claim answers the question (the one written by you on SO, not one you actually have) is very strange - question asks how to get notifications in web app and comment suggests to drop it in favor of logic app... I think there is some space to make question more specific and demonstrate what you've tried and how it did not work...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree that the question could have been more specific. A request for more specificity I would have responded to with more details. My point is that the answer given is correct (if I was more explicit it would have helped clarify that this was the right answer) and it was closed because the solution is a library.

Comment: Would closing as "needs more focus" (aka "too broad") be more useful? Listen for/ forward events is not narrow enough to have one answer agreed by large number of developers... so question in its current state either asks for list of approaches ("too broad") or list of libraries ("recommendation"). Side note: I'd personally would not bring up this question - you put zero efforts in writing the question and got answer you were looking for... It would be far more valid complain if post would be longer than one sentence with details of couple approaches that did not work and still got closed.

Comment: Maybe try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ next time? but there is less traffic there than in SO