# How would I have asked this question in such a way that it wouldn't get closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

This question was closed:

[Is there a WebSocket equivalent that works in Windows 7 that is complete and requires no coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68155684/is-there-a-websocket-equivalent-that-works-in-windows-7-that-is-complete-and-req)

For this reason:

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations

I don't post here as much anymore, so maybe your guidelines have tightened up a bit, but this seems like a perfectly legit question for someone looking for an alternative to `WebSocketClient` who still has their own reasons for using Windows 7 which doesn't support it.

How could I have asked this differently?

Comment: You literally said `Therefore, I am hoping that some kind of library exists that ... ` and yet you are somehow wondering why it was closed for asking for recommendations?

Comment: @JK. The question's title itself just says "WebSocket alternative", so I guess I made the error of using a forbidden word in the body. I just now edited the question to replace the word "library" with "alternative". The question is exactly the same minus that word.

Comment: Nope.  What you are asking for is still an off-site resource.  Whether you call it library or an "alternative".

Comment: @StephenC I would argue that the vast majority of questions and answers here ultimately point to off-site resources such as NuGet, third-party software, etc.

Comment: Yes.  But you are explicitly asking us to **find** or **recommend** one for you.  That's what makes the question Off-topic.

Comment: Okay, so then I could have just said, "How can I open a web socket connection in Windows 7 using .NET?" Correct?

Comment: Possibly.  I don't know if 1) that is really what you want to find out, or 2) if that is a question that already has an answer.

Comment: Actually ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039438/using-websocket-on-windows-7  ... so your question *could* have been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: But you could ask that question for anyone's inquiry and it wouldn't change anything. Also, that question you pointed to is 9 years old and is specifically about VS 2012 RC. So back to my question, would my question have been closed if I asked "How can I open a web socket connection in Windows 7 using .NET"?

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what kind of answer you expect *other* than a library recommendation? The question requests an "alternative [...] that effectively emulates <websocket> and **requires no coding to implement interfaces**". Websocket interfaces usually do ship as libraries, and not investing coding seems to boil down to finding a library.

Comment: Ask what you want to know, now what you want to have. "I need X" questions are better put into a Google search box. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, questions need to be asked accordingly. "How can I open a web socket connection in Windows 7 using .NET?" sounds so much more reasonable, don't you think? I'll tell you why I find it a beauty: the question is now overflowing with research keywords. People often stump their toe on that Stack Overflow "no recommendations" rule but you can't deny the beauty in just flipping a question onto it's back to make it infinitely more useful.

Comment: As always, don't ask for a tool recommendation. Ask how to accomplish a goal. The question should be, "How can I...?" Let the *answers* recommend the tools. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605

Comment: I had to roll back your edit because it reads more like a rant than an edit for clarification... Completely disregarding communities' feedback is not constructive at all.

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 That is fine. Anyone who wants to read it can still view the edit history.

Comment: Err…regarding your edit: *"'How can I open web sockets in .NET on Windows 7 when the WebSocketClient is not supported on that OS?' That topic has been officially deemed 'forbidden knowledge" on SE.'* **No, that's *precisely* how you can and should ask the question.** And, no, we don't deem anything "forbidden knowledge"; this is ridiculous hyperbole that demonstrates a serious misunderstanding of the reason why we close questions. We close questions that request resource recommendations because they turn into bike-shedding and attract spam. They don't work well, based on years of experience.

Comment: @CodyGray That's why this meta question ends with "How could I have asked this differently?". Also see my comment way above "so then I could have just said" that I asked twice, so three times altogether basically. Gimby has the one comment that addresses those inquiries, but not long before the page turned into a wall of text with 20 downvotes. I think much ado was made about this.

Comment: @CodyGray Also, the word "library" was indeed in the body, but the title uses the word "alternative" which could encompass a library or a code solution. I was expecting the community to be able to identify my core request and not get hung up on a binary word in the body. At any rate, I believe I found my solution and have definitely learned the proper way to ask a question here. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 16):

The issue is not the wording.  The issue is more fundamental.  The ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page states:

> *4) Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Changing the word "library" to "alternative" in your question does not cure the problem.

In fact, there is probably no cure.  Your question is fundamentally off-topic.  You are asking us to find or recommend some software for you.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the term "off-site resource". It's referring to literature or other learning material.

Comment: I think I am NOT misunderstanding it.  And presumably, neither did the people who voted to close your Question.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin The term "off-site resource" refers to off-site resources. Note how the preceding examples also include "tool, software library", not just literature and learning material.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin What are *you* basing your understanding on? [Here is the close reason](https://i.imgur.com/wmiFTSu.png) and it directly names "software libraries". The same text exists [in the close banner on your question](https://i.imgur.com/IAC4euT.png). Note that it also mentions "tools". The close reason is really not ambiguous whether it's only learning resources or not, We have a whole stack dedicated to [softwarerecs.se] - you can try using that.