# Should old, high-rep, link-only, accepted answers be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, answer-quality, moderators

**Exhibit A:** [Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery/119473#119473)

NOTE: Don't get itchy with your duplicate trigger finger.  I'm trying to find out if the community genuinely believes that high-rep, accepted, link-only answers should be deleted or converted to a comment by a moderator, in response to a moderator flag.

I am asking if you want the policy to be changed, because right now we don't delete these answers.  We assume that the community sees value in them if they are highly-upvoted, the OP accepted the answer, and the question is on-topic.

**Exhibit B:** [Python math is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11950819/102937)

**Exhibit C:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/2939979.  Alexei was kind enough to rescue my link-only answer by making a judicious (and extensive) edit.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this very important topic bugging so many community members in my experience. +1 for the question to bring it up for wider discussion.

Comment: No, otherwise even the time gap in which it will be needed to rewrite a history every time will be revised. That is, if you need to rewrite the rules to the current state once a year per se - you'll soon need to redone all million things in a week span. Although, the upper case might differ in the situation when the popularity growth rate varies from "those times" to "now" and influences accordingly to the number of users in power and thought (at local time).

Comment: I think the main problem with your question is that you're not really reaching out for the community using the stack overflow, but instead to the minority reading these questions and being active on meta. They tend to have different priorities: people on meta would more probably be of the janitor kind, dealing with the cleanup, whereas users are consumers, possibly gaining a lot from the answer they've upvoted. Now, you can prefer the opinions of people at meta, but claiming that would be the voice of the entire user base is just wrong.

Comment: If you'd like to know the opinion of users, you'd need to have a poll next to the answer about its usefulness. But isn't that pretty much what voting is?

Comment: @eis: you mean [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173399/how-to-turn-source-file-to-install-program/23173469#23173469) that got downvoted into oblivion? The main problem is that people are afraid to downvote such answers submitted in the past because they are too afraid to reach any result with it, and that is sadly true. You never get 50-100 downvotes even though many people separately think this is not valuable, they do not trust each other acting so. The best I have seen so far score 9 turning into 1-2 and got deleted, but that meant a chat discussion with others involved.

Comment: @eis hasn't that always been a problem with Meta though? I've been a member of [main] since 2009, and I've only recently become more active on Meta, mostly because of the spin-off of [metase], and because more interesting questions seem to pop up in the Community Bulletin on [main] now because of it. Before that, for the longest time, the activity here on Meta was basically invisible to me. I think it helps a lot now too that your posts on Meta are no longer tied to reputation, like they were before the spin-off of [metase]. You don't have to be so afraid of disagreement/downvotes now.

Comment: @Cupcake possibly. However, I would think in most cases it wouldn't matter as much. When you're talking about deleting content that's possibly highly popular and valuable to some, the controversy is a bigger concern than usually.

Comment: Right, so it seems Gilles's proposal was the most liked by the community, so it is time for the moderators to change their habit?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Gilles' answer has 26 downvotes, and the other answers are mostly dissenting opinions, so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: if voting by the community is not enough, then I must say that I think this is not a democratic process and there is not that much weight in votes.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: It's not enough for me to change the way I moderate.  The community still has the power to dispatch these answers, if they're so inclined.

Comment: It is not only about you, but the whole moderator team. In any case, moderators complaining about deleting upvoted link-only answers... Yeah, right... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list To me, those moves do not make much more sense than deleting link-only answers, but anyway ...

Answer (score 56):

I don't see what high-rep has to do with this, except possibly a presumption of not being spam (pending investigation on what else the user did to gain reputation).

High-scoring and accepted are indications that the link is useful and should be kept in a comment. As a moderator, I would err on the side of converting to a comment unless there are hints to the contrary (e.g. the link is mentioned in another answer, or the flag says “the solution behind this link is the same as Joe's answer”, or there is a strong smell of spam).

But **any link-only answer should be deleted**. [It is not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

As a moderator, doing this is your job, especially in cases when the community cannot act, such as high-scoring or accepted answers.

If someone wants to include content from behind the link in an answer, they can and should post an answer of their own. Editing the link-only answer would generally be a radical change (it might be acceptable if all the edit does is to introduce a literal quote from the cited web page, but not if the editor introduces wording of their own).

Note: by “link-only answer”, I mean a post that does not contain any content that answers the question, but contains a link to a web page where an answer may be found. A post which contains a terse answer and is formatted as a link is not a link-only answer.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery/119473#119473) (in its first revision, it has now been edited) is a non-obvious case: it says “use this particular library”, with a link to said library. When the library referenced is at a well-known, stable location, this kind of answer is a generally poor answer but an answer nonetheless: it says “use this”. On the other hand, when the library is “the code on Joe's blog”, this is not an answer: you have to read Joe's blog to find out what is meant. The way to tell link-only answers is: **if you didn't have hypertext links, would the post still be useful**? If the answer is yes (e.g. because the answer gives a name of a module from the standard library), then the post is an answer. If the answer is no, then the post is a sign that says “there's an answer over there”, it is not an answer.

Comment: I think it would only be a radical change if the edit did include information that is contrary or different from the solution. I think only allowing a clearcut copy is taking it a bit too far. I've amended answers myself this way if the user did not respond to a request to change it, never got static over it. Most of the time the users did not know the link only policy and happily edited their answer, by the way.

Comment: Rather extend the answers to provide minimum required content (as in exhibit #3)

Comment: [43](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251613/321013) vs. [23](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251701/321013)|[7](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251693/321013)(!) ??! ... oh my ... and so the insanity is spreading ... to which I might add: **Stop $&%§%!& deleting content if it's not spam and still useful.** Of course Robert and George put it much more eloquently, so go upvote their answers.

Comment: @TravisJ The question was about the general case, this was just one example. (I see that more examples have been edited into the question, they weren't there when I answered.) The example in question is a borderline case, I don't feel strongly about it either way. I haven't looked at exhibits B and C.

Answer (score 34):

You know what? *I don't care* if it is highly voted and accepted - it's still a link only answer, therefore it has a certain fragility and is [susceptible to butterflies flapping their wings in China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect).

However it does have a little bit of value, just not enough in its current form. **It should not be deleted**, it needs to be built upon and expanded into a good answer. But therein lies the dilemma - the question needs improving but that isn't a moderators job. The moderator can rightfully dismiss the flag but that doesn't help improve the answer.

So in this case would a custom decline reason help, along with routing the answer to the Low Quality review queue? That would give the flagger a hint on what they should do (if they ever bother to check the result of the flag). If the answer is routed in to the [low quality queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) that might get it some lovin' attention (it should be safe to do that - it can't be deleted because it's accepted).

Comment: I know there isn't a mechanism for a mod to just move a post to the low quality queue, however does a mod flagging it as low quality get it immediately to the queue?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable compromise.  Instead of the low quality queue though, maybe some other queue of "answers that need improvement" or something.

Comment: @AdamRackis 'queue of "answers that need improvement"' - that is the low quality queue already (or at least its intention) - "Identify, **then improve** or delete low-quality posts".

Comment: Moderators can edit answers just like everyone else.  I agree getting the flagger to do the work is an even better solution.

Comment: @WarrenDew I'm aware of that - I am a pro-tem moderator on a beta site. However it isn't their primary focus - especially on a site like StackOverflow where they have a reasonable daily workload. Moderators are the exception handlers - answer fixing needs to be offloaded to the community.

Answer (score 28):

Well, I apparently see this very differently than the meta netizens that have participated here ([other than George, with whom I agree wholeheartedly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251693/16587)).

First, I agree with eis, who [states](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted#comment4178_251609) that the viewpoints expressed here may not convey the sentiment of the community at large.  Most Stack Overflow participants never come here; they rely on you and I to make sensible decisions about how the site is run. Deletion of an answer solely on the basis that it is "link-only," regardless of the veracity of the information imparted, is not a sensible decision.

The mission of Stack Overflow is to collect useful programming knowledge; if that knowledge is useful, but not in a form that we like, the first thing we should reach for is making that knowledge available to the community in a form that is acceptable to us, not removing the information outright.

Moderators are tasked with getting involved on posts that cannot be handled by the community.  Their first priority is the *preservation of useful information,* not a slavish adherence to the rules.  If the first thing you reach for on a high-rep answer that is accepted by the OP as the correct answer is a moderator flag, you have abdicated your role as a member of the community.  You've taken your eye off the ball.

Comment: Preservation is important. A link _can_ be a a very good answer, and safer than summaries that lack the nuance of some topics. Adding useless fluff just to avoid deletion is a waste of space. However, protecting the information the link points to (it _is_ fragile), is just as important (a dead link might as well be deleted). That's the challenge. Writing comprehensive, completely accurate, updated for all time summaries of linked documents, videos, or other material, is a challenge to any busy professional. The link may be all the OP needed; it might be _more_ valuable than a short answer.

Comment: "The mission of Stack Overflow is to collect useful programming knowledge; if that knowledge is useful, but not in a form that we like, the first thing we should reach for is making that knowledge available to the community in a form that is acceptable to us, not removing the information outright." - amen to that. I've raised a question exactly about this outright ramoval practice at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289411/first-timers-answer-pointing-to-open-source-code-and-disclosing-affiliation-de

Comment: Does your answer apply to link-only answers that have broken links?

Comment: @Laurel: Link-only answers that have broken links contain no information at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Should I flag as NAA? Or what?

Comment: @Laurel: Links don't appear in the Moderator Dashboard.  Use a custom flag, and explain the problem.

Answer (score 12):

One of the particular advantages that Stack Overflow once enjoyed (and now copied by Q&A type sites across the internet) is the ability to 'pin' an answer. This is done on Stack Overflow by the checkbox next to a given answer.

This confers a few advantages to that answer:

- It's the first answer seen by a user from Google
- It has the best chance of getting upvotes
- no one can change an accepted answer except the OP.

Moderators are really glorified janitors, our job is described as:

> It’s deleting obvious spam, closing blatantly off-topic questions, and culling some of the *worst rated posts in various dimensions*. (emphasis mine)

Even further than that, one of our guiding principles is:

> The ideal moderator does as little as possible. But those little actions may be powerful and highly concentrated. Judiciously limiting your use of moderator powers to selectively prune and guide the community — now that’s the true art of moderation.

So in those twin sentences we have our charge: Get rid of the really bad stuff; and try not to be overbearing in what we do.

Deleting an accepted answer with a ton of upvotes doesn't strike me as judicious, nor is it a janitor's job.

Clearly the community finds utility in the answer (otherwise it would not have that many upvotes).

When an answer is flagged, we really have two practical options:

1. Delete the post.
2. Do nothing.

For accepted answers, a member of the community has a lot more practical options at their disposal, especially if they organically find that answer:

1. Leave a comment for the OP to fix the issue in their answer.
2. Edit the post with relevant information.
3. Downvote the post.
4. Go to a chatroom, drum up support for downvotes and comments (or asking someone to fix the issue if it's their wheelhouse)
5. Flag.

We're at the very bottom of those list of things to do for a reason:  Moderators are not a substitute for the everyday work that is required to keep the site clean.  We are too few.  There are many more effective things to do (and things that are in keeping with our purpose) than flagging these sorts of answers for us to delete.

It's easy to flag; it's a little harder to do something -- but the 'do something' part is exactly what keeps a community thriving.  If you see a broken window, help repair it when you can -- that's much more useful than saying, "Hey, there's this broken window. SOMEONE FIX IT."

Comment: Clearly the community *found* utility in the answer *at some point in the past*.  Such an answer probably would not be as heavily upvoted today.

Comment: FWIW, all of Robert's examples received multiple, recent up-votes @cHao. Two of them get upvoted at least once a week, regularly, and have for some time.

Comment: @Shog9: try to post such an answer with fresh evaluation cycle. That is, starting from zero score, and see how far it goes. Try to get people 50-100 people to downvote a highly-upvoted wrong answer to compensate the site policy changes. Only a few will do it, especially within a short while, so they are rare. If the post starts from scratch, it might even be downvoted to oblivion in worst case, but I am almost certain it would not even exceed ten upvotes altogether, or perhaps even five.

Comment: If you're arguing that such answers would fair poorly if posted in their original form today, @Laszlo, then... Well, I *hope* so. Not sure why that's a bad thing. Does it offend you that yesterday is not tomorrow?

Comment: @Shog9: we want Stack Overflow to be the best site without carrying the bad things from ages the policies of which have been put into rest by this community. I am not sure I would care as a reader when a post was born. I only care about its quality. If the age is an excuse for very poor posts, that will only make me less happier as a reader seeking for _awesome_ posts.

Comment: @Laszlo - Huh?  If I'm using SO as a *user* that means I have a problem.  Something is preventing me from doing or fixing something.  I need the problem fixed.  Surely you're not suggesting that I'd be less happy if I were to find my solution in a "low quality" SO post?  That's absurd.  I want my solution any way I can get it so I can move on with more productive endeavors.

Comment: `Go to a chatroom, drum up support for downvotes and comments (or asking someone to fix the issue if it's their wheelhouse)` -> Are you sure that chat rooms are well sized for the issues and tasks at hand?

Comment: @Shog9: What does bother me that "answers" which would be considered substandard today, could nonetheless be pointed to tomorrow as evidence that that's how good answers look.  If they could have a note similar to the historical value one that appears on some questions, it'd be slightly less bad.

Comment: He has a point, @Shog.  Can we get a simple post notice that mods can slap up there???

Comment: I'm skeptical that those work, but... Post a feature-request @Adam.

Comment: @cHao: I don't really buy that. First off, we've deleted literally *thousands* of similar answers of the same vintage, so if nothing else the argument falls apart quickly - but more importantly, it's so much easier to *fix* these answers than it is to get into a long, drawn-out argument over them, that folks who care enough to do the latter can just as well do the former. That's why I see it as so crucial that *new* answers of this form are identified and corrected  (commented on, deleted) as quickly as possible - it gives the authors a chance to learn. But you can't re-write the past.

Comment: (And yes, I find it really embarrassing that I've watched dozens of folks respond to their terrible link-only answers being deleted in the Low Quality queue these past few weeks by coming back and editing details into them, only to come here and see the folks flagging these answers unwilling to lift a finger toward the same end.)

Comment: @shog - point taken.  It's hard to justify a post notice when editing in content from the link is just so easy.

Comment: @Shog9: I'm pretty sure you just said that deleting people's terrible link-only answers *caused their improvement*.

Comment: Indeed I did, @cHao - particularly when coupled with a comment. What, did you think there weren't *any* ulterior motives involved in not fixing [this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable) The problem is that **it stops working when the author has been gone for *years*** - commenting in those cases is just wasting your time. Either the post has no value and should be deleted, or you're stuck having to fix it yourself.

Comment: @Shog9: And in nearly all cases, i'd argue the former.  **A link is not an answer unless you're Google.**  Someone who wants to write a real answer can do so -- even based on the link.  But an answer that actually includes content is no longer the post the original author wrote.  And quite frankly, the editor of such a post, who took the time to turn it from a steaming pile of an answer into something worthy, deserves the credit for that answer more than the author does.  He should post his own answer incorporating the info from the link, IMO, and/but the link-only answer should be nuked.

Comment: Well, @cHao... I have [a rather strict definition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for what I consider "not an answer". Beyond that, nothing's stopping anyone from posting another answer, if they would prefer that to editing an existing one; both are good options in many cases. But in all cases, one should not step into a question that has proved useful and leave it *worse* than when they found it - by one means or another, they should strive to improve, but at very least ape Hippocrates and *do no harm.*

Comment: Couldn't agree more with the mission of moderators to "Get rid of the really bad stuff; and try not to be overbearing in what we do". Did you forget about this maybe when you [deleted the last standing answer to the GPS offset in China question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448149/googlemaps-gps-location-is-always-offset-in-china/29466209#29466209)

Comment: Here's the meta question - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289411/first-timers-answer-pointing-to-open-source-code-and-disclosing-affiliation-de

Comment: This answer is partially out of date now that accepted answers are not pinned to the top anymore on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10):

Well, are we here to slavishly follow the FAQ, or are we here to provide useful information? If it's the former, then go ahead and delete them; if it's the latter, then let's keep useful answers, as measured by the response of the community.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you can't take context into consideration when applying rules, how are you any better than a machine?

Answer (score 7):

Naturally having more than a link is always ideal, so editing some content from the link into the answer is the best of all worlds, which is fortunately what happened with Robert's examples.  But deleting the answer or moving it to the comments section is antithetical to the purpose of this site, or at least what the purpose of this site should be.

If the post is high-scoring, that implies that many people found it useful.  The goal of Stack Overflow is—or at least used to be—to compile the best repository of questions and answers to be found; it's disturbing to me that some people find settling on a particular set of rules and enforcing them to be a more important goal.

If I Google for something and come to a relevant Stack Overflow post, I desperately want to see this highly-voted answer as ... a highly voted answer.  That helps me much, much more than burying it with myriad other comments for me to sift through.

Comment: We are discussing link-only answers that become pure garbage the moment this link becomes stale.

Comment: @PM77-1 - well when the link becomes stale, nuke it.  It will have zero *information* at that point.  But until that happens, kindly leave it for the next person who arrives from Google, or, if you really want to be a good citizen, edit some content from the link into the answer.  Clearly a lot of people found it valuable.  Consider that before you vote to move it into a comment.

Comment: If you look at my answer, I have suggested a *nuclear option*.

Comment: @PM77-1 - I don't think that's a nuclear option - that seems like just good housekeeping to me :)

Comment: Please refrain from arguing about terms. The comment wall makes it unreadable and less comprehensive to follow what is going on. Focus on the gist only, please.

Comment: We are trying to compile a repo of good questions and answers, not links to where good answers might be.

Comment: @0x7fffffff - then by all means click the edit link and add to the link-only answer.  Or write a better answer.  But please don't banish an answer which many have found useful to the comments section.

Comment: @AdamRackis I just want to point out that highly upvoted comments don't get buried underneath a bunch of other comments, they get sifted to the top, with bold arrows that eventually glow orange and red. You can even observe that here on Meta.

Comment: @Cupcake - if it's an old comment, that was posted when the question was new, then sure, it'll have a ton of votes if useful.  But if you're talking about a year's-old post, then it's likely a newly-added comment *won't* get a ton of votes after getting dropped to the bottom of the comments list.

Comment: @AdamRackis perhaps a modification can be made that will allow moderators to convert answers to comments in such a way that the comments will have the same number of upvotes that they had when they were answers.

Comment: @Cupcake - it's a solution in search of a problem.  These answers have, *and continue to have* (see Shog's comment under George's post) value.  Leave them.  We can absolutely have high standards for new content while letting old and valuable content exist and continue to help people.  That said, a post notice of some sort saying that these sorts of answers are no longer acceptable and should not be used as evidence that you can post link-only answers today might be useful...

Comment: @Cupcake: yeah, moving the votes to the comment, too, would make it smoother to migrate, but then they will come up with the "no exception mantra" they like to repeat which I do not personally agree with.

Comment: I also found it disturbing that [all answers to this very difficult questions have just been deleted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289411/first-timers-answer-pointing-to-open-source-code-and-disclosing-affiliation-de), after I raised the problem on meta.SO.

Answer (score 2):

It's different when the links are broken. There are a few actions that you can take:

1. Try to find a suitable replacement.

   The WayBack Machine may be helpful, although I haven't had any success with it so far.
2. `@ping` people.

   This mostly applies to pictures more than other links. If you think the answerer/questioner/editor/commenter can make another picture, there's no harm in reaching out.
3. Flag a Moderator.

   Nobody can fix some of these links. If a post has no information and all its links are broken, it is adding no value.

   > Links don't appear in the Moderator Dashboard. Use a custom flag, and explain the problem - [Rob Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted/251701?noredirect=1#comment336454_251701)

Answer (score -2):

How bout...

- Editing the core of the answer in from the link. OR
- Post a new answer with the content inside
- While still placing the link (in the new post) for more details, and accreditation.
- Bonus points: [use archive.org wayback machine.](https://archive.org/web/) for the link/ Where it will never get stale.

(Note point 4 assumes archive.org never runs out of donations)

Comment: @LaszloPapp : Thats me >_> i was using a colleagues com without logging out and in by accident.

Comment: If you think that what's behind the link is useful, and that it isn't redundant given the other answers (which is pretty common, given that `see here http://joesblog.example.com/` doesn't give any hint as to what method was used), post an answer that explains the solution in your own words. Then flag for deletion.

Comment: @Gilles yup, as i believe its fairly common for the external link to cover more then what the question is asked. That may be related or useful to an individual facing a similar situation. So putting the answer in, and leaving the link as reference is the idea here.

Answer (score -6):

Please don't deleted those answers because from the *nature of acceptance itself it proves that OP have tried it and found it(the link) very useful.*

*And from the no. of votes, not only OP but it also helped other users.*  I used to vote an answer in StackOverflow by not only looking at it.  I used to try that solution and if found it much useful +1 from my side and sometimes I used to place comments(even if it fails - just a comment).

> How to handle this case?

*Link only answer?  come'on lets flag it..* Before flagging it members should consider the aspect of votes. Why the hell this *link only answer* has so many votes?  whats in it?

If the link is broken or it needs to be improved let **put a step to improve the answer or simple add comments stating your points about that answer.**

In case if it is not accepted, lets [convert link only answers into comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228175/233367)

Comment: Agree. Don't understand the downvotes. [Sometimes the answer is the actual code library posted at the link, e.g. on GitHub.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289411/first-timers-answer-pointing-to-open-source-code-and-disclosing-affiliation-de)

Answer (score -8):

I believe that **link-only** questions with **broken links** should be deleted.  It can be done as a matter of policy enforcement on individual basis and, to a limited extent, automatically: check `http response` and if it's `404` - delete. Yes, I know that many sites redirect to their custom "404" pages and so we would not catch 'em all.

This way *completely* useless posts would be gone.

Comment: You cannot detect completely useless posts automatically. An answer may be perfectly useful even if it happens to contain a broken link. The issue is whether the answer has some useful content and this cannot be determined automatically.

Comment: We are discussing **link-only** answers, aren't we?

Comment: But then how do you detect that the answer (not question, but I assume that's a typo) is link-only in the first place?

Comment: Surely a simple regex could tell if all of the text of the answer is in a link...

Comment: They will be rendered as a link and nothing else.

Comment: Link-only answer also means answers with a link and some chatty text like "follow the link here: ...", or "this caused me some headache, but this solved it: ..." etc. It cannot be automated. You cannot automate a complex issue like parsing a language automatically like the human mind would. This needs to be manual as Gilles already wrote.

Comment: @LaszloPapp  That's what my "to a limited extent" meant. **Some** of them can be caught automatically. I'm not advocating creating an [AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) solution. Just a procedure with some common sense that would err on a side of caution.

Comment: @PM77-1: this thread is not about catching "some of them". This thread is about solving an overall issue for once and all for _any_ case like that after manual judgement. Your post is about process automation - which is a useful, but different topic -, not about an overall community decision. Process automation would come into play later.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - Have you even read my answer? I said "yes" to deleting link-only answers with broken links and suggested that some of these cases can be dealt with automatically.  I believe that I'm well within the scope of this question.  In comments I simply provided clarification to my post. Nowhere I suggested that complete automatic solution is possible. And please do not take on yourself alone to decide what this thread is about.

Comment: Yes, we did, and even told you a few times already it needs manual evaluation, as even if there is a broken link, there can be useful information around.