# I'd like to be able to flag again

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, flag-ban

I ran into one of those bad questions that spawns a raft of bad answers. I flagged several as non-answers or extremely low quality. A mod disagreed, and now, no more flagging for moi. All flags lead to the 'review your errors' page.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/131433

OK, so one bad day means no more flagging, ever?

Since others cannot follow my flag history link, here's a link to one of the answers in question:

[Apache is not running from XAMPP Control Panel ( Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946150/apache-is-not-running-from-xampp-control-panel/19268156#19268156)

Comment: So here's my question:  did you investigate if the question could be closed?  If it couldn't be closed, did you at least downvote the answers that were actively harmful and not useful?

Comment: Of course, btw, I downvoted them. I downvoted them, and flagged them as VLQ or NA, and (I think) VTC'd the whole question.

Comment: You're not really supposed to flag bad ***answers*** as "non-answers" or extremely low quality. If it's an answer, it's an answer, even if it's a bad one. You have a ton of rep, just downvote them, and maybe leave a ***friendly and polite*** comment explaining why they're "bad" or incorrect. Or if you're not so inclined to comment, just downvote without one.

Comment: By the way, I don't think anyone can see your flagging history other than yourself...

Comment: The moderator handling of flags is so unpredictable that I have stopped altogether until there's some improvement in quality.

Comment: @GarryVass: Really.  Examples, or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Cupcake why do we have a 'not an answer' flag if we don't flags answers as not-an-answer?

Comment: @bmargulies it's mainly used for comments that are posted as answers. Like I said, if someone answers a question, even if it's a bad and low-quality answer, it's usually still a legitimate answer (link-only answers are a notable exception, but you have to be careful about how you define a "link-only" answer). See [Should old, high-rep, link-only, accepted answers be deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251609/456814) and related discussions.

Comment: @bmargulies Your example is not "Not an answer".  Mods are not here to judge quality.  That's what the community is here for (via voting).  If the answer **appears** to be an attempt to answer the question, then it is definitively not "Not An Answer".  For subtle issues that aren't really answers but look like answers on the surface, you have to pick "Other" and explain why it isn't really an answer.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that we probably should not have a "Not an Answer" flag.  We spend so much time explaining it that we should probably just remove it.  Not an answer means that it is... not an answer, but something else (an attempt to communicate with another user, an edit on the question, a new question).  Many folks want to argue that "it doesn't answer the question" is not an answer, but *if it looks like an attempt at an answer in the moderator dashboard, and you flag it as not an answer, your flag is going to get declined.*

Comment: **Rule of thumb:** If you have to look at the question to evaluate the moderator flag, don't use the Not an Answer moderator flag.  Use a custom flag instead, and explain the problem.

Comment: why cant/doesnt the NAA flag simply dump the answer into the NAA review queue.  Thats what I thought it did for a while.

Comment: @Plutonix there is no NAA review queue, and never was to the best of my knowledge.  There *was* the 10K flag queue which no longer exists, but even then 10K users couldn't really handle the flag.  They could agree or disagree.  20K users could also vote to delete if the post met certain criteria.  So generally speaking virtually all NAA flags went to mods

Comment: @psubsee2003, yea that didnt look right when I wrote it, I meant something like either the LQ pool or a new NAA pool.  The point was that NAA doesnt seem mod-worthy when there is a remove/delete opyion the "community" could use

Comment: @Garry Vass: You're assuming every flag is handled exclusively by diamond moderators. That hasn't been the case in a very long time. But hey, if you don't wish to flag anymore, that's cool, it means less work for us anyway.

Comment: @Plutonix: But considering how much the community sucks at *raising* NAA flags I'm not so sure we should trust them to know how to *handle* them correctly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey to me, troubleshooting advice is _obviously_ not an answer. The author clearly does not have an answer to offer, and is shooting in the dim or the dark. But, you diamonds don't agree? You're in charge.

Comment: @bmargulies: To know if it's troubleshooting advice, you'd have to evaluate the *content* of the "answer," which is what votes are for.  For NAA flags, we're looking for things like "this should be an edit to the question, not another answer," or "this is an attempt to communicate with another user, so it's not really an answer, it's a comment," or "this guy is asking a new question; he should have pushed the 'ask question' button instead of posting an answer."  Things where the user is abusing the platform.

Comment: ...so in the LQ pool, the banner reads 'this question has been flagged as not an answer...` (or words to that effect).  So flagged by **whom**?

Comment: @RobertHarvey you don't have to read one word of context to recognize 'you could try X' as not offering an answer to a question. However, I do get the message about what you don't want here. Mostly, I thought these flags existed now to push things into the queue, not to bother diamonds.

Comment: @bmargulies Whenever you see "you could try X" it almost *always* means it's an answer to a question.  It's an answer that someone is not confident and is unsure if it'll work, meaning it more likely to be an *incorrect* answer, but it is almost *always* an answer.  Here are some examples of Not an Answer posts, "Have you solved this yet?" "I also have this same problem, can anyone else help me?" "John Smith's answer didn't work for me, it generated the following error message:" "I got exception when i run program why happen"

Comment: @Servy: Obligatory follow-up: Beware "John Smith's answer didn't work for me, it generated the following error message: ... Doing this instead worked" and the like. People like to wrongfully delete such as NAA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> OK, so one bad day means no more flagging, ever?

Of course not.  Just like review bans and suggested edit bans, the flagging ban is 100% temporary.  The only difference is the ban is not really timed in the traditional sense, as it won't automatically go away after a set period of time.  There is some timed aspect to this ban however, because the ban only accounts for flag actions within the past 7 days.  At a maximum, the ban will end in 7 days, but may end sooner.

Shog9 explains the details of the flag ban calculations in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/182513) to [Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban)

But the short version is the flag ban is, at most, 7 days and is based on your flagging history of the last 7 days.  You can recover from the ban as soon as your flag history over the previous 7 days no longer meets the ban criteria (which is less than 25% of your flags handled in the last 7 days are declined).

Comment: Can we see our current flagging stats?

Comment: @Jongware in relation to the ban?  No.  The flag summary in your profile is the only details we get at this point, but it doesn't show dates when flags were handled, so if you have a lot of flags that were handled out of order and/or well after the flag was raised, it won't be a good guide.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion - depends on how you are defining max and min.  Minimum in this case was supposed to mean the worst case scenario.  But i can see how it could be confusing for someone.