# Can't flag link-only answers as link-only answers

Tags: support, flags, link-only-answers

I wanted to flag [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222983/2338750) as link only. However, I don't seem to have that option when selecting a reason to flag.

[image]

None of the reasons fit:

- It is spam - False
- It is offensive, abusive or hate speech - False
- It is not an answer - Close, but it does actually attempt to answer the problem.
- It is very low quality - True, but it is salvageable through editing (including the information from the link)
- Moderator attention - I try not to use this flag too often, and IMO this is most definitely a case that shouldn't need a diamond moderator's attention.

## Question (or feature-request?):

Why can't I use one of the following reasons when flagging the answer? It doesn't seem to make sense. The screenshot below if from the Low Quality Review Queue.

[image]

For the record, I left a comment to OP, and flagged it as not an answer. It might be OP tried to leave this as a comment but was prevented due to low rep, but I don't know.

Comment: I'd argue that this _is_ an answer, since it stands as one even if you remove the link itself.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I partially agree, but it only touches parts of the question, so IMO it should be a comment (at best). Regardless, even if I'm wrong about this particular answer, it doesn't change the question.

Comment: [Add a "link-only answer" flag reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167953). [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) Also somewhat related (shows what the community thinks VS staff) - [Should old, high-rep, link-only, accepted answers be deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251609)

Comment: Considering the answer without the link... that specific one seems like "very low quality" (you can edit **anything** to be appropriate - not sure what "salvageable through editing" is doing there).

Comment: @Dukeling let's not forget [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers), which is marked as a duplicate of one of the posts you linked, but I think adds some value.  This discussion has been done to death.  A "link-only" answer is **not** a reason to flag a post.  If it can be fixed, edit it, if it can't, then flag it for another reason (Low Quality is often the best reason, but sometimes Spam or Not An Answer, and as a last resort, a custom flag.

Comment: @psubsee2003 while I think that's a good idea for older posts, I'm not sure whether always fixing other people's posts is necessarily a good idea (especially (a) when there are many better answers, and (b) it encourages users to only posts links, as they know it will be fixed).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy then flag is for what the problem is.  It has been stated before... the link isn't the problem.  The problem is either the entire answer (low quality, not an answer, etc) or the question.  And if the question is the problem, then flag the question, not the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because *the mere presence of links* is not a good reason to remove an answer.

If you removed the link from that answer, could you in good faith flag it as Not An Answer? If not, then you've no business flagging it *with* the link. If so, then... Well, just flag it as Not An Answer!

We don't have a "link-only answer" flag because folks can't quite seem to wrap their heads around the notion that "only" means "*[and no one or nothing more besides; solely or exclusively](http://google-dictionary.so8848.com/meaning?word=only)*". Even as it stands, folks routinely flag answers for moderator attention and *type in* "link-only answer" - on answers that are merely *terse*, with links to documentation and so on.

#### See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I've had several of my "link-only answer" flags declined for not being *that* link-only, but most such flags I've made have been marked helpful, along with the post being deleted.