# Am I evaluating link-only answers correctly?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32757155/4342498) on [How can I play Apple HLS live stream using html5 video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434803/how-can-i-play-apple-hls-live-stream-using-html5-video-tag) and it was declined. This has caused me to re-evaluate whether I am evaluating link only answers correctly.  Now when I evaluate if an answer is a link-only answer I strip out any links and see if the answer still can be an answer. So if we do that then

> On Browsers supporting [Media Source Extension](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mediasource) you can use https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js

Would become

> On Browsers supporting Media Source Extension you can use

IMHO this is not an answer as the rest of the answer is listing the requirement to use the linked to utility. If that link were to break, the answer would not be an answer.

Am I evaluating link-only answers correctly? If I am could someone explain why this would have been declined?

Comment: You need to leave the *text* of the link in. It becomes *On Browsers supporting Media Source Extension you can use [project name]*.

Comment: E.g. the link may break, but if you can still find the project hosted somewhere else you could still solve the problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So it should actually be `On Browsers supporting Media Source Extension you can use dailymotion hls.js`? when we strip out the link.

Comment: Granted, the answer is pretty crummy. It fails to address the question posted.

Comment: Yes, because without the mark-up, you can stil see plenty of info about the project. Google certainly can tell me loads about Dailymotion hls.js.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you wouldn't mind making that an answer I will accept that and update how I am evaluating link only answers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Without the HTML markup, the project name is still clearly readable in that text. Just because the link *text* is also a URL doesn't mean the text is entirely devoid of meaning.

So without the markup, it is still clear that the answer is to use the Dailymotion hls.js project, provided the browser supports the Media Source Extension.

Comment: I have a doubt, how do you flag link-only answers? As "not an answer"? At some point I thought you were not supposed to flag those answers, because they still were answers, just pretty bad.

Comment: @Dzyann: see [Can't flag link-only answers as link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260572); if it is *nothing more than a link and nothing else* a NAA flag applies.

Comment: Martijn thanks a lot! I have seen different posts regarding the issue and I really appreciate you pointing to one that is the official view.