# Is evidence required for link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged an answer as "Not an Answer" for a link only answer, and a moderator declined it due to "lack of evidence". **How do I build a case of evidence to show the mod that there is no content to this answer?** Even comments like "For those not interested in digging through the wiki" exemplify the fact that the links are not even focused on the question at hand, but are generic, "here's the documentation, wallow around in it for awhile and maybe the answer is in there" links.

My understanding of answers containing a link, that the community seems to agree on, is that they at least contain a minimum of some conceptual description of the answer, and be a link that is focused specifically on the question at hand. Not just links to documentation that address a vast superset, that do not even have one sentence that describes the solution conceptually.

Comments like "So every time page renders (when I start the hub), I have to update my list of users with new clientId?" exemplify the fact that users are left to guess even at the conceptual solution.

**Just a few sentences that describe the conceptual solution to accompany the links would have been enough to meet what (in my opinion) is a very low bar for what it takes to be an answer.**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7872685/84206

There's more to determining if it is an answer than just link rot.

This has an intersection of two really bad things: no conceptual description of the solution AND the link does not focus on the solution. It's not just missing one of those things; it's missing both, and I thought there was at least a minimum for asking people to meet those very-easy-to-meet minimums.

If it were a link to an article/tutorial that addressed the question directly and described a solution, then it wouldn't be half as bad in the absence of a conceptual description in the answer, but the links are not even that focused.

This question is about as good as having said "Google persistent connections and hubs and read the documentation or RTFM".

At the very least, the discussion in comments should have prompted them to add a little more concept to the answer.

Comment: Borderline,  without the link markup we still have the url that can be seen one of which points to a github page and the other points to the official documentation so neither are going to be very prone to link rot (though it is still possible). I would say that the biggest contributing factor that I see is that it is highly upvoted *and* accepted. In my experience you will have a hard time getting a moderator to delete any accepted answer, especially a highly upvoted one. That is entirely conjecture though, and no I am not going to divulge my flagging history in order to back up this point.

Comment: @TinyGiant Mobs are not always the best judges.  I thought that's why we had flags.

Comment: The original version of the answer had inline code then it was changed to point to the docs. I'm not sure if that code is obsolete and the OP thought pointing to the docs would keep things current.

Comment: Strangely, [a mob is indeed the recommended solution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284267/a-little-consistency-in-flag-reviews/284269#comment146277_284269).

Comment: @JoshCaswell If this was a case where someone did put genuine effort and it was simply duplicate information, then I'd agree that comment that they deserve that reputation.  This was not that level of effort.  They did not find an article the apply narrowly to the question.  They did not put even 10 seconds of effort into just 2 or 3 sentences describing conceptually what one should do to pull those APIs into a solution to address the question.  Virtually no effort, so I don't see a reason to apply that logic here.

Comment: That said, if there is some threshold of "too much reputation to apply the established rules of Not an Answer", then we should just disable that Flag and put a message in its place that says "This answer has received 20 upvotes, and is no longer subject to the guidelines of Not an Answer".  I don't really believe that's the solution, but I think it exemplifies the misguided nature of that logic.

Comment: One issue may be the age of the post. Back in 2011 when the answer was posted, it was probably OK according to the guidelines, and now it's not only the accepted answer, but it was upvoted 43 times. If the links are still valid after four years, they're probably going to stay, and without more justification for doing so, it's pretty unlikely that the answer is going to be deleted. This looks like one of those posts that isn't really worth making an issue over to me.

Comment: Oh, I'm inclined to agree with you. Most interestingly, as [has been pointed out elsewhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290370/can-we-please-clear-misunderstanding-that-deleting-old-highly-upvoted-posts-caus), George Stocker's recommendation actually results in the _loss_ of the reputation that he is trying to preserve, while the mod deletion _preserves_ it. The whole conversation around deletion of answers is generally a mess.

Comment: @KenWhite Maybe so, but the flag decline implies I didn't provide evidence of the issue, which I did it pretty good detail.  If there is some other criteria they are applying of age, upvote count, resistance to link rot, etc. then they could have cited that easily as the decline reason.  I'll walk away from this though as it's not worth discussing further.

Comment: The site was reasonably mature in 2011, @KenWhite: the [prevailing attitude about link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/159251) had [already been pretty well established](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/8259/1).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yeah, I was here in 2011. While your link may be accurate, there were lots of things that were better received then than now (although people seem to be getting punished for them well after the fact). The answer and it's votes have survived four years plus; it doesn't seem to be hurting much IMO, and as I said, the links appear to still be viable.

Comment: Sidenote: an (almost) link-only answer should be flagged als Very Low Quality, not as Not An Answer.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306765/am-i-evaluating-link-only-answers-correctly

Comment: @Glorfindel That isn't (almost)?  It is link-only.  "See the docs." is not an answer: it describes what the links are.  The label on each link is nothing but repeating (part of) the question.  That answer has *no content other than the links*.  Even the url text of the links is not informative.  The only content (the names of some classes) are repeats of what the OP was saying (they where asking about said classes).

Answer (score 12):

I think this is a textbook case of confusion between link-only answer and NAA, along with a technically correct (the best kind of correct) decline reason, more than anything.

As you stated, you flagged a link-only answer as NAA. So it follows that there is no evidence that this is NAA because it's quite clearly an attempt to answer the question. *With links.* Granted the decline reason that was chosen wasn't particularly helpful (like I said, it's only technically correct), but had I been the one reviewing your flag I wouldn't have been inclined to act on it either.

Mostly because it wasn't *always* link-only. In its original state, the answer consisted not of two links, but two very brief code samples, the latter of which was updated some time later by another user. Presumably this is why it has so many upvotes today — it was useful, and very much so. Later the author decided to move the content to GitHub due to updates, leaving nothing more than a stub as an answer intended to point to an external source that is more likely to be kept up to date than one or more answers scattered around the site.

But that doesn't change the fact that the answer is already upvoted, and accepted, but most importantly — an attempt at answering the question. My advice to you? Rather than quibble about it being link-only now, I suggest helping restore the answer to its former glory, and then some. Improve the answer by editing it (since the author probably doesn't have time to do so). That is something you should not need to involve a moderator in.

Of course, you don't *have* to. The onus doesn't fall on anybody to improve an answer. If you're not inclined to spend the time editing an answer (I do understand how time-consuming substantial edits can be), you're free to leave it alone. But given the status of this answer, and the context behind it, I'd say flagging this sort of answer is counterproductive at best.

Comment: So, when did official guidance change to flagging link-only as VLQ instead of NAA? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't know, all I know is that it changed to ["stop systematically flagging answers based on a programmed set of criteria"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183676#183676)

Comment: Well, that's nearly a year older, and not nearly as well-received, so presumably obsolete... Also, it doesn't say which flag to use, only to not simply do pattern-matching. Actually, it's a lot less explicit in many ways, and the main thrust is make sure it should actually be deleted and try to get it resolved some other way.

Comment: Oh. So how should this particular issue be resolved, then, if both its past history and the fact that it's easily salvageable without requiring moderator intervention are irrelevant? Delete current answer as obsolete, post as new? That seems to me like a colossal waste of time for multiple persons all because of one bad but easily reversible decision.