# Failed audit in "Low Quality Posts". What do you think?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Although good, I know that the audit system is not perfect because it is mainly based on upvotes. And upvotes, as you know, do not always reflect the level of quality...

I was reviewing *Low Quality Posts* a couple of minutes ago and got a failed audit for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16341304).

[image: Low Quality Post]

Even if it received 5 upvotes (most of my in-depth answers do not even have this score...), I still think this answer is not a good one. There is almost anything tangible here because the essential parts are provided by an external resource. That is why my decision was to consider this post as a *link-only answer* and recommend deletion.

I would like to have your opinion on this particular review to see if I took the right decision. I am doing reviews quite seriously and I try to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: Even with a broken link, the answer does still give what appears to be a property to use to solve the problem. The first sentence by itself looks like an attempt to answer to me, even if it isn't a good one. (I'm not familiar with Plone at all.)

Comment: I think this community consensus should be explained more clearly to newcomers. It is not always easy to differentiate a very bad answer that deserves downvotes from an answer that should be flagged and deleted. *Attempt* is an important keyword for answers. It should be highlighted somehow...

Comment: @Badacadabra I've been here myself. You get used to it. Read over the links provided by NathanOliver a few times and it should start to make sense. It is difficult as sometimes you think _this does not answer the question at all_ but if it's an attempt it's still an answer. With link only, I tend to be careful here. If it is literally a tutorial they are pointing to, VLQ. If they give some insight however then stay away. Remember **you aren't on your own** and so others will catch them. Skip if you're unsure :)

Comment: @Bugs I think it is clear for me now, thanks to a couple of declined flags and answers on this thread. Asking this question was definitely a good idea...

Comment: This is a *low* quality answer, not a *very low* quality answer. It provides a bare minimum of substantial information that may help the questioner and others, but it could be *so much more* If if it had more information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually think this is a good audit.  Sure the answer is not great but

> There is the `Products.PlonePAS.events.UserLoggedOutEvent` for such purposes.

Answers the literal question.  Sure the how to use it sits behind a link but you really don't need that for it to be an answer.

You might want to give [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) a read.  There is also [Am I evaluating link-only answers correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306765/am-i-evaluating-link-only-answers-correctly) which helped me to truly understand what link only means.

Comment: I also had this problem with the *not an answer* flag. Some of my flags were declined, even though the content was terrible (just one line with poor grammar and almost no info...). That is why I posted this question. :)

Comment: @Badacadabra Yeah, answers get a lot of leeway.  Remember you can always down vote answers you feel are bad or not useful, but those feelings are not reasons to delete.  Something that doesn't even try to answer the question/gibberish deserve NAA/VLQ flags respectively.

Answer (score 14):

This is not a link-only answer.  It is a short answer, but it has real, tangible information that `UserLoggedOutEvent` is the event the OP is looking for. Then it provides an example link to supplement the answer.

Even if you think this is not a very good answer, it does not deserve deletion.  The audit is a good one for getting reviewers to avoid deleting legitimate (if short) answers containing links.

Comment: OK. So I just have to recommend deletion for answers that contain NOTHING except the link, right? :)

Comment: @Badacadabra Yes, something like: *There's a good tutorial here [link]*

Comment: That's mostly correct.  If there isn't any meaningful information after removing the link, then delete.  Otherwise, if you could reasonably get information it can stay.  Downvote if you wish, but don't delete.