# I need some help understanding these disputed NAA flags

Tags: support, not-an-answer, link-only-answers, disputed-flags

I noticed some of my recent NAA flags were disputed and I have a hard time understanding why. I understand that the community (or a moderator?) decides the result of a flag and I respect that. However I have been reviewing these cases in particular and I keep coming to the conclusion that I would flag them again if I saw them for the first time.

It feels like there is some fine line between a true NAA and what I have flagged as NAA, and it is unclear to me.

Below are 3 cases, for each I explain my interpretation of them.

1. [How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures/2791219#2791219)

   > [image]

   "Here is a link named after something you don't understand, read it and your question will be answered. Oh here is another link".
2. [Expand/Collapse Lollipop toolbar animation (Telegram app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070079/expand-collapse-lollipop-toolbar-animation-telegram-app/31074173#31074173)

   > [image]

   "This library makes everything simple. Check this tutorial. Here is a link to an app. Here is another link"
3. [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super/2723503#2723503)

   > [image]

   "I already answered this, here is a link to it. Also here is some info that you won't understand unless you already know the answer"

To my understanding, these are all textbook NAA. [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> The rule-of-thumb here is to strip the markup; if you can still regard it as an (attempted) answer without the link, it is still an answer and should not be flagged.

Strip the mark up -> what remains? -> nothing useful. Yet the flags were all disputed.

I am looking for an explanation on why the answer is not NAA for each of these 3. I sincerely do not understand.

I did not come here to discuss my voting behavior. Only the flags.

---

<sub>Previous to the edit in Rev 2, [the dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) was a good one, because it answered the question as I had phrased it. However it was not the answer I was looking for and it was my bad for phrasing the question that way.</sub>

Comment: I don't think shog's example and your answers are the same.  Even without the link you know what technology or who's tutorial to use: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306765/am-i-evaluating-link-only-answers-correctly

Comment: "Disputed", of course, means that you have your peers to blame for disagreeing with you, not moderators. That means it will be even more difficult to give you any sort of objective guidance.

Comment: There have been lots and lots of meta questions about the flagging powers of NAA flogging already, be sure to read them.  But sure, you are never going to find somebody to do what you don't want to do yourself.  Nobody will volunteer to kill such highly upvoted posts, just as you don't appear to be willing to downvote them.  Which is what it takes.

Comment: @HansPassant when I flag posts as confidently as in these cases, i don't usually also downvote them because that costs a vote, of which I have less. Don't mistake me for someone afraid to lose rep for downvoting answers. I downvote many bad answers, just not always all of them

Comment: I think the community has already decided (most of) these answers contribute to the community. NAA deletes the answer. Would these questions be improved by removing these answers? While they may be technically invalid answers, getting a dozen or more upvotes to me means they are exceptions. Improving them would be welcome. Deleting them? I would dispute it.

Comment: terrible answers get upvoted all the time, i wouldn't consider score to be a good factor to go on.

Comment: @KevinB One or two upvotes, even 5, sure. But not 80. At that point it's been voted by the community as not a terrible answer.

Comment: eh, no, it's been voted as "useful" or "correct", not not a terrible answer.

Comment: I assume people will see this and the meta effect will mean they get more NAA flags, and downvotes.

Comment: You get votes returned to you when a post you vote on is deleted, so you aren't really "wasting" your votes when you downvote things that you flag for deletion. In my opinion, if you feel confident enough to flag something as NAA, you should probably be casting a downvote on it, too.

Comment: The flag might get declined/disputed, but the downvote will remain as long as the answer does.

Comment: It means that some users are less willing to get rid of them, kind of like questions that get a historical lock put on them. FWIW, I don't understand why 1 & 4 didn't flag as duplicate instead of posting an answer that just links to another Stack Overflow answer but it seems not everyone disagrees with doing that.

Comment: somewhat tangentially related: [Cleanup 500 old terse answers that either have hidden value or indicate awful questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334866/839601)

Comment: Comments above this one were made on the original version of the question

Comment: @TemporalWolf The answer with roughly 80 votes is now deleted. So two out of the three flags presented by Tim Castelijns may have been good. So **mjs** answer and Lundin comment may be the most correct evaluations of the expected results, while Petter Friberg answer may be an appropriate explanation of what happened unexpectedly.

Comment: @Cœur I can't say I agree with the decision. In the 2nd case, the question's usefulness to future readers is actively harmed by the removal of content, especially given the top rated answer links to the now deleted answer as "an easier solution." If you take the time to improve or migrate the information, that's one thing... but as it stands, useful information was lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two look like classic link-only. Declining/Disputing NAA flag on these is.... odd.

The last is not a great answer, however *at a glance* does appear to at least include some extra information. Its borderline, I think.

In context, it might be as useless as you describe, however at first appearance looks vaguely valid. Having said that, if another question has the answer, the question should probably have been marked as duplicate.

Comment: I agree, the first two examples are not attempts to answer but attempts to provide personal assistance by providing some links with information and then letting the people figure it out for themselves. You don't need domain knowledge to see that this is happening.

Comment: 1) and 2) are crystal-clear cases of answers that should be deleted. Those flags should not have been declined. 3) adds additional information on top of the link. It tries to answer the question and it adds some information which is unique to the answer. It should not be deleted - the flag was correctly declined.

Answer (score 6):

Let me try to answer, but first we need some background about the purpose of the Low Quality Post queue.

The LQP queue is composed of >2000 rep users and its main purpose is to delete answer that are nothing more than:

> "Thanks you, Great Answer!", "I have same problem any updates?", "Ohh, this is a forum let me ask another question in an answer?", "This is some additional info to my
>   question", "What does X mean in your question"

Its purpose has also been extended [to delete "link-only answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), that stripping markup contains nothing more then "Read this" and currently there is also discussions about [deleting link to tools that does not explain how to use it or what it does](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354501/did-the-site-policy-regarding-link-to-tool-answers-change)

Let's check the individual answer you flagged (I will be stripping out the core info)

> Producer Extends, Consumer Super

Tim (with domain knowledge) says, *"Hey this is a broad and general concept, how the heck does that answer the specific question"*

LQP queue go for, *"That's an answer it indicates what design pattern should be used"*

> Android Design Support Library

Tim says,  *"sure that lib has 1M functions how the heck is that an answer?"*

LQP queue go for, *"It indicates what library you should use, so it's an answer"*

> Note that generally you should only be using ? extends T and ? super T for the parameters of some method. Methods should just use T as the type parameter on a generic return type

Tim says, *"What the heck that just a copy of the other answer, close it as duplicate if the answer is the same"*

LQP queue go for, *"That's seems like an answer"*

**Conclusion**

You are using the wrong tool, whether you like it or not that queue is open to 2K user and you should not expect them to have much domain knowledge, you should only feed it with simple and clear stuff that can easily be judge without much domain knowledge.

***but, then how do we clean up these old questions, that already have other good answer?***

Your tools are:

- **Leave a comment to OP**, explaining what is wrong asking that they improve the answer, if OP is not active anymore this can still serve for others to take appropriate action.
- **Edit it**, but since this question already have other more highly up voted answers I can understand that probably it does not have much sense.
- **Down vote**, send'em down towards the bottom (and signal to OP that's something is wrong), then move on to other stuff (I would probably have done this), with some luck in the future if not improved by OP it can be deleted by >20k users.
- **Custom moderator flag**, for example the first answer you could try to flag and ask for it to be converted into comment, explain with your domain knowledge why it does not answer and instead should be only a comment.
- **Meta**, try to get the community together, [bring a bunch of stuff that we can work on and we involve mods to help us out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334866/cleanup-500-old-terse-answers-that-either-have-hidden-value-or-indicate-awful-qu)

Comment: as far as I can tell edited version of the question is indeed strongly related to [Cleanup 500...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334866/839601) All questions listed currently look like perfect candidates for this posse, and reasoning on how to handle these would fully apply. The only reason why these didn't make it back then is exceeded length limit - and that limit in turn is not an essential requirement but only means to decrease rate of false positives in a script that generated that list

Comment: Yes, I agree. it's about old "link'ish answer" that over-time have gather upvotes but does not have much value anymore and can not be delete by >20K rep users, however sending them to  >2K user is probably not the solution.

Comment: overall idea of that posse was slightly different, it took into account that there is a chance of upvotes indicating useful content behind the link, course of action was (if question itself is OK) to first check if link really leads to useful / quoteable content and if it does then edit it / otherwise delete. Important to note the part of checking the link content is an exception made only for historical value answers, normally step like this is absolutely voluntary and one has full right to abstain of doing it and demand straight deletion

Comment: "its main purpose is to delete answer", nope, they are there to fix problematic posts. That's why they also have an edit button.

Comment: @Braiam true, but in the context of this post, Tim did not flag because he needed help to edit. When you raise a flag, you raise for deletion not requesting help to edit. The edit feature is included so that people with insight can fix posts that does not belong in queue (edit will automatically bring post out of queue and is often misused clearing valid flags). I still believe that the main purpose for LQP queue is to help mods deal with all NAA answers that SO is flooded with, hence I will not change the wording.

Comment: @Braiam with all due respect to me deleting link-only answers is main purpose indeed. I am not there to click every random link and help every lazy sucker do what they are required to do per site guidelines, I am neither inclined nor obliged to do this nor have time. As for edit option, to me it's merely a secondary time saver for rare cases when I know that link is very useful beforehand or when I feel generous. As I mentioned in prior comment, priority of edits in that historical posse was purely exceptional and had a very specific justification that regularly doesn't apply at all

Comment: @gnat well, that's your opinion, but the site clearly state "Identify, **then improve** or delete low-quality posts". Improvement has always been chief of the queue.

Comment: @Braiam what is important to me is that such an opinion as mine is 100% legitimate, you won't find any official requirement to prioritize edit over deletion. (Compare that to official requirements to authors in [answer]: "Provide context for links... Always quote the most relevant part...")

Comment: @PetterFriberg my grip is that you characterize the queue as having a single goal which is delete posts. It's not. If you change to "one of its purposes" or "one of its most common uses" it would be better.

Comment: @gnat yet incomplete. If you are given a hammer everything you see is a nail. The queue wasn't designed to be just a hammer.

Comment: well I use it as a hammer @Braiam (well 99,99% of time to be accurate) and I am happy with that. And I am happy with that my use is 100% legitimate. "I am not there to click every random link and help every lazy sucker do what they are required to do per site guidelines, I am neither inclined nor obliged to do this nor have time."

Comment: If a custom moderator flag had been raised on those, it would have been declined

Comment: @mjs I would not be so sure, if it's well formulated explaining the exact issue and context it may depend on mod, but for example [Producer Extends, Consumer Super to the rescue!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2791219/5292302) have been deleted by mod, however I'm not sure how mod saw it, do note that mod even consider it to not bring enough info to covert to comment, probably because there is already another good answer on question

Comment: "...and you should not expect them to have much domain knowledge" This is no excuse for incorrect reviews. In case the reviewer runs into something that requires domain knowledge, they should skip the review. Which isn't something that the flagger need to be concerned about.

Comment: @Lundin this is the [guideline for LQP queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/320339) the related text is *"If you think that an answer does not address the question at all or is incomprehensible"*. I think we need to be realistic when we flag as NAA use "Android Design Support Library" with 80 upvotes, to delete this or not is not what we expect from the 2K rep peps in LQPQueue (I even think it will get an automatic mod flag if it is deleted). Conclusion: They should have some domain knowledge but they don't need to have 20K judgement nor mod judgement to choose if to delete or not.

Comment: *maybe it can be rephrased some, I'm up for suggestion.* What I want to state is that it's not the right queue for these answers, you should choose another tool.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Up-votes is not a reliable metric at all. The up-votes on old, link-only answers is more of an indication of age than of quality. You can even come across some with lots of up-votes but leading to a dead link.

Comment: @Lundin I'm well aware of this, I'm not discussing deletion or not, I'm discussing tools that we use. It's fairly obvious that the LQP queue is not the correct tool to solve this problem and I don't think we should expect it to be.