# Do link only answers get a free pass just because they are highly voted?

Tags: discussion, flags, link-only-answers

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55828/4909087) and [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829/4909087) for the same question. Here's a screenshot for convenience.

[image]

This answer, by the way, does not have as many votes as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840/4909087) which happens to demonstrate exactly what to use and how.

While I can't say I know much about c#, this answer seems like a blatant link only/NAA. Upon raising a flag, it was declined for the reason:

```
declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
```

This could either mean

1. The answer is not link only (highly doubtful, because it is)
2. My flag was declined just because of the sheer number of votes on the answer

So, the question to be asked is - do link only/NAAs get a free pass just because they have a lot of upvotes? I don't think that's the case, because I've seen other famous questions with highly upvoted link only answers which have been deleted.

Would appreciate a fellow user or moderator shedding light on this.

Comment: It's not a link-only answer. Strip the markup and you still have an answer: use LINQ to XML on .NET 3.5 or higher.

Comment: @CodyGray Not sure if you want to use it as a target but there is also [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306765/am-i-evaluating-link-only-answers-correctly)

Comment: Also see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135920/why-are-accepted-answers-immune-from-flagging-link-only-answers-as-not-an-answer/136026

Comment: Also good links. Especially @Tiny's. I'm sure I read that one years ago, but it had slipped my mind. Very helpful insight into a moderator's mindset. But, I closed as a dupe of the FAQ intentionally. I also took the opportunity to improve and clarify the FAQ.

Comment: possibly related: [Cleanup 500 old terse answers that either have hidden value or indicate awful questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334866/839601)

Comment: [Try this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357416)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not a "link-only" answer.

Here's the test: remove the hyperlink but leave the text. Is it still an answer?

> I'd use LINQ to XML if you're in .NET 3.5 or higher.

That looks like an answer to me. Too short, probably, and lacking any context, but it's still an answer. Vote accordingly, but don't flag it.

Now *this* would be a link-only answer:

> Try [this](https://a.link.to/somewhere)

Comment: This link... is broken!!!

Answer (score 7):

> The answer is not link only

And there you have your answer.  Just because the answer *contains* a link, doesn't make it a link only answer.  The post is still an answer even if you were to strip out the link markup.  It's not a *good* answer in my opinion, but it is *an answer* to the question.

If you think that a given answer isn't a *good* answer, then you can use your vote to reflect that, but it doesn't make flagging it appropriate.

Comment: Also - from 2008...

Comment: @Oded I'd expect that if it really was a link only answer that wouldn't matter.

Comment: Yeah, fair point.