# Link-only answer advertising a library - why has it not been deleted?

Tags: discussion, flags, link-only-answers, convert-to-comment

A little while back, I found an answer that matches the description of a "link-only answer", [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers):

> Which is great, however, you haven't answered their question at all, you've deferred the answering to somewhere else. And in this (fictitious) case the person has to take quite a detour to get to their destination.

Here is the [exact answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213609/symfony2-custom-password-encoder-bcrypt/8219546#8219546) in question:

> Instead of reinventing the wheel, I suggest you to use my bundle, which solves the same problem. Or, at least, you can see how it's implemented.

It has upvotes, so it has been useful. This is why I suggested it be converted to a comment. According to [This link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer) on whether or not to flag answers which contain only a link as "not an answer", I read:

> (This section spells out the logical consequence of the first section, plus some additional advice for moderators.)
>
> A link-only answer is not a desirable answer. Therefore, any flag that suggests the deletion of a link-only answer should result in the deletion of the answer, and should be marked as helpful.
>
> If the link looks like it may be useful, convert it to a comment. A link that is spammy, redundant or irrelevant should be deleted outright; a link to a page that looks like it contains the answer should ideally be in a comment (“here's something you could extract an answer from”). If in doubt, converting to a comment is the best default choice: it removes the clutter from the answer section while preserving the information.

With the above in mind, would the community please tell me why it has not been converted to a comment despite multiple flags? It is a link-only answer to advertise a library.

Comment: Just a question for you, you've now flagged this 3 times and none have been declined - why do you feel so strongly that this **accepted answer** needs the attention of the moderators to be deleted?

Comment: @bluefeet Because it's a link-only answer and the more significantly upvoted answer is by far the most helpful (and the most deserving of credit)? I also put a lot of effort into my own answers, so when people put barely any effort in, I think that this site can do so much better. Do you disagree?

Comment: That answer is from _almost 3 years ago_ when the standards were different.  The library addresses the issue that that user had - we are always hesitant to delete accepted answers. Why do you feel this is so urgent that you need to flag the mods _3 times_ for this?  You could easily edit this to elaborate on this answer incorporating details from the link.

Comment: @bluefeet There is already an answer with 15 votes more that addresses the exact issue for OP along with a link to the documentation; and it's a great answer. The currently accepted answer does not do anything other than advertise a library. Just because it was posted a while back doesn't mean it should stay like that, it's still effectively an advertisement for a library. If it were merely an out-of-date answer then sure it should stay, but it's not: it's an advertisement. It can still exist as a comment, and StackOverflow can keep progressing with good answers.

Comment: The answerer has had plenty of time to upgrade / convert their own answer to a comment, btw.

Comment: @Jimbo, regarding your comments... (a) It's up to the asker to choose the accepted answer, not you. (This can be a problem when the answer is completely wrong, misleading or insecure, but probably not the case here) (b) "*I also put a lot of effort into my own answers [...]*", here you sound almost jealous for them getting reputation (in a Q&A where you're not involved at all). It's unfortunate, but reputation and effort don't necessarily match on SO, you just need to take reputation with a pinch of salt. (c) Not sure it's an advertisement in the promotional sense. He was just trying to help.

Comment: @Bruno No jealousy. Just standing up for what I believe in when it comes to StackOverflow - which is good quality stuff, basically. I've taken in so much from this site, and I fully intend to give back. So when I see others put little effort in it does rile me somewhat - almost as if they don't really care too much about future users (who might also help them in the future). Karma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting it to a comment is not going to happen. Comments are not for answers; they can't be maintained, aren't indexed by search, and have a host of other problems *when used for purposes they were not intended for*. This is the advice given to moderators considering that option:

[image: Answers should be converted to comments when they do not attempt to answer the question]

So yeah, *not an option*. Here are the real options:

1. **Edit it**. Anyone can do this, someone who knows something about the topic probably should.
2. **Delete it**. This requires a moderator - no one else can delete heavily-upvoted, accepted answers. If the link was broken, the answer was deemed obsolete, or the votes were fraudulent, this would likely happen. Otherwise, it is *at the discretion of the moderator team* - given they do not necessarily possess the knowledge to evaluate arbitrary answers based on their technical merits, they tend to err on the side of *not* deleting answers that others have found useful.
3. **Nothing**. This is the worse of the three, but if no one cares to edit or delete it, it'll sit around.

Worth noting that if this answer was posted today, I would delete it on sight - as would most folks here, I suspect. The only reason it's still around is that, in spite of appearances, folks have found it useful - including the person who asked the question.

There's one more wrinkle to this though... As noted in the comments on that answer, in other answers, and *in the documentation for the library itself,* this answer is obsolete: the support it offered was built into Symfony as of version 2.2. Given that fact, I think it is safe to remove it now - and have done so. You might have mentioned this in one of your *three flags*, you know...

Comment: Link-only aspect aside, I don't think there should be any ground for deleting an answer that was correct when answered, but is now made obsolete by a newer version of the tool or library. Both the answer with the old version and the newer version were useful, both were upvoted, both can still be useful (either for historical context, or because someone cannot upgrade).

Comment: I'm totally puzzled how you would come to the conclusion that "delete" is a better option than "convert to comment". First of all, "comments are not for answers" but, well, it's just a pointer to an answer - the only hard info in the answer was a link to seemingly useful information. Second, why completely delete the answer just because it's outdated by a newer version of the software? Now the information is simply gone which seems like the worst option. Having it as a comment, ideally with the added information that it's only required for 2.1 and earlier versions, seems way more helpful.

Comment: Stop deluding yourself, @l4mpi: "convert to comment" is just a fanciful name for "post a comment **and then delete the answer**". There's no magic here; you're not somehow able to have your cake after having deleted it. So if you can't justify deleting the answer, you should not dare to suggest converting it to a comment. The decision on whether to delete or not comes *first;* then we can talk about whether anything else should be done.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with posting a comment and then deleting the answer. My thought process is simple: Is it an answer? No -> delete it. Is it useful information? Yes -> keep it as a comment if possible. I don't care if someone writes the comment by hand or if a mod turns the answer into one, that's only a technicality - but converting it is probably easier in many cases. I just don't think the information should be removed from the site if it has value for future visitors.

Comment: FYI, I edited the question earlier, to make it less "link-only". There's no way for me to vote to undelete, though. It's a minimal change indeed, but hopefully, it should make it a valid answer.

Comment: Converting is *never* easier than posting a comment, @l4mpi, for the simple reason that a moderator handling a flag has less time to spend on it than the person raising that flag. In order for an answer to be converted, it must be obviously not an answer *and* obviously a good comment; if you have to explain why it's not an answer or why it's a good comment, then conversion is unlikely to happen unless you make a very compelling argument. In particular, *short answers* never make good comments, and folks who repeatedly assert that they should be converted are just making more work for others.

Comment: I didn't delete it because it had a link in it, @Bruno - I deleted it because it's obsolete. You disagree?

Comment: @Shog9 absolutely, it's useful to keep both. As I said earlier, someone may now or in the future a previous version of that tool. Answers are complementary. One that says "at the moment (before version 2.2) you can't you need this" and "since version 2.2 you can do that" can stay perfectly well next to each other.

Comment: That'd be a useful edit then, @Bruno

Comment: Fair enough, just edited. (I still can't vote to undelete, of course.)

Comment: Edited further, and restored @Bruno

Comment: Ah, great work!

Comment: You'll note that editing *was* my #1 option... Folks could save themselves *so much grief*...

Comment: Just wanted to say - with the edit, it's been worded really well and now makes the page look much more like a knowledge base :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't share the hatred that a number of people have for so-called "link-only" answer. Some people seem to be hunting for them, without seeing the bigger picture. Some are of very bad quality (especially those that point to a long tutorial), but some are useful and valid.

Yes, one of SO's aim is to build a repository of knowledge, but it's also a place for people who have useful, on-topic questions to get help.

While I understand why questions asking for recommendations don't really have their places on SO, this wasn't such a question. It just so happened that the answer was simply "*I wrote a library that does exactly what you're looking for, here it is*" (with a link).

That was both useful to the asker and anyone stumbling upon this question (presumably having the same problem).

I understand the problem with link-only answers: links sometimes disappear. However, in this case, the link is still valid (and who is to say which of SO or GitHub will vanish first anyway?).

I'll admit that this answer would have been much improved by just putting the name of the project explicitly (although it's obviously visible from the GitHub link), but having that piece of information **is** a valid answer, in that it's useful to anyone having the same problem.

If the answerer who wrote this code doesn't wish to publish it under the CC licence on SO, it's their right. That doesn't make the answer less useful. In fact, someone other than the copyright holder could have written an answer pointing in the right direction, without having the right to re-post the code on SO anyway. (It seemed it was definitely more than a comment, by the way, considering the fact it was the accepted answer and had 10 upvotes.)

Deleting it because of "link intolerance" and because the problem doesn't apply to the latest version doesn't make sense. Not everyone is always able to get the latest version of every tool, and keeping historical answers that apply to multiple versions of a problem is extremely valuable.

Comment: I feel like "the link might break" is not a valid reason advocating deletion. "the link might break" says that some time in the future access to the linked information might be lost, removing the value it provided. If it is deleted, access to the linked information is lost immediately, immediately removing the value it provided. So deletion just ensures that the negative consequences happen right now, instead of possibly never.

Comment: It is their right, indeed.  Just as it's SE's to dictate that link-only answers are not kosher.  In the sense that if you want to work within SE's network, you have to abide by their rules.  One of which is that link-only answers are burned on sight.

Comment: @fbueckert, that's rather different though. The primary purpose of SE is to seek and find help, buy building knowledge. Useful links *are* knowledge. In addition, as I said in an edit, it's actually *not* always the answer's right to post or not to post the code: they might not be the copyright holder. As for abiding by SE's rules, that's only partly true, SE wouldn't work at all without its user community, and we make some of the rules collectively (it may just turn out the subset of heavy Meta users may also have more weight too). It's more subtle than "no link-only ever"...

Comment: That's the wrong purpose entirely.  Helping users is a byproduct, nowhere near the primary purpose.  It's to build a high quality repository of knowledge, which helps users with its very existence.  Links do NOT meet that need.  If the user doesn't have the right to post the code, then a workaround as a link should not be used.  There are many, *many* reasons that link-only answers are shot on sight, and all of them are due to their running contrary to SE's primary purpose.

Comment: Firstly, yes, links that provide an exact answer to the question (as opposed to vague tutorials or blogs) do meet the need of providing knowledge. Knowing where to look for something is often just as useful as knowing that information directly. Secondly, saying that "*helping users is a byproduct*" is rather misleading. If you take away that notion of helping users (as long as the questions are on-topic of course), SE completely falls apart. You can't have one without the other.

Comment: You totally can, actually.  The help comes from users *reading* the repository.  We help a ton more people that we don't even realize, just by making sure what we keep is relevant and high quality.  Links are neither of those, due to their penchant and vulnerability to entropy.  Are we helping users?  Yep.  But not at a primary, or even secondary, focus.  But by building a repository of knowledge, and curating it to the best of our ability.

Comment: @fbueckert, a link like this can be relevant, and it certainly *adds* to the overall pool of useful knowledge on SO. Quality is subjective, but it certainly wasn't poor quality in the sense it would have been vague, unintelligible or off the mark. It was straight to the point and potentially useful for other users (10 upvotes in this case). I don't ask many questions on SO, but I do use it both for existing answers (in which case I would have found such a link useful, better than deleted) or to answer (mainly to help in general). Dismissing the "help" aspect of SO as secondary is non-sense.

Comment: I disagree.  A link, by itself, adds no discernible value whatsoever.  Unless the knowledge is here, on SE, it is subject to entropy and link-rot, which is the exact reason why link-only answers are not allowed.  It doesn't matter how many users it helps *now*.  It matters how many users it *will* help, and that value drops dramatically the longer it sits.  Which, when contrasted against actual, valuable information, directly sitting on the page, makes it a no brainer as to why we don't allow link-only answers.

Comment: @fbueckert, knowing that there's a library that is specifically dedicated to solving the problem in the question (and which library it is) **will** be useful to anyone having the same problem as in this question (having to use the same version). This wasn't just an "link-only" answer saying "You'll find the answer somewhere on Wikipedia" or "... in the middle of that blog entry" without saying anything about the solution. Rather it was pointing exactly to an implementation of the solution. This is completely different. You can't put all answers that are mostly a link into the same bag.

Comment: I think "hatred" is the wrong way... there is no such strong emotion rather than passion for a site standing the test of time with canonical answers containing the crux of the answer to the problem in question, *supplemented* by external links; the contents of which may or may not exist in the future. It's putting your faith in StackOverflow.

Comment: @fbueckert: "It matters how many users it *will* help": An existing link will likely help at least those that come by in the next year or so, a deleted link will help nobody. To the user reading the repository, is it more useful to find a link that points them to the information they were looking for, or is it more useful to find no information at all?

Comment: @sth This isn't about an all or nothing deal.  Links, by themselves, could help some users.  But you can't compare it to nothing; you compare it to an actual answer, generally the text behind the link, except as an answer, instead of a link.  Compare those two: which one helps more?  A link that has a much higher chance of losing its content the longer it sticks around, or the text that sticks around and directly solves the problem the asker had?

Comment: @fbueckert, no one disagrees that a clear text is better than a link. However, sometimes it's not legal, practical or useful to post the content behind the link. For example in [revision 3 here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24553601/revisions) (clearly posting non-OSS code of which they're not the author). For libraries fragments, it can be worse to post an outdated version that's never going to get the upstream fixes. The web is made of links, live with it.

Comment: @fbueckert: If the discussion is about deleting the link, then certainly it has to compared with a deleted link. The "actual answer" won't just appear out of thin air just because an answer containing a link got deleted. And even if there is an "actual answer" sketching a solution: Having additionally a link to the whole code only improves the situation.

Comment: Legalities are a strawman.  There is fair use, one of which posting code snippets is a part of.  Either way, it's not up to us to decide what is and isn't legal.  The whole point is that, here at SE, link-only answers are bad.  And continue to bad.  It is not I that must live with links, but you with having link-only answers be removed.  Which is, by the way, one of the weakest arguments I've ever come across.

Comment: @fbueckert, fair use is one thing, but posting an entire plugin is another. Saying it's someone else's problem is just burying your head in the sand. It *is* the community's problem, since users might then re-use in good faith what was posted under CC licence (but should never have been). Remember by the way, this wasn't strictly a "link-only" answer, it was "you can't do it out of the box, but you can do it with this". That's very different.

Comment: I think we're just going to have to agree to disagree.  The overriding feeling at SE is that link-only answers are burned on sight, and you have made no new arguments to convince me otherwise.

Comment: @fbueckert, again, this was *not* a link-only answer. Check the last paragraph [in this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251613/372643). It would still have been useful with a broken link (since thanksfully the name of the project is in the GitHub URL), all it needed was a slight rewrite to put the name of the library.

Comment: Are we even arguing about the same thing?  I've been saying that link-only answers need to be shot on sight.  I agree they're fine as *supplemental* information, so long as the answer doesn't lean on it as the crux of their answer.  The one you're referencing, "I wrote a library to solve this, here", is a link only answer, if that's all there is.  If you're going to recommend a library, the *least* that should be done is to explain how to use said library to achieve the stated goal.  That I would define as a useful answer.

Comment: @fbueckert, no it *is* an answer. This library solves the specific problem in the question (So much so its author integrated it into the project later). This is not supplemental information, this is the main information. In contrast, [this is a link-only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11917175/372643) (which I'm just about to flag, it just says "Take a look at this: http://..../some-article-number"). Both may *look* like link-only, but the first one has the merits of answering the question directly and bringing useful information. Those are *very* different things.

Comment: Nope, sorry, we're not going to agree on this.  Links as answers are not answers.  It doesn't matter whether the linked page is the holy grail of answers.  If all we get is a link, it's not an answer.  If we get, "Hey, this library can solve your problem, **here's how**", and we have the steps here, *that* is an answer.  "This library can solve your problem", is not.  In fact, it's one step short of a LMGTFY link.

Comment: @fbueckert Completely agree.

Comment: Note that I've never argued that these were *good* answers, but just that they *were* answers, which didn't need to be deleted. It is completely different from an LMGTFY link.