# What should be done with links to defunct sites that are now hosting different content?

Tags: discussion, broken-link

An example came up [on the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17554329#17554329):

> Many SO answers refer to wixwiki.com pages, unfortunately wixwiki.com seems to be a different website now. Where has the content moved?

The domain currently points to an unharmful placeholder site. In the future, this domain could link to malware.

Sometimes it's possible to replace the link with a [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/) copy of the content. In the event that a copy is not available, what should we do with these? Should links simply be removed, or should a note be added that the external resource no longer exists?

Comment: Keeping the original address would only make sense if there is hope that the content ever comes back. I rather wonder how many questions become completely meaningless because they relied on an external link that doesn't exist in the old form anymore.

Comment: A note to indicated broken link would be nice.

Comment: Replacing the link with a archived copy of the content might not always be possible, even if you have that content: you might not be allowed to do so.

Comment: If the content can't be easily located, I'd advocate their removal. (And this is a perfect case of why link only answers are a very bad idea!)

Comment: Downvoting the answer might help. Aside from the fact that the answer isn't (as) good any more, the original author might be more familiar with the source and better able to find a replacement.

Comment: @SteveJessop, downvoting without a comment would be rather pointless in this case. Chances are the initial answer wouldn't notice it, or not understand why this was downvoted. I'd also give the answerer a chance to update first. Not everyone's permanently on SO ready to fix things as soon as they get a comment (even if the "last visited" date shows recent activity, this doesn't mean people had the time to look into that particular answer).

Answer (score 15):

My thoughts:

- If the answer is pretty much based on the link alone, then flag the post for moderator attention.
- If the answer is useful even without the link, just edit out the references to the said link.
- Optionally, comment on the answer informing the original author that the previous link is not working anymore; they might update the post with a working link (or link to a better resource).

Comment: Or better still update the post with the relevant information in the post rather than at the end of a link.

Answer (score 9):

At first, try to assess whether the link is likely to come back. This is a difficult one, since it depends very much on the context. I seem to remember a medium size open source project having all its pages replaced with the default Apache Httpd page ("It works!!!" or something like that) for a few weeks, because the server had somehow crashed, just at the time its main maintainer had gone on holidays. Don't necessarily start altering all the links to that site immediately after you notice it being down. (Sometimes, sites also move to different content management systems and links are at least temporarily invalid.)

Assuming the link can be considered as broken, put a comment asking the initial answerers to update it if they know (or do it yourself if you know where the content has now moved).

If nothing happens, remove the link. If the answer no longer makes sense at all, this probably was a link-only answer, flag it as such, it will probably be deleted.

There was some [disagreement a few days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262315/372643) on where to draw the lines with so-called "link-only" answers. In some cases, it can be useful to salvage the crucial piece of information from the link. For example, if the link is something like "`[This library](https://github.com/someuser/SomeFantasticLibrary) addresses this very problem.`", even if that repository is deleted, rescuing the name of `SomeFantasticLibrary` from deletion can make the answer still useful: someone finding that answer can still look for that project by themselves or look for a cloned copy. (Whether or not there's more text around this answer is another matter.) This is of course very dependent whether you can guess anything from the URL structure (URIs are meant to be opaque after all...).

When applicable, replacing the link with its Wayback Machine equivalent is a decent fallback solution.

Copying and pasting the content that you knew was there doesn't sound like a good idea. That content might not be yours to paste, and it might just be too long or completely disrupt the flow of the answer (link-only answers aside, there's often a reason why the reference was just a link in the first place).

Comment: +1 for Wayback Machine. Even if the content will never return, a link can be used to search it.

Comment: Not all links are archived in WayBackMachine,  @Xan.