# Are users unaware that posting a link to a tool is not an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, scope, link-only-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5180431), for example, along with [a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6459239) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655236) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21548165) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5180429) on [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5180382), are code-lacking, link-only answers to a tool/library/off-site resource. Even the question, which starts with `Is there any jQuery or javascript library...` has **12 upvotes**.

Are users unaware that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow?"

---

[This is another (very) similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051061/). Although there is not issue with the question itself, the accepted answer (with **22 upvotes**), as well as two of the other three answers, are code-lacking, link-only answers to a tool/library/off-site resource.

---

**EDIT:** I have flagged all code-lacking, link-only answers to the first question, and all the `not an answer` flags returned `disputed`. So this is not only an issue of rules changing in the time since the questions were asked/answered.

Comment: Those questions are very old, and the rules have changed over time.

Comment: Lacking code isn't a symptom of a non-answer.  Providing a link to an off-topic resource and that's about it is a symptom of a non-answer.  In spite of their age, cleaning up old questions and answers like this is something that we would want to do - downvote + flag as not an answer.

Comment: How would we know?

Comment: @goldilocks Note that the "third" and "fourth" answers linked to in the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251007) have since been removed anyway...

Comment: Actually I retracted my close vote because I realized you are asking about something more specific -- *tool* links.  IMO the real crimes are blog links, etc., and a minimal answer mentioning a tool with a link is better than a minimal answer mentioning a tool without a link.  They're kind of edge cases, e.g., I don't see much wrong with *most* of the "Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery" Q&A.  Privileging answers which include DIY code over ones which recommend a library, for example, is begging people to re-invent wheels.  **Context, context, context.**

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, a third-party tool, library, or framework is a viable solution to a problem. You can't post the entire code for a framework in an answer, and Stack Overflow doesn't host code repositories or other file downloads.

While I'd prefer to see more detail in answers like this (a short explanation of how this solves the particular problem, or code demonstrating it in action), I don't believe every single answer containing links to third-party libraries or tools should be deleted. Ones that don't answer the question or ones that are purely promotional, sure we remove those all the time. However, if they directly target the question asked and provide a link to a tool or library that solves the problem, I consider that an acceptable answer.

Ask yourself: does removing those answers make the Internet a better place? If it cuts people off from solutions others have identified as being helpful, I would argue no, it does not.

Comment: (There was a similar discussion in [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262299/372643), which was closed as a duplicate, but is actually a bit more specific.)