# Do tools and libraries constitute "helpful" link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers

When reviewing, it's not uncommon to find a question that's been asked within the on-topic guidelines, most pertinently one that isn't specifically requesting a tool or a library, and for someone to answer with a link to a relatively well known tool or library saying "this is what you need" or words to that effect.

These get flagged as link-only answers and stuck in the review queue, and I usually mark them for deletion because, well, it's a link-only answer in the letter of the law.

Occasionally the answerer will reply to the auto-comment with some snarky message to the effect of "It's a library. It's stable. The link is going nowhere. What else do you want me to post?" And the more I think about this, the more I wonder if they don't have a point.

So what's official policy on this? Should we be flagging and deleting such answers? And if so, given that (like a lot of link-only answers) the link content is often helpful to the question, how should we direct users to improve their answers? It's not like they can paste the entire source code into the answer, after all.

Comment: Well, I'd like to see some words of explanation some excerpts from the page... A link-only answer seems a very poor meal to me. It doesn't help me understand what I'm doing wrong and why - possibly how to fix it in general. If it's a library, then the question itself was off-topic, because "it asks us recommending a tool, ..."

Answer (score 20):

I had [this to say](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266201/19679) on [a similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266194/are-users-unaware-that-posting-a-link-to-a-tool-is-not-an-answer):

> Sometimes, a third-party tool, library, or framework is a viable
>   solution to a problem. You can't post the entire code for a framework
>   in an answer, and Stack Overflow doesn't host code repositories or
>   other file downloads.
>
> While I'd prefer to see more detail in answers like this (a short
>   explanation of how this solves the particular problem, or code
>   demonstrating it in action), I don't believe every single answer
>   containing links to third-party libraries or tools should be deleted.
>   Ones that don't answer the question or ones that are purely
>   promotional, sure we remove those all the time. However, if they
>   directly target the question asked and provide a link to a tool or
>   library that solves the problem, I consider that an acceptable answer.
>
> Ask yourself: does removing those answers make the Internet a better
>   place? If it cuts people off from solutions others have identified as
>   being helpful, I would argue no, it does not.

A few people have recently been running blind queries against any short answer that contains a link, and flagging them as "very low quality" or "not an answer". This appears to be an attempt to farm helpful flags, and I don't think it is productive behavior. Personally, I've declined several of these where the linked library was a good answer to the question posed.

Comment: So, I should vote "looks OK" if the library's an actual answer to the question? I've heard mixed opinions on that (delete it as VLQ because it's link-only, leave it there because it actually answers the question, and delete it because you really shouldn't be promoting third-party libraries on Stack Overflow to begin with).

Answer (score 11):

Depends on who you ask.

If a question specifically asks for a library (a no-no, usually), then it doesn't help the flag answers -- because they're doing specifically what the question asked.

In those cases, it's better to flag the question, and leave the answerers be.

An answer can absolutely contain a link to a library that solves the OP's issue, and it would be a great answer, if it included the following detail:

- How to use the library to fit the OP's immediate need
- Code included to show an example of the above
- Detail regarding anything that wouldn't be obvious to someone who hasn't used it

Otherwise, it's still an answer, just not a very good one.

My recommendation:

Don't use "not an answer" for this. Don't custom flag it as 'link-only answer'. Leave a comment asking the OP to fix their answer according to the guidelines above.  If they don't, then you can feel free to downvote them into oblivion.

Comment: Just don't use these guidelines when encountering something in a review queue. It might be an audit and "Looks OK" will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

There was [a similar question a few weeks ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262299/372643), to which I provided [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262315/372643). If you look at the discussions in the comments, there was some visible disagreement (my answer is also currently voted +3/-5).

In short, [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262304/372643) suggested this order of preference: edit (to put a bit more explanations), delete, do nothing.

I'd have said: edit (to put a bit more explanations), do nothing, delete.

Giving you the name of a specific tool or library that can address the problem directly can be an answer. Of course, it's completely useless it it's too vague (e.g. "I'm trying to do this or that using JavaScript" -> "Use jQuery").

Essentially, as a rule of thumb, I'd say if an answer carries some information that is not strictly dependent on the link working, it is an answer (not necessarily a good one).

- `The [WonderfullProject](http://....) is a library specifically designed to address the problem in your question` would be a valid answer.
- [`Take a look at this http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzab6%2Frzab6xnonblock.htm`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917175/372643) would not.

The main difference is that the first one will at least give you something useful you may look for (who knows, that library might already be installed on your system), whereas the latter can't give you anything to go on if that link is down. Many answers using the latter format also tend to point to rather long documents where the relevant piece of information is hidden amongst other things.

Remember, this does not make such answers *good* answers. You can still vote either way or abstain (in particular downvote if it doesn't help).

Comment: The problem is that WonderfullProject might as well be a commercial tool in whose sales the answerer is personally interested.

Comment: @JanDvorak I must admit I had in mind the case of a open-source project and something where the answerer would not have commercial interests. If the answerer has a commercial interest with the project, they should disclose affiliation (e.g. "*We wrote WonderullProject [...]*"), but their answer can still be an answer. Of course, spam rules still apply (more specifically if that tool has nothing or very little to do with the question, which is often the case for spam, it should be treated as spam indeed).

Comment: I'd rather not have to visit random people's websites when I'm  reviewing VLQ posts. Not that I don't trust my browser's security, I don't want to give them views.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not suggesting you should visit them. All I'm really arguing for is the use of reasonable judgement instead of processing the VLQ like a robot and just flagging or deleting everything that resembles a link-only answer. It's sometimes fairly obvious to see where the link is going to take you before clicking on it. For example, treating a link to some GitHub/GoogleCode/SourceForge project is somewhat different than going for some other obscure places.