# Can we get some explicit clarification on the *intended* legal usage of code from SO answers?

Tags: discussion, legal, code, licensing

I was recently told by someone that due to the fact that Stack Overflow uses the [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license any code examples cannot be used in a commercially available closed source application. This individual works for a relatively large international corporation and regularly speaks with lawyers of his company to determine what libraries and sources can be used in their development products.

**EDIT DISCLAIMER:** This question, the answers and the comment discussions contain a *lot* of *highly speculative* opinions and perspectives. We do not currently have any official response from Stack Overflow. However I have contacted their support directly and was told that this question is being looked into. I believe the discussion here is worthwhile but until an official response is made please take anything said here (including my words) with a *great* amount of skepticism. The point of this question is to clear up confusion not to contribute further confusion.

I read through some of the old Meta posts and I can see how that interpretation could be made. Jeff Atwood's own answer to the question [What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25957/131570) states:

> The cc-wiki license seems pretty clear to me on this point: free to remix and reuse, as long as you attribute and use a similar license.

Suddenly the interpretation by legal makes sense. If I remix/reuse a piece of code from SO that means I can't use a commercial license on my product.

He goes on to say this:

> That said, a snippet of code falls under excerpt category and thus should be free to use under fair use.

However as another user points out in the comments, [in the US, the legal doctrine of Fair Use does not apply to embedding excerpts of copyrighted works into source code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12196/15498).

I am an active contributor on SO and hence it concerns me that a legal department would be reluctant to allow their developers to use Stack Overflow as a resource due to these concerns. I have always assumed that the majority of the code I provide in an answer ends up in a commercial closed source product. After reviewing this information I can see why those concerns exist and I believe that warrants some explicit clarification by someone authorized to speak on behalf of Stack Overflow regarding this issue.

**EDIT:**

My lack of knowledge with regard to legal matters seems to have led to some confusion. I concur with [Erik Funkenbusch's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-indended-legal-usage-of-code-fro#comment157921_286582):

> I think what is being asked for here is not for SE to legally interpret the license, but rather for SE to state what their intention was in choosing that license, and to say "Yes, we intend that code from SO Answers cannot be legally used in commercial applications (or applications who's licenses is incompatible with CC-BY-SA)" or "No, we do intend that everyone can use this code for their applications". Now, it can be argued that choosing the license says what they intend, but I think what Spencer wants is verification that what seems like an oversight was actually intentional

Jeff Atwood's follow up statement regarding code snippets seems to imply that the *intention* of SO is to allow users to copy, paste and tailor code from the site to their needs. At least, that's how I interpreted it when I read his answer. However it is not expressly stated and even if that is the intention it is questionable whether or not that intention is achieved given the current terms of the site.

An explicit clarification of the intention would help developers better understand their obligations when using Stack Overflow as a resource.

**EDIT 2:**

I wanted to clarify why I believe the intention would be useful. *Speculation* regarding SO's intended use of source code in answers seems to fall two ways.

One way is how I've described per Atwood's answer to the question I've linked above. Simply put, the *interpretation* is that Stack Overflow intends that visitors of the site copy, paste and edit source code found in answers per their needs. If that is the intention there is a problem because the current terms of the site do not support that intent.

The second *interpretation* is that Stack Overflow intends for users to contact the authors to request permission to use their code. However it's questionable whether that intention is being met. Take for example the following answer: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/52551) An example of an answer which contains piece of code that someone may want to copy and paste (and possibly edit) into their project. At the time of this edit the question has 1.3 million views and the answer has been upvoted 3,481 times. Now, it would be naive to think that nobody has copied or pasted this code but there are only two comments regarding the source and absolutely nothing about the license. If the intention of Stack Overflow is that visitors contact authors and request authorization to use this code in a commercial product it is suspect those intentions are being met.

As I see it, both interpretations of Stack Overflow's intentions come with problems that should be addressed. Of course these are just two *highly speculative* interpretations of an unlimited number of possibilities.

**REMEMBER:** Again, lots of speculation here. Stack Overflow has been contacted and is looking into it.

Comment: *"However as another user points out in the comments, in the US, the legal doctrine of Fair Use does not apply to embedding excerpts of copyrighted works into source code."* - the answer that you've linked to is just the legal opinion of the poster, who is presumably not a lawyer. He commits at least one obvious error of reasoning (claiming that copying code for a commercial application is clearly not fair use because it is not included in a non-exhaustive list of *examples* of probable fair use Section 107). He provides no evidence of his theory being tested in court. I think it is bullshit.

Comment: @MarkAmery - Fair enough but clearly there's some confusion surrounding this issue. I believe an explicit response in plain English would clear that up.

Comment: "An explicit response in plain English" would be nice, but may also be impossible for Stack Exchange to give honestly. Remember, they don't own the code here, and as you've already pointed out, the license they demand you post contributions under does not cover the use case of copying code into a closed-source application. Whether it is legal (in the US) hinges on whether it is fair use, and Stack Exchange are *barely more qualified than you or I* to judge that, unless there's some really explicit case law they know about and have never mentioned when this has come up previously.

Comment: @MarkAmery - If that were the case it still warrants a response from someone who can speak on behalf of Stack Overflow. Even if their response is "We can't say for sure." There's no point in speculating.

Comment: If you want a real answer for you, hire a lawyer.

Comment: @paqogomez - If you read my question you'd see some lawyers have already been consulted and in their professional opinion SO cannot be used as a resource for commercial products. This is concerning to me and I would like clarification from a representative from Stack Overflow if this is indeed the case.

Comment: If your lawyers say that its not defensible, then either get new lawyers or believe them.  I cant see how a statement from SE would make any difference.  Its those lawyers that are going to have to speak in court.

Comment: @SpencerRuport All user content here is licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0. All users agreed to that. This license makes it pretty clear what you can do with content under that license: If you use it, you have to provide attribution (BY), and offer it under the same or a compatible license (SA = share alike). The SE team cannot redefine this license to mean something more liberal. The legal interpretation you heard (SO code cannot be reasonably used) is correct and generally well-accepted. The Fair Use exception only exists in the US, and is more of a possible legal defense rather than a usage right

Comment: @amon - You could be right. I would just prefer to hear it from SO directly. There has been plenty of speculation and armchair lawyering about this matter. I want to hear from someone who can speak definitively on the matter. Even, as I said earlier, if the answer is "We can't say for sure."

Comment: @paqogomez - They aren't my lawyers. I would like to know if SO intends for their site terms to be interpreted in this way. If not they should clarify their terms.

Comment: By definition the [CC licenses weren't designed for software / source code](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_apply_a_Creative_Commons_license_to_software.3F) licensing. Stack Overflow uses the CC-BY-SA because it's intended as documentation resource, not as code repository. So you won't get an official interpretation on that, in particular not in a generalizable form.

Comment: @mario - And yet, Jeff Atwood did in the past.

Comment: I think what is being asked for here is not for SE to legally interpret the license, but rather for SE to state what their intention was in choosing that license, and to say "Yes, we intend that code from SO Answers cannot be legally used in commercial applications (or applications who's licenses is incompatible with CC-BY-SA)" or "No, we do intend that everyone can use this code for their applications".  Now, it can be argued that choosing the license says what they intend, but I think what Spencer wants is verification that what seems like an oversight was actually intentional.

Comment: The whole problem is CC-BY-CA works great for the plain text, tutorial part of SO, but is abysmally misapplied and confusing when we start talking about code.

Comment: Interpretation of written laws and contracts never means anything in the USA until it is put to the test.  In front of a judge and jury, the decision becomes precedent that will be quoted in future cases.  Nobody yet has been dumb enough to claim a copyright violation on code he posted on SO and make a case out of it.  Nobody will.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Well said. I've added your comment to my post since I think it will clear up some confusion. Also added the word intended to the question title.

Comment: @RubberDuck: There's no problem until people start trying to treat tutorials as if they were debugged, fully ready-to-use code.  You want copy/paste ready code, ask the contributor to license it under a license meant for code.

Comment: Ohhh but how many people *do* copy paste code that isn't production ready @BenVoigt? But I digress...

Comment: @BenVoigt - Have you read the license? It says "remix, transform, and build upon the material". This goes beyond just copy/paste ready code. Copy/paste/edit doesn't release you from the license.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: That's why I said "ask the contributor to license it under a license meant for code".  Read my answer.

Comment: @SpencerRuport, then refer to my original statement.

Comment: @paqogomez - I've edited my question since your comments were posted. I'm interested in whether or not this is the intention of SO because this needs to be addressed. It's naive to think that people aren't copying/pasting/editing code from a Q&A site.

Comment: @Spencer - You now, the thing is, that, for code examples of answerers that are writing the answers in their work time (which I assume many do) and that work in closed-source companies, they likely have no legal right at all to publish anything under any license when they wrote it during their work time. SO the issue is not only that the CC BY-SA poses a question when using the source code, IFF the source code is eligible for copyright, it is highly likely(?) that the individual posting it had no right to post it to begin with. Oh my :-D

Comment: @MartinBa - That's a separate issue. The point is if there is a legal danger in using this SO as a resource then it calls into question the usefulness of the site.

Comment: @MartinBa - Then that makes the poster legally liable, not SE.

Comment: *Related:* [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12527/134300), [What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25956/134300), [I'm worried about Stack Overflow content licensing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3646/134300), [Who owns the intellectual property of answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25125/134300)

Comment: @JeremyBanks - Of those four answers only one of them was weighed in on by someone authorized to speak on behalf of Stack Overflow and as I've pointed out in my question what they said is somewhat unclear.

Comment: @SpencerRuport What we really need isn't *just* an authorized statement, because even if Stack Exchange Inc. decides that people should be allowed to reuse code, as people do, it would be *illegal* for them to encourage that given the existing licensing. They'd need to start dual license the code under a suitable license, and for that you'd need authors to agree - it couldn't be done retroactively. I agree that this is desirable; I just lost all hope years ago. The links provide context for why.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - A public statement on their intention is the first step towards a dialogue that can clear the matter up. At this point we don't even know how they envision visitors using source code on this site.

Comment: Just to let you know: any code samples I put on this site DO NOT comply to SOs own license. Use them in whatever way you want, I really could not give a ****. That license for SO is more about using SOs data itself in external sources. For example if you wanted to use an SO question or something you must abide by rules of reference and linking. I have never known SE employees to chase matters like this and if a user complains just tell them their code is in the public domain "so suck it"

Comment: @Sammaye: Of course they comply. But it's nice of you to grant extra rights.

Comment: Has Stack Overflow made a public statement about this yet?

Comment: @skybluecodeflier - This is the last email I got from them: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288713/52551

Comment: @SpencerRuport: Ok, thanks.

Comment: Is there even a way to tell if code is copy pasted?  Because for many simple tasks, coders using similar conventions (eg camel case, Hungarian notation, etc) very well may write their code separately exactly the same.  Hence even in a scenario wherein there were an infinite amount of time to analyze everyone's code for intellectual property violation, verbatim equivalence would not denote plagiarism.

Comment: @SpencerRuport, *"I have always assumed that the majority of the code I provide in an answer ends up in a commercial closed source product."* Why would you assume that, especially when the license is linked from the bottom of *every single page on Stack Overflow*? Forgive me for cynicism, but your question seems to reduce to, "Why did I fail to read the (commendably respectful and minimal) small print, and then make a false assumption about it?" Only you can answer that.

Comment: @SpencerRuport, you also say, *"The point is if there is a legal danger in using this SO as a resource then it calls into question the usefulness of the site."* No. With copyrighted material generally, if the users of the material follow the license terms, there's no danger. The terms under which SO contributions are licensed allow re-use in a manner respectful to the original author (& the "four freedoms"). Contrary to your assertion, this renders the site *very* useful, as the site's success has shown. Please don't stray into [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt).

Comment: @sampablokuper - It's not FUD. I sat in a meeting room of a very large international corporation which employs a full time legal team and the word we were given is "Do not use Stack Overflow as a resource. Period."

Comment: @SpencerRuport (1) Very large international corporations *never* promulgate FUD? History tells otherwise. False premise => unsound argument. (2) SO has clearly helped *a lot*(TM) of people, so again: false premise => unsound argument. The site manifestly *is* useful. (3) No-one using material from SO in line w/the licensing has been prosecuted for it. (If you know otherwise, please say.) That makes it as safe as any other source that has clear, legally valid licensing terms.

Comment: @sampablokuper - You're not understanding me. When professional lawyers for large businesses do not feel comfortable using a resource due to legal concerns it compromises the usefulness of the resource. *That* is not FUD and that's precisely what was happening.

Comment: @SpencerRuport (4) Demanding that contributors consent to the lowest common denominator license required across *every possible corporate legal team* would be untenable, because we don't know for sure if such a common denominator even exists. Some companies *may* have legally conflicting requirements, e.g. for jurisdictional or other reasons, which is impossible to know without exhaustively surveying them. It would also breach the contributors' moral rights to be identified as the authors of their works; which in some countries might be fine (w/consent), but in others is likely illegal.

Comment: @SpencerRuport, (5) *"When professional lawyers for large businesses do not feel comfortable using a resource due to legal concerns it compromises the usefulness of the resource."* No. The resource has the same total usefulness before and after the lawyers' assessment, because their assessment does not modify the resource. And unless you're a scraper/etc, your business probably shouldn't be predicated on reusing SO code snippets! (However, your situation does perhaps highlight a paucity in the usefulness of those specific lawyers, or those specific businesses. That's a different matter ;) .)

Comment: @sampablokuper - The fact that the moment SE hired in house counsel this change of license followed quickly on it's heels would indicate that there was a definitive problem. At least it does for me. :)

Comment: @SpencerRuport, that's clutching at straws. (1) [Sam Brand's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080) suggests it happened in the reverse order: SO staff felt an unjustified need to wake some sleeping dogs & consulted a lawyer to help them. (2) Even if you're right about order of events, yr conclusion isn't supported by it. (a) Lawyers aren't always right (in court, counsels' arguments are found wrong close to 50% of the time!). (b) Any new employee/contractor has a conflict of interest, & may get the employer to undertake unnecessary work so as not to be seen simply cooling their heels.

Comment: @SpencerRuport the arguments you were presenting earlier read a bit like this: "I believe *every SE should be compelled to wear brogues when they're contributing code*, because my boss (and his in-house counsel!) took me into a meeting and told me that other footwear isn't tolerated at my workplace, and the same thing happened to my friend at a different Very Big Company which means it must be important."

Comment: @sampablokuper - That's not at all what I was saying but I'm not going to try to clarify further. You're being very antagonistic and I don't think any further discussion with you will be constructive. Have a nice day.

Comment: @SpencerRuport, my perspective is that you have been committing a series of logical errors, and I have been pointing them out to you, by way of debunking. I believe that to be a constructive activity, as no-one should be burdened with bunk; moreover, SE users should not have a change imposed upon them based on bunk. I am sorry if that feels antagonistic to you, and as you say it does, I will refrain from replying to you further. (P.S. apologies for the typo in my earlier comment: `s/every SE should/every SE user should/` .)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you [Dreaded semicolon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro/312610?noredirect=1#comment596243_312610) for pointing out that the change I mention in my original answer below seemingly never went into effect as shown in [A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1), which itself is probably the best answer to this question.

---

<strike>https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312598/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code?cb=1</strike>

<strike>And now everything has changed, well, as far as I understand the licence above still applies to code added before <strike>January</strike> <strike>February</strike> March 1st 2016 (that subject to change thing is kicking in already...), but that link says all code after is under the MIT license.</strike>

<strike>Probably subject to change etc. so just go look for yourself.</strike>

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: It's not going to be January 1st.

Comment: For anyone finding this from search.  this didn't go into effect, see the update https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1  and also footer on stackoverflow

Comment: I just downvoted this answer due to lack of updated answer to the OP question. I would appreciate at least a link to an updated answer, such as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300861/1283667.

Answer (score 50):

Early on, I decided that posting my answers in a less restrictive fashion was better. Therefore, [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/) includes:

> All original source snippets I post on Stackoverflow.com, and other sites in the StackExchange network, are dedicated to the public domain. If you do find value in my answers, I would very much appreciate an attribution and acknowledgement where possible.

I understand there are places where the concept of "public domain" doesn't exist, but for the rest of the world, I would like content I offer in the spirit of "hope it helps someone" not to be encumbered by licensing questions.

#### Update

I found the comments pointing to the shortcomings of trying put things in the Public Domain convincing, and decided to instead dual license my answers under the MIT License.

Comment: I like this and will implement it in my profile as well. Honestly, this is what I thought StackOverflow was all about when I joined. Particularly in an answer (but even pertaining to questions from the other direction) how do you post code as an answer to someone's problem and expect them to ***not*** use it?

Comment: @mbm29414: depends what you mean by "use". If I ask a non-programming question on a forum somewhere and want to "use" information from the answer in a commercial work, then I can paraphrase the information I get back in order to avoid copyright concerns (I might consult my lawyer). However, if I copy an answer verbatim then I might well be plagiarising. So, is there something special about code answers that means "use the answer" implies "copying or remixing, for copyright purposes"? If so, then personally I'd worry that I'd asked a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: ... that said, I've had a similar dedication in my user info for years. I do agree that if someone wants to copy my SO answer, I don't care to stop them. I just don't think I generally "use" SO answers by copying code from them. Normally for me the license of SO answers that I find helpful, is more or less irrelevant, because (in my opinion) I'm not using them in a way that requires a license anyway. If I was publishing the question and answer on my own site, or copying code answers into my own code, then I might worry.

Comment: @SteveJessop Which brings up the question of what it means to "[copy] code answers into my own code". How different does it have to be to **not** be copying? If I **do** copy and then tailor it to my needs, when does it "exit" the license?

Comment: I like this approach but I feel like a way to publish the license you select of all your answers should be a feature of the site. This would mean that the license would be in plain view on the answer itself rather than expecting people to go digging in your profile. Something like this: http://i.imgur.com/8LRGKie.png

Comment: Public Domain has its own peculiar set of issues whic sqlite deals with http://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html

Comment: @SpencerRuport I agree with that, but it's very against the "standard" sentiment here of "no signatures". But I think it's a great idea.

Comment: So, Sinan, is it accurate to say that everyone on earth who has used a code snippet of a significant length provided as an answer on SO, ***can*** *be held legally liable if they used the code in a private license, for-profit application?* Unless the owner of the answer has announced something like you did, some user could potentially take legal action against anyone who uses a significant code snippet from one of their answers for profit in a closed source project?

Comment: That's a scary prospect considering SO might be the single most powerful programming problem solving tool on Earth. I'm willing to bet more than a few lines of Stack Overflow code are floating around as solutions in profitable applications around the world. We developers are efficient creatures - if the code works, we'll implement it directly into our applications without any modifications other than a few comments. I guess no one would ever be able to prove that a snippet originated from SO but the mere fact that one could be held legally accountable is not cool to say the least.

Comment: You should never make code "public domain" if you intend to use it yourself for anything.  If it's public domain, it is possible in certain cases for others to claim copyright on it and prevent YOU from using it.  See http://www.wired.com/2012/01/scotus-re-copyright-decision/ for an extreme example. It's always best to have at least  BSD or MIT style license.

Comment: and what stop you from changing this line to "you should never use my code in commercial software" and sue someone in the future? I am not necessarily speaking about you, but mostly what stops any person who writes this to change their statement.

Comment: @MediaWebDev: As far as I can figure, as a non-lawyer, yes "everyone on earth who has used a code snippet of a significant length written by anyone else, might be legally liable for copyright infringement, if they haven't obtained a license permitting that use" and also that liability is significantly higher when related to commercial for-profit usage.  And they might be legally liable for patent infringement, even if they wrote the code themselves.

Comment: @Erik: Also you have a very weird interpretation of that SCOTUS ruling.  It concerns works which were placed in the public domain by law, not by their creators, and when the works were removed from the public domain, the rights went back to the original copyright holders.  Saying that somehow allows a third party to claim copyright and prevent the author from using his work is utter nonsense.  Only a copyright assignment can have that effect.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I said it was an extreme case.  The point is that laws are fluid, and SCOTUS has given congress the right to change copyright whenever they want retroactively on the public domain.  However, this was just the first thing that came up in a search.. other examples are collections, where you can "copyright" collections of public domain works.  Further, even if someone claims copyright on something you put in the public domain, it could be very expensive to litigate otherwise, an explicit license has much more cut and dried terms.

Comment: How about http://unlicense.org/

Comment: Upvoted. Also including this in my profile. I think this should be more standardized in StackOverflow.

Comment: @Nathan, Unlicense seems to be having some problems: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147111/what-is-wrong-with-the-unlicense

Comment: The safest option is probably [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/deed.en) (Creative Commons Public Domain Dedication), which makes your work public domain to the extent allowed by law. Unlike other Creative Commons licenses, CC0 is recommended for software and it's GPL-compatible. (Sources: [Free Software Foundation](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#CC0), [Creative Commons](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F))

Comment: I approve of this idea as well and tries to implement it in my profile.

Comment: @mbm29414 you say, *"how do you post code as an answer to someone's problem and expect them to **not** use it?"* The obvious reply is: by all means expect them to use it, if the license you used permits it; and expect them to do so according to the terms of that license. For example, if you posted to Stack Overflow and have not dual-licensed, then expect them to use it under the terms of [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Simple!

Comment: @sampablokuper IANAL, but the summary on the page you linked even says: "You do not have to comply with the license for elements of the material in the public domain..." And that's kind of my point. Legality aside (and I'm a stickler for my own personal adherence to the law), how can someone rationally expect to post code to StackOverflow and have that code protected in any way? It would seem to require StackOverflow to **not** be public domain. Again, IANAL, but something just isn't adding up. (My comment assumes the code is theirs to post, i.e., that it's original code.)

Comment: @mbm29414, why would anything on any website be in the public domain (in the legal sense)? By default, it absolutely isn't. In most countries in which SO/SE is active, published material is Copyright (C) The Author w/no user rights to reuse the material unless specified otherwise in the national law. That is emphatically *not* public domain. It sounds like what "isn't adding up" is that you have made a false assumption about the (legal) meaning of the term "public domain". Specifically, you appear to be conflating it with "published", which is (legally) an entirely different concept.

Answer (score 41):

IANAL but...

The way I understand the terms of service, Stack Exchange does not claim exclusive ownership of content you submit.  They do not require copyright assignment.  They do require you to make it available under a CC BY-SA license, which allows them to make it available in turn under that same license.

But there is nothing about the terms of service for contributors, nor the CC BY-SA license itself, that stands in the way of a separate agreement between copyright holder (the content author) and another private entity (such as a development shop) that permits use of that same content (maybe a code snippet) under commercially-friendly terms.

If you want to use content from any Stack Exchange site without releasing your derivative work under CC BY-SA, **contact the copyright holder and ask them for permission.**  Be prepared to pay a fee commensurate with the code's value.

And don't expect Stack Exchange to ever try to force contributors into any license that would conflict with their ability to negotiate commercial licenses on their work, at least not to any greater degree than what CC BY-SA already does (by providing a free license that competes with other possibly paid licenses)

Further observation: **The license is what it is, regardless of intent.  Stack Exchange cannot change the license terms** for content without the permission of the copyright holders.  At most they could require a different license for future contributions, but that will never happen either for two reasons:

1. Having some content under one license and some under another would actually be confusing, unlike the current status quo which is merely perceived as complicated by a few.
2. **Mandating a BSD-style license for contributions would drive experts away in droves**.  Not just the ones who believe in the principles of copyleft, but also the ones who believe in others' right to copyleft their contributions.  At a minimum, experts who feel this way would entirely stop including code in their answers, and answer with text only (assuming that text continued to be CC BY-SA and the new license covered only code).

Comment: ++ Yes. It's often forgotten that CC-BY-SA doesn't preclude other licenses.

Comment: I can see the logic in this and it seems reasonable but unfortunately until SO states explicitly that this is their intention this answer is just more speculation.

Comment: @SpencerRuport their intentions are irrelevant. The license is what it is, and no statement from SO will make any difference whatsoever. The copyright remains with the original poster, and if they decide to sue you for violating the terms of the license then that is their right. If you're extremely paranoid note that code posted on this site might be in violation of somebody else's copyright, in which case the original poster may not have the legal right to offer the CC-BY-SA in the first place and you're liable to a much greater degree.

Comment: @SpencerRuport no, everything in this answer is true regardless of StackExchange's intention :)

Comment: You have a good answer but IMVHO this raises the point: you shouldn't have to contact the code author to get permission to use the code in a product (and this has been covered before). By publishing it on SO the intent is for you to use it if it is useful for the stated purpose. cc-by-sa should only apply to republishing the post itself. This sort of uncertainty is why SE need to have an official statement - if you're gonna select and use a license, explain to people exactly what the implications are.

Comment: @MarkRansom - What is the point of a Q&A site if I can't use an answer without contacting the author and receiving explicit consent to use the code provided? If intentional it seems like a pretty irresponsible decision by SO to not make their users *very* aware of the *huge* potential risk they're taking by using SO as a resource.

Comment: @SpencerRuport there are plenty of answers that don't include actual code. And even if they do include code, you're not obligated to use it.

Comment: @MarkRansom - That's not an answer. This is a programming Q&A site. If people are opening themselves up to legal troubles by using it as such they should be made aware of this fact.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: You have a false dichotomy there.  It is not either (A) copy/paste from answers or (B) don't use Stack Overflow.  There is (C) read and learn from answers and write your own code, which is the intention of the site and the CC BY-SA license works just fine for that purpose.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: Also, why should Stack Exchange go to any special lengths to remind users that copy/paste is in violation of copyright unless there is a license that specifically allows it?  This is an issue that programmers have to deal with when they find any code on the Internet, or even in printed books.  It is not unique to Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Responding to both your comments here, if a user comes across an answer to a question they have with 30 lines of code what do you think is going to happen? 1) The user immediately contacts the author of the answer requesting to use said code and waits for a response? 2) The user manually types out their own code which is mostly identical to the answer? 3) The user copies the code, pastes it into their source code and tweaks it for their needs?

Comment: @SpencerRuport: 4) The user reads the explanation, realizes that they've used the wrong calculation for one function parameter, checks the 30 lines of code in the question to see how it should have been done, sees that they've completely forgotten to set another property, and fixes their own attempt by changing only two lines

Comment: @SpencerRuport: Remember that StackOverflow is not a code hosting service.  It is a Q&A site hosting explanations, and the code merely illustrates the explanations.

Comment: @BenVoigt - That is not always the case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1176255/52551

Comment: The claim that just because you don't copy and paste, you're not infringing copyright is *as speculative* as the claim that code-copying cannot be fair use. The US has the standard of [substantial similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantial_similarity), which states that if a work appropriates another's "the fundamental structure or pattern" it may infringe copyright even if nothing was copied verbatim. Any time you do any substantial task *foo* aided by a "How do I do foo?" post on Stack Overflow, you are potentially infringing. Fair use may be all that protects you. I dunno; IANAL.

Comment: I have never, NEVER seen usable code on a SO answer.  That said, with some tweaks/changes, it is all quite usable.  The idea that changing the code could still put you in copyright trouble is technically true, if you are infringing on a patent, but generally it is complete nonsense.  In fact many patents are violated this way without any consequence, and many common, obvious software algorithms are granted patents despite the frivolity of it.  The comments discouraging people from reinterpreting answers are akin to saying one should never drive a car because you open yourself up to litigation.

Comment: @Mark, it's definitely true that Spencer's "The user manually types out their own code which is mostly identical to the answer" has just as much potential for infringement as copy/paste.  But Darren's right that the bigger risk if the code is significantly modified is of patent violation.  Anyway, to use someone else's work, you need a license.  Either from the content owner, or from the govt (such as "Fair Use").  Since content on StackExchange sites is no exception to this global rule, there's no special duty for Stack Exchange, Inc. to "clarify" it.

Comment: @DarrenRinger, I've seen some usable code in SO answers. It's probably more common in functional languages than OO.

Comment: @BenVoigt - It would be naive of Stack Overflow to think that the majority of users that end up here looking for a code snippet contact the author requesting permission to use it before pasting it into their source. Especially since the SO website offers no clear way to do that. Should you ask in a comment?

Comment: @Spencer: If the author isn't providing contact information in their publicly available profile, then yes, a comment would be appropriate.  For those uses where CC BY-SA isn't enough.  And commenting, even though restricted to users with 50 rep, is still a much more convenient way of contacting the owner than you'll find accompanying most code.

Comment: "And commenting, even though restricted to users with 50 rep" this isn't a practical solution.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: Too bad.  The site, and its chosen license, is built for sharing answers, not for sharing code.  You come demanding that it needs to share code, and what you are going to hear is "too bad".  Modify your expectations.  When you want to share code, post (a copy of) it on github or wherever, with the license specified, and leave a link in your answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt - You speak as one with authority when you have none. :) Also I never made any such demands.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: I'm just paraphrasing what those in authority have already said, many times.  Here's one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270813/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt - I just think it's interesting how you chose to paraphrase it in the most dismissive tone you could muster.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Your argument has a number of flaws.  Your argument "why should Stack Exchange go to any special lengths to remind users that copy/paste is in violation of copyright" flies in the fact that SE goes to great length to prevent other kinds of copyright violation (linking to pirated ebooks or sites that provide them, for instance).  They also do not allow questions and answers primarily intended for copyright infringement purposes (hacking, etc..).  I would argue that SE has an inherent responsibility to protect users, since it "enables" users to violate copyright without knowledge.

Comment: @BenVoigt - especially since it would be extremely easy for SE to provide a disclaimer (and no, hidden in the ToS does not really count, particularly when it flies in the face of the assumed use of the site) on each post (even a link to said disclaimer).  Other sites even go so far as to have users select a license they wish to associate with their submissions, and have that license visible on each submission.  I'm not suggesting that SE needs to go that far, but it seems clear that the copyright reality is contradictory to the presumed purpose of the site.

Comment: @Erik: You are aware that a link to *exactly the plain English explanation asked for* is in the footer on every single page, right?  It's not just "hidden" in the Terms of Service.  That is making the license visible on each and every submission, and also serves notice that the material is copyright.  Heck, it even uses the copyright symbol.

Comment: @MarkAmery: "substantial similarity" is not relevant if the similarity is caused by external constraints. In many of the cases here, the surrounding code acts as those constraints. In fact, we often see that those external constrains are tight enough that we have to argue whether there's any degree of creativity left that can be protected under copyright law. E.g. you typically cannot be creative in passing the parameters in the right order to a function. All callers of that function will be substantially similar without it being a copyright violation.

Comment: "Mandating a BSD-style license for contributions would drive experts away in droves." is the only part of this answer that is questionable. It's only an opinion and I don't think SO would just stop working and for example Matlab Central does it like this. So in order to really be useful one could seriously think about a BSD style license, so everyone can profit in every possible way from the knowledge (as it is now already). Typically nobody thinks alot about the license when visiting SO, so why not adapting licenses to reality and make it BSD or PD. Simple and clean and useful solution.

Comment: @trilarion I didn't say that all experts would leave, or that the ones who remain would be too few to be viable. But the community would be a lot smaller.

Comment: @BenVoigt Maybe, although I do not quite believe it. There would be no practical difference. Already now everyone just takes all the knowledge that is available from here and uses it with or without attribution and for commercial or non-commercial projects. The used license is not really regarded as a real obstacle, because with a bit of rewriting you can always obscure the origin. Then why not giving away your knowledge for free and adopt BSD or PD, if that's anyway what happens even now?

Comment: @Trilarion: Now you're conflating code with knowledge.  You don't need a license to apply the knowledge you learn while reading StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, this answer is now distressingly dated, since several of the things that were confidently asserted would never come about are now being seriously proposed. (Whether the answer, or the [present situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange), is the more distressing is of course open to some debate.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Well, there's no change to the ramifications of instituting a different license on future content, it just appears that Stack Overflow (the company, not the site) doesn't care about the negative aspects as much as I thought they would.  On the other hand, they've already shown that they have no interest in actually allowing contributors to reap the benefits the current license promises, so I'm no longer surprised.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Although, no one seems to be particularly worried by the fact that the proposal to use the MIT license omits the usual BSD language of "Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.".  Since we had that protection with CC BY-SA (see clause 4-c near the end), that's a significant change.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hmm, yeah, I'm not sure why that hasn't gotten much attention.

Answer (score 22):

IANAL but...

Most of the code on SE sites is so limited and resides in such massively independent snippets isolated from their originating problems that they can hardly be considered unique works of their own.

For example, if you asked how to check for some value in a file in PowerShell, take advantage of function pattern matching in Erlang, avoid NULLs in SQL table definitions, implement dispatch functions to create OOP objects in Scheme, take advantage of virtual functions in C++ class definitions, or any of the other bajillion or so basic questions out there you are almost certain to receive an answer that illustrates its point by way of a *short one-off example*, not a complete program that performs some unique and useful function.

What I am saying is, snippets are both probably not considered "works" and, most importantly, they are *not unique at all*. The exact same code is almost certainly written and rewritten thousands of times per day, because example *answer code is almost always examples of generally accepted idioms*.

With this in mind, is it plagiarism to use phrases like "don't get ahead of yourself", or quote a common programming aphorism that has appeared on this site? Of course not, because they are idiomatic expressions of common ideas.

More extensive code, of course, may introduce licensing questions, but *most* of the code on SO is isolated snippets or one-off examples of idioms. In any case, SO's encouragement of replication of "the relevant bits" of linked information introduces some interesting questions pointed the other direction, especially when code is involved.

Comment: Does this mean we could prohibit people to post (and answer) long fix-it-for-me code dumps *on legal grounds*!? That'd be fantastic! ;o)

Comment: @deceze That would be pretty insane. OTOH most of the DMCA is even worse. I think it comes down to whether anyone would actually try enforcing any of this. An employer may forbid an employee to post any code (or "derivative works") in a question (rendering questions useless), and the stated SO policy seems to actually forbid inclusion of any significant works here in closed-source derivatives (rendering answers unusable). It is amazing how quickly things get stupid once we try to project a sense of individual morality onto a group, even when everyone has the best of intentions.

Comment: @zxq9: Please stop pretending the only "use" of an answer is to copy/paste from it.

Comment: @BenVoigt That was the focus of the question when it was written originally, so that is what I addressed. I don't see how snark adds anything to the discussion.

Comment: @zxq9: No, I'm serious.  Being the topic under discussion, and being the *only* use are entirely different things.  If it is the only use, and we assume that StackOverflow is meant to be useful, then it follows that StackOverflow is meant for copy/paste.  But because there are other uses, it's entirely possible for the intention to be "don't use code in your own projects, ever, it is there only as a repeatable demonstration that an answer is correct".  Of course, the reality is somewhere in between.

Comment: Wow... srsly. I never even implied that the only "use of an answer" was to copy/paste it, I simply addressed the question directly. Last time I try answering something on meta; I've got other stuff to do with my time.

Comment: @zxq9: Sorry, then I guess I don't understand what you meant by "forbid inclusion of any significant works here in closed-source derivatives (rendering answers unusable)" in your comment to deceze.

Answer (score 19):

I received a response from Stack Exchange.

> Spencer,
>
> Sorry we haven't been able to give you more help. More sorry that I still can't add much helpful info. Giving a response that I know is not solving someone's need is about as unsatisfying as this job gets.
>
> I checked back with the folks who liaise with legal, and confirmed that for the time being, they don't think it's legally fair to our users to try to interpret what we think the license means or what we might intend: the license speaks for itself. More specifically, I'm told folks who deal with legal issues are following up on some of the questions that have been raised in the hopes of being able to be more helpful, but we don't have in house counsel, so it could realistically be a month or two before we can offer up a better answer than that the license should speak for itself. As a non-lawyer, I know it's often not that simple.
>
> In any case, sorry I can't offer more info for now, and thanks for your patience!
>
> The Stack Exchange Team

I have responded with another email.

> Well I appreciate the response but the fact is Jeff Atwood has already interpreted what he (and by association Stack Exchange) thinks the license means or what you might intend. Every time this topic comes up people reference his answer.
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25957/131570
>
> I agree that what's fair for the users is of high importance. So do the people who are responsible for this kind of thing SE believe that this conflicting information is fair to it's users? Perhaps this answer should be removed?

Comment: The thing that makes this hard to interpret is that that's his **personal** account. Not an "[official company account](https://www.quora.com/Huffington-Post/)".

Comment: @Pacerier - In his answer he says "We're not sourceforge, github, or codeplex." He's not speaking from a personal perspective.

Comment: But it's highly likely to be regarded as a personal comment in courts. At the minimum it'll need to be signed off *"The Stack Exchange Team"* or equivalent, like what you have in your email.

Comment: @Pacerier - I'm not a lawyer so I won't speak to that. I'm saying that's not how it is interpreted by the many SO users who read it.

Comment: *"we don't have in house counsel, so it could realistically be a month or two before we can offer up a better answer than that the license should speak for itself"* So, um, anything new from them to report?

Comment: @ruffin - Silence. I even sent Joel an email.

Comment: @SpencerRuport Hey Spencer I feel for you. I asked a [similar question before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253618/if-i-use-so-code-on-my-website-how-should-i-give-attribution) . I think my "dream solution" would be some kind of email blast to SO users encouraging them to choose a license to mark their code. It'd be listed on their profile, whether they do/don't require attribution, etc. One hairly aspect would be if users willy nilly start changing their licensing. For instance, there would need to be warnings like "code submitted to public domain cannot be revoked" etc. etc.

Comment: @D.Tate - I just think outright refusing to clarify their intents flies directly in the face of "making the internet a better place". I've simply stopped answering questions for this and other reasons.

Comment: @SpencerRuport Well I commend you for trying anyway. I guess if we really wanted to make our voice heard, nothing is stopping us from making a petition or something. lol. I might be down for that. Otherwise this request may just not really be heard. fwiw, sometimes I ask ppl to use their code, like in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php/834355?noredirect=1#comment49409228_834355) . But it is cumbersome and kinda goofy. Best of wishes

Comment: [Check this out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312598/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code?cb=1) Spencer! I'm excited about this .. still need to re-read it, but it looks like SO really has been paying attention to this issue! yay

Answer (score 15):

Glad this came back up.

#### [Even the CC says not to use CC for software](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/FAQ#Can_I_use_a_Creative_Commons_license_for_software.3F):

> We recommend against using Creative Commons licenses for software.
> Instead, we strongly encourage you to use one of the very good
> software licenses which are already available. We recommend
> considering licenses made available by the Free Software Foundation or
> listed as “open source” by the Open Source Initiative.

I take this to mean that SO licensing is broken.

In the meanwhile...

#### Make licensing of your code explicit yourself

One way to "fix" this personally is to dual (or more) license your own code, though it's often hard to do properly, especially when you're building on, say, code from an OP. But for code that's yours, it's very easy to add licenses in addition to the CC license SO demands. Unlicense it (or MIT or whatever you'd like) *in addition to* CC-ing while SO tries to figure this out.

I'm trying this snippet:

> You're also welcome to take any code snippet I've sole-source posted
> on StackOverflow.com and consider it to be dual-licensed under the
> [Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/) as written on July 8th, 2014 for you, and as a rights
> reserved copyrighted source when I use it in other projects.

I've heard some well-meaning comments that I can't dual license my code. Well, of course I can! If it's my own, closed source, nothing's stopping me from posting a snippet of it to SO. Even though that snippet is now CC'd too, nothing's stopping me (IANAL) from continuing to use that snippet in my own, closed source code. It's not exclusively CC licensed; it's *also* CC licensed.

Same with Unlicensing -- you can still treat this as CC'd, but you're also welcome to take the same code that I concurrently released under the Unlicense as well.

If SO thinks it has a right to un-Unlicense my code posted on SO, I'd like to hear it, though I can't see any reason they'd want to. It might be useful for them to denounce any CC copyright interest they have in source code snippets.

Honestly, though, it's time for SO to rip off the band-aid. I realize old answers would be licensed differently. There's nothing aside from asking active users to re-license sole-sourced or derivative works differently once they log in that you can do about that. But not doing anything for so long just forces us all to apply the ill-suited CC license to more quality (and not so quality) code.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that it would be really nice for someone retained by Stack Exchange to give us an easily readable break down of the application and ramifications of cc-by-sa.

It's incredibly easy to read, but when you sit and think you very quickly come up with complexities:

- is the compiled version of some source covered under the *remix, transform, or build upon* phrase?
- does compiling some source and then distributing it to others who never see the source meet the definition of a *contribution*?
- when I offer some source code on Stack Overflow it is done without expectation of payment or credit, does cc-by-sa trump my intentions?
- if I use a snippet from Stack Overflow I will include a reference link back to the Stack Overflow post, and all Stack Overflow pages have the cc-by-sa link at the bottom. Is this sufficient attribution?
- a lot of what is covered on Stack Overflow could be described as knowledge that a competent developer could be reasonably expected to know or arrive at under their own effort (i.e. how to call some API method), is it reasonable to apply any sort of license to this more generic and reproducible knowledge?
- Jon Skeet, Marc Gravell or [Simon André Forsberg](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1310566/simon-andr%C3%A9-forsberg) publish a specialized class on Stack Overflow - what is the impact of using that class in a closed source commercial application?
- is cc-by-sa intended to only cover publication of the written word (i.e. web pages or books or public source code repositories)?

That's just scratching the surface. It is unlikely that the answers will have much influence on my modest contributions to the site as they are done without expectation of anything except maybe some magical unicorn points.

Stack Overflow is a great tool for the working professional. But I think the creators of complex and powerful tools have a moral duty to provide some guidance about using it. If I use a shovel I need to know that I can hit an underground cable or pipe if I dig a hole. But if I use a pneumatic drill to do the same job I have a whole different set of considerations, and the manufacturer will provide me with a handbook explaining them.

While some of the information relating to the application of cc-by-sa can be googled, it would be great if that could be aggregated in one spot right here. Members shouldn't have to search for the information, nor should they have to interpret how it applies to their specific type of contribution. If after analysis we find that the license is detrimental to the operation of Stack Overflow (i.e. members do not like it so they stop contributing) then it should be possible to come up with a site specific variation that better suits the SO model.

Comment: Why mention "Jon Skeet or Marc Gravell" specifically? How would using a class that they wrote be any different from using a class someone else wrote?

Comment: That is not an answer, but an unnecessarily long comment. Also, most of your questions can be trivially answered. A compiled representation of a program is still that program – original licenses apply. Whether or not you contribute to the work is irrelevant for CC-BY-SA 3.0. Unless you explicitly offer a more permissive license, CC-BY-SA applies to your contributions – users cannot assume any intentions of yours. Merely attributing a snippet is not sufficient, since SA=“Share Alike” requires derivatives to also use CC-BY-SA or compatible licenses. […]

Comment: […] Knowledge is not copyrightable, but creative works such as non-trivial programs are. Blatantly copying code is a copyright violation, independently arriving at the same solution is not (but it's difficult to prove violations for trivial code). Code published on SO cannot be reasonably used unless it's also available under a more suitable license. CC-BY-SA is intended for any creative work, but is not very suitable for code. In the end, CC-BY-SA isn't meant to be creatively interpreted by potential code copy-pasters or by the SE team. It's meant to be adhered to.

Comment: Welcome to Meta @amon, this certainly is an answer. The point is that Stack Exchange need to publish an official explanation of the licence. Your comments contain good material, but that knowledge needs to be aggregated in easily reachable one spot. This topic has been brought up repeatedly in the past and we still have no conclusion. No developer should have to google this stuff, just like I shouldn't have to google for the handbook for my pneumatic drill.

Comment: @amon Even if you put your material into an answer, up votes from the community do not represent endorsement from Stack Exchange - hence why an official publication from them is desirable.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg You are right. I simply used them because many members will instantly recognize them due to their many excellent contributions to the site. A new user could be equally capable of writing and publishing specialized *Foo* class but they wouldn't be as good for the example I was making. But I suspect you knew that. In any case I've included you in the example so that we don't get side tracked over inconsequential details.

Comment: compilation clearly falls under the "transform" point

Answer (score 8):

Pretend that you google for some topic, and find 10 lines of relevant example on some random website, with no particular license. Or, equivalently, no reliable chain of provenance to show that any license was actually applied by the person who owns the copyright, if any. What would you do?

Well, if you are at work, you should do what your particular corporate legal people want you to do. Some would tell you '10 lines is not enough to make a work protected by copyright law.' Some would tell you to get out the long tongs and deposit those ten lines behind radioactive shielding -- to learn from them and then write your own.

If google brought you here, the situation is only slightly different. Yes, there's a license. But there's no guarantee that the person who put the code in the box did, in fact, have the right to publish it there, under CC-xxx or anything else. Your particular legal department may shrug and say, '10 lines isn't enough to have a copyright', or '10 lines isn't enough to worry about.' Or, they could give instructions about long tongs. SE can't change this, unless they want to become (e.g.) the Apache Software Foundation and require that all people that post code sign an agreement promising to only post code that they actually have rights to license. I don't see that happening.

Comment: It would be naive to think that the majority of people who end up here through a google search are contacting authors asking to use code before copying it into their source.

Comment: True, but where does my answer talk about contacting any authors?

Comment: 10 lines describing an hitherto unpublished algorithm can make a work be protected by copyright law. But yeah, in general I would not copy but slightly alter the code from SO and actually even not attribute it - that way it will be hard to prove that it was taken from here. May be counteracting the attribution idea though. But better not to take a risk of being accused of stealing. If of course my projects is compatible with CC-BY-SA than I can attribute readily. Or maybe as a compromise I could say that I got inspired by SO and a particular answer (way to give credit without commiting).

Comment: @Trilarion: If it is a novel and non-obvious method, it might even be patentable (I think the rule still is up to one year after disclosure).  But yeah, attribution is where my moral compass is pointing, and if anyone contacts me to ask for permission to use my work posted here, due credit is all I'm likely to ask for.

Comment: @bmargulies, "lines" of code? So is a standing `{` and `}` considered one line? What about a one statement array declaration split into 50 "lines" for clarity?

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, I'm not a lawyer either. But:

I see StackOverflow as a kind of book. Yes, copying the book verbatim is forbidden, but learning from the book and using what I learned in closed source business applications is *the point* of me buying and reading the book.

The same goes for SO: apart from homework assignments, I don't think anybody here professionally develops applications that are so simple that a StackOverflow snippet will satisfy the business requirement. So if I have a question and get a good answer, I paste the answer into my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is not production quality code anyway. I will then learn how the problem can be solved in this sandbox and only then will I use my newfound knowledge to solve the actual problem.

Does the code look similar? You bet. I mean there is not much creative freedom of expression when signing an XML document in C# for example. If done correct, all codes will look strikingly similar. But that does not mean that one guy posted it on StackOverflow and now people are no longer allowed to sign XML files.

**TL;DR**

If you copy from SO verbatim, you and your lawyer really deserve each other. Because good developers don't do that anyway. Developing an application is more than just copy&paste. Learning from the examples here and implementing *the ideas* behind the sample code in your own application is the point of this site.

Comment: As I pointed out, this question has 1.3 million views: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144 Do you think the code in the answer has been copied?

Comment: @SpencerRuport,  It had just been ;)

Comment: I fear I fail to see how to practically apply this answer in many cases. Often, questions are not so much about an *idea* or a *method* per se, but about what part of a library to invoke and how to format its argument values. In such cases, there is no *underlying idea*, and any variation possible is merely superficial (e.g. assigning a value to a variable before passing it instead of passing it directly). Either, the code is copied verbatim (possibly with the aforementioned superficial, hence meaningless changes), or it doesn't work. To be explicit here: "I don't think anybody here ...

Comment: ... professionally develops applications that are so simple that a StackOverflow snippet will satisfy the business requirement" - in the age of reusable components and complex library APIs, yes, solutions to problems are, in many cases, indeed very much "so simple".

Comment: If it's no about ideas or method, then it's not copyrightable anyway. There is no way I post "int i = 0;" somewhere and somehow nobody else may use it. In Germany that would be called "Schöpfungshöhe", in anglo-saxon countries there may be a different term. Compare it to a book. I own the Petzold, I'm still able to program in Windows, though he probably described every single API.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, the CC-BY-SA license was chosen to allow re-publishing of questions and answers by others, so long as they credited the original source/authors and did not alter this published license.

But, publishing (as in re-printing, copying the original text verbatim, etc..) is not the same thing as using that code in your application, and I don't think it was the intention for this license to apply to that.  I think it was intended that Fair Use would allow the code from answers and questions to be usable in developers code, but this ignores the thorny problem that Fair Use is not a universal concept.

Perhaps SE needs a "source code license" in addition to a "publishing license".  However, since i'm not a lawyer, I can't say whether having two licenses, one more permissive for source code.. would provide a loophole for the more restrictive license for re-publishing.

Comment: Code posted to StackOverflow needs a source code license... but that is not for StackExchange, Inc. to dictate.  It's up to each contributor to choose a source code license for code in their answers, or keep their rights reserved (except that they have granted a CC BY-SA license, which as you have noted, isn't supportive of use of answers as code, only as documentation)

Comment: Argueing about the most probable intention of something is often counterproductive in legal discussions. It's better to only take into account what has been written down and assume the worst case (very limited Fair Use). That way one should always be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*warning:  IANAL*</sup>

It makes sense to sit down with your legal department and enumerate what the actual ramifications would be of a developer **blatantly copying and pasting code** from Stack Overflow and placing it into the proprietary code base.  At the very least, I would expect the legal department to agree with your observations; the CC-By-SA wants you to redistribute under the same license if you've modified it, and if you're modifying the code to suit your needs, I could see the rub.

The beauty of code, though, is that more than one person has arrived at that solution, and there is more than one approach to take when writing some specific piece of functionality.

My personal concern would be that of the people wholesale copying the code into their project and believing that it'd just work, **which is *bad*** for reasons too numerous to enumerate here.  From a legal stance, I could see why the legal team of the corporation would be justified in what they're saying.  At the very least, it demonstrates that they're conscious of the licensing of various tidbits of code, and that they're trying to do the ethical thing when it comes to using it (or not).

Comment: I cannot understand why this answer was downvoted. IANAL but it seems that strictly speaking the code published on SO cannot be readily used in a commercial project which does not also use CC-BY-SA. You would need at least another license from the author. So one could in principle sue companies using code from SO that do not have gathered the necessary rights to do so. This answer should have more upvotes.

Comment: I haven't seen IANAL before. Does it mean "I Am Not A Lama"? "I Am Not A Lawyer"? It's the second one, isn't it?

Comment: ["I am not a laywer."](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/I/IANAL.html)

Comment: There are plenty of useful non-trivial code snippets in StackOverflow that will compile and run without modification. I think it's OK to put code snippets into proprietary code bases, but I would appreciate a knowledgeable explanation for why it's OK, and how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I wish that StackOverflow used a better clearer license for source code contributions, like the MIT license. Or I wish they would give examples of how they believe we can abide by the CC BY-SA license.

Here is my best attempt at how to copy source code from StackOverflow and abide by the license. If anyone (especially a lawyer) sees a problem with how I'm doing this, I'd appreciate hearing from you.

Put a comment like the following above the copied code:

```
// The class below was written by StackOverflow user John Leidegren and is licensed
//  under CC BY-SA 3.0 ( http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ ).
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/4634505/386091
```

Here are the key points that I see from the [full text](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) of this license:

- Section 4(a): include the URL to the license.
- Section 4(c)(i): give credit to the original author, by name or pseudonym.
- Section 4(c)(iii): give a URL to the SO source code. (If the source code is in an answer, use the 'share' button on the answer to get a perma-link.)
- Section 3(b): If you make any changes to the source code, add a comment saying "The original code has been modified."
- Section 4(c)(ii): If the source code came from the question itself, put the title of the SO question in the comment.

I think that's it, as far as what you have to do.

I would argue that the copied source code is being added to a Collection in your software project, from the viewpoint of this license. That means that the copied source code is under the CC BY-SA license, but the rest of your source code is unaffected.

I think that copied source code also becomes an Adaptation when compiled to machine code, because the license says in Section 1(a) that translations from one language to another (e.g., English to French) count as an Adaptation. So, the one little bit of the executable would be covered by this license. Section 4(b) says that you have to link to the license as part of every "performance" (meaning when the copied code executes) but that's just not possible with most bits of code; you can't display a message "the code that is executing right now is covered by CC BY-SA" in the nanoseconds it takes most code snippets to run! I don't think you have to describe the copied code in credits, if your software has a list of credits, unless you do it for all code snippets from SO, because Section 4(c) says that you only have to make a listing in the credits if you list *all* contributing authors.

Comment: Your argument hinges on the classification of source-code as a Collection (which gets you out of Section 4(b).  However it's unclear to me that this license would view source-code as a Collection rather than an Adaptation, based upon the definitions provided.  In particular, "derivative works" are classed as Adaptations, the examples provided of Collection 'elements' are all things that are capable of standing on their own (which code snippets _don't_), and the license points out that combining audio with video creates an Adaptation.

Comment: ...the argument you're making is something that a court would have to weigh in on, but personally I'm very doubtful that they'd agree that source code is a Compilation of snippets, as you suggest.  Established legal doctrine would lean much more heavily towards viewing code (and in particular, compiled binaries built from code) as derivative works and therefore as an Adaptation.  And to be clear, it's the _entire_ binary that counts as an Adaptation, not just the particular bits of machine code that came from the snippet.  And your entire Adaptation can only be distributed under CC-BY-SA.