# Best practice for using code snippets from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, code

Is there a best practice for reusing code snippets from Stack Overflow in production code?

Personally I always do something like this:

```
// Handling input that is not parseable as an integer.
// Courtesy of greyfade (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655685/2947592)
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Some related questions come to mind:

- Is it perhaps wiser omit the contribution with regards to unclear issues with the licence (see [Can we get some explicit clarification on the *intended* legal usage of code from SO answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro))
- Is this contribution good enough?
- Does a 1-line code snippet even warrant a contribution?
- Should Stack Overflow offer a standard copy-paste template to make it easier to use proper attribution? ("Click here to use this code")

Comment: wow - does meta have drive by downvote issues all the time?  The only few times I have been here, anything I say seems to immediately get downvoted.

Comment: @Tommy Review the [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) section of the help center.

Comment: [Who knows?](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_apply_a_Creative_Commons_license_to_software.3F)

Comment: Thanks - I get it.  However, downvoting without attempting to foster the discussion the FAQ mentions seems fruitless :)

Comment: @JeremyBanks - LOL, even the basic legalese in some of these licenses is rediculous!

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question is apparently considered off-topic?

Comment: If you were to make a feature-request of the "Click here to use this code" bit I would most certainly vote for it. Otherwise, generally Meta doesn't dispense legal advice.

Answer (score 2):

According to the site [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), all content is licenses under [Creative Commons Attribution-Share alike license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

This [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) article helps explain a little bit around the license as well as states that [proper attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) is required.