# Do I need to license my code under GPL if I use code from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, code, legal, licensing, creative-commons

From [the licensing page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing):

> Content contributed on or after 2018-05-02 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).

When I looked on the Creative-Commons page describing the license, I found the following:

> **ShareAlike** — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the [same license](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses) as the original.

In the [list of compatible licenses](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses), BY-SA, ported versions of it, free art license and GPLv3 are allowed:

> - BY-SA 4.0, or a later version of the BY-SA license.

- Ported versions of the BY-SA license (if any), version 4.0 or later
- A license designated as a “BY-SA Compatible License” as defined in BY-SA 4.0.

  - Free Art License: The [Free Art license 1.3](http://artlibre.org/licence/lal/en/) was declared a “BY-SA–Compatible License” for version 4.0 on 21 October 2014. See the full [analysis](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/ShareAlike_compatibility:_FAL) and [comparison](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/ShareAlike_compatibility_analysis:_FAL) for more information.
  - GPLv3: The [GNU General Public License version 3](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) was declared a “BY-SA–Compatible License” for version 4.0 on 8 October 2015. Note that compatibility with the GPLv3 is one-way only, which means you may license your contributions to adaptations of BY-SA 4.0 materials under GPLv3, but you may not license your contributions to adaptations of GPLv3 projects under BY-SA 4.0. Other [special considerations](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/ShareAlike_compatibility:_GPLv3#Considerations_for_adapters_applying_the_GPLv3) apply. See the full [analysis](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/ShareAlike_compatibility:_GPLv3) and [comparison](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/ShareAlike_compatibility_analysis:_GPL) for more information.

I saw [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321291/10871900) asking if the CC BY-SA license

> According to [Stack Overflow TOS section 6](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) code posted on StackOverflow falls under CC-BY-SA, now [CC BY-SA 4.0 (International)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) (was [CC BY-SA 3.0 Unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) according to [this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro) and [this post by Sebastian Baltes](http://empirical-software.engineering/blog/so-snippets-in-gh-projects)).

As of this answer, it seems that anyone using code from stackoverflow needs to license it in one of the few licenses defined.

I also found [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286582/10871900).

So, **do I need to license my code with one of those licenses if I use code parts from stackoverflow or is attribution sufficient?**

Does this still apply if I just copy the idea of how the code works and reimplement it?