# Is "your" code really yours?

Tags: discussion, questions, plagiarism

We know Stack Overflow has a high standard regarding plagiarism in the answers. However, I believe it falls short when it comes to the questions.

Every now and then I see a question where OP says *"here is my code"*, but "their" code is just a verbatim copy of some original code (I often recognise the copied code or I know the author of the copied code). Because of my scientific/academic background those copies without attribution really annoy me.

What is the consensus here, if any? Should we:

- Leave a comment to OP, like *"hey, mate, please reference the author"*;
- Edit the question with the due reference;
- Flag the question as plagiarism;
- Do nothing and move on.

It seems to me that as long as the question is on-topic the consensus is *"do
  nothing and move on"*... but I hope I'm wrong here.

---

<sup>EDIT: Since this question has gained considerable attention let me explain what I mean by *“copy”*: I’m not talking about one-liners or just a couple of methods, I’m talking about copying a full, working code: I’m active in the d3.js community, in which OP normally shares the entire code for creating a data visualisation. By entire I mean the **whole** thing, from the opening `<script>` tag to the closing `</script>` tag. Those codes are often copied ipsis litteris (comments included) from books or tutorials about D3.
To better put it, as brilliantly explained in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380687/is-your-code-really-yours?noredirect=1#comment674193_380758), this is not a *"question about who technically owns the code, whether it's you or your employer. It's not just a semantic issue about the definition of 'my'. It's a rather clear-cut case of directly copy-pasting code that someone else has created, and failing to provide proper attribution, in flagrant violation of our rules"* (Gray, 2019).</sup>

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375761/how-to-handle-code-clones-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Are you sure users use "_my_" in context of "ownership" rather than "usage"? Might they have copied from someone else, they are likely to make changes to it to adapt to their needs, hence they ask about _their_ code rather than the original one. Myself I would refer to whatever code I _use_ as _my_ code because I try to use it in _my_ project. However I usually mention "I am using XXX plugin/library/etc" first if that's the case.

Comment: @lolbas Yes, what you mentioned happens sometimes. But the cases I'm talking about (I'll refrain from giving some examples here, to avoid the meta effect) are normally dozens of lines of code without a single different comma, including the author's comments. I understand that several of those OPs, normally new contributors, are not ill-intentioned and they use *"my code"* meaning "usage", not "ownership"... but it is still plagiarism and OPs, even if new contributors, should be aware of that.

Comment: Yes. I print code out and type it over. It's mine.

Comment: I think if the question contains dozens of lines of copypasted code, it likely needs to go away regardless of plagiarism.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado  I'm surprised after stating your academic/scientific background that you so quickly go soft on anything but long exact copies.  It does not matter.  If you take someone else's code and change it and use it for "your" (i.e. "my") purposes, the original basis of that code should still be referenced and given due credit.  *There is no need to distinguish between many lines of exact code, or just a a single line which was altered.*  Just because this is outside academics, the coding community should be held to the same standard of proper attribution and usage for any copying.

Comment: @CPerkins: If a single line of code has been copied and then modified without attribution, how are we supposed to even know it's plagiarized, much less prove that to take action on it? That's impractical. Sure, the original poster has an ethical duty (although I'm not terribly convinced of the ethical duty to attribute `count[i++]++;` or something similarly minor), but that's not something we can in all cases hope to enforce.

Comment: @CPerkins I know, I just got "soft" because of the comments here claiming that OP may have just a one-liner, or that OP is just refactoring the code for their purposes etc... So, leaving these cases aside, I'm just remembering people here that we have cases of questions with ipsis litteris copy of long, complete codes. That being said, I'm trying to change the focus of the discussion from single-lines and simply methods (which is quite complex and debatable) to the whole, verbatim copies, which is clearly plagiarism by any measure.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  It's a matter of separating principle from practice.  I only commented because I was not addressing how one-liners should be handled.  I was only pointing out that we shouldn't have to soften the principle just because there are those which don't understand/respect these ideas.  I did not claim any particular action for these cases, but the principle remains that even small amount of code should be held to the same basic principle.  A thorough answer would therefore address both such short code snippets along with longer snippets.

Comment: Pretty sure the `[CSS]` community would riot over this post if it were to be actually enforced. ["How to horizontally center a <div>?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div) - no changes required just copy pasta and win.

Comment: If an employee shows you his contract and says "this is my contract" would you accuse him of plagiarism because the company wrote it?

Comment: Yeah depends what kind of code, sometimes person has a function say which has code from here another code from there etc. I don't think one should expect him/her to list all the sources. Because in the end how you combine that code, that is yours.

Comment: I've never been in the situation but what about when part of the code is GPL'd? Doesn't all the code then inherit the GPL licence?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: If part of the code is GPL, then you cannot post it on [main] anyway, since by posting it, you relicense it as CC BY-SA 3.0, which the GPL does not allow you to do. If you want to post GPL code on SO, you need to obtain permission from the copyright holder to relicense under CC BY-SA 3.0.

Comment: @JörgWMittag so in effect any questions about any GPL'd software are automatically banned on SO?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: I have no idea why you would think that. Asking questions *about* any software does not require copying that software at all. *If* you want to copy code into your question (or answer), then you need to have the legal right to a) copy that code, and b) re-license it under CC BY-SA 3.0, but this applies to *all* code and has nothing to do with GPL. The GPL does not give you the right to do this, but that doesn't mean that you cannot obtain that right any other way, say, by contacting the copyright holder and obtaining a separate license.

Comment: What about cases where the code is essentially unlicensed (public domain) by the SO contributor, often in their profile page, as well as being CC-BY-SA 3.0? Some users dual license their code in their posts.

Comment: I have an extension: What if you converted it from another language? I have a question about a javascript raycaster, and have linked the original C++ code when I posted it, but would it be considered plagerisim if I didn't?(Still gonna post my sources in the future regardless, just curious)

Comment: Technically yes, @Vakore, that would be a violation of our attribution requirements. Granted, it would be very difficult for us to catch you, but it would still be wrong. The CC by-SA license allows *remixing* of content, but requires that you *provide attribution* to the original author. So nothing wrong with converting, say, my C++ code to JavaScript and posting it as an answer, but you'd need to give me credit as the original source of the C++ code. That can be done as simply as using my name and linking to my original answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Comment: @owacoder: If the code is unlicensed, then you *do not have any rights to do anything with it*. Any rights to do anything with the code can only be given to you by the copyright holder, either via a contract or a license. If you don't have a contract, and there is no license, then the code is essentially toxic and useless: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26548

Comment: @Jörg - That's true, but I was referring to the [Unlicense](https://unlicense.org), not code with no license whatsoever. That "license" essentially puts it into the public domain, if that construct is recognized, or allows you to do anything with it (including withholding attribution) otherwise. My bad for not explaining myself well before.

Comment: @owacoder: Sorry, I didn't recognize that you were verbing the Unlicense :-D In that case, copying the code is not a copyright violation, since the license explicitly allows everything, which obviously includes copying. It is, however, still Plagiarism, since the license is completely irrelevant for that. The Stack Exchange Terms Of Service, which you acknowledged to have read and understood when you signed up, say that you must attribute anything you take from elsewhere. In other words, Plagiarism is defined by SE, not the author of the copied code, so the author cannot absolve you of that.

Comment: As was mentioned elsewhere, proper attribution is important because of "traceability of ideas". Without attribution, you don't know where that code comes from, and thus you cannot study its context, its history, the constraints under which it was created. One question that was raised in another comment: what if the problem in that code has already been fixed at the source? How would you know that? How would you find out? Or, what if the problem turns out to have security implications. How do you warn the original source? Or at least warn others to stay away from the original source?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Simply put: there is no difference** between how we handle plagiarized content in questions and answers. Plagiarism is plagiarism, and we don't tolerate it. [Attribution is very important around here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/), and we have [very clear instructions in the Help Center on how content written by others is to be attributed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Doing nothing and moving on is not and has never been the recommended approach.

If you want to assume good faith and simply edit in proper attribution, that's your call. Use the edit description to explain why you've made the edit. This tactic might be appropriate when it is otherwise a very useful question, and you think the answers to it would help a large number of other people.

However, **it is never wrong to flag plagiarism for moderator attention**. Use a custom flag, and fill the text box with both your concerns *and* your evidence. Moderators take plagiarism reports very seriously, and thoroughly investigate each of them.

I won't think twice about deleting an unanswered question with plagiarized code. For a question that has received quality answers, that's a bit harder, because deleting the question would throw away the answers. I'm hesitant to do that. I would certainly do so in egregious cases, but if it's otherwise a good Q&A, I would also consider assuming good faith and adding in the proper attribution myself.

If you've assumed good faith in the past, yet continue to see the user ignore our attribution requirements, then a custom moderator flag is once again in order. We can officially contact the user and explain the attribution requirements in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe I'll choose the "edit" approach: most of those question I mentioned are useful questions (i.e., on-topic) and it seems to me that OP is not ill-intentioned, so their *"this is my code"* is just a *"this is the code I found online and that I'd like to change somehow"*. So, an edit with the proper reference won't hurt anybody.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: You have to be very carefull when you leave such messages. Op adapted the code from the reference, so simply stating "Code is from ..." might steer people to check the orignal code instead of the adapted version. I would at least state something like "Code is from ... but I adapted it to do XYZ".

Comment: @BDL That's a good point against the "edit" option. Combined with the [answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380697/5768908), which argues that flagging may be inadequate, I reckon I'll stick with *"do nothing"* (and eventually leaving a comment), which is the option I've been doing until now.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: I'm not saying you shouldn't add references. But you should add *proper* references. If the code is a copy-paste from some source, then you can state "Code is from []". But if it is a modified version than state that. "Code is based on the work of []" or "The original is from [] but I adapted it". Or whatever similar sentence you like.

Comment: @BDL You are right, the code in the question I linked in my comment (now deleted, to avoid the meta effect to the poor OP) is not an exact copy, some lines are different... I just linked it because it was posted today! But yes, *"Code is from []"* should be used only for verbatim copies.

Comment: *"it is never wrong to flag plagiarism for moderator attention"* When doing so, be sure to include the word "plagiarism" (properly spelled, unlike me one time leading to a flag sitting there for weeks). There are (or at least, used to be years ago) to bring this to the attention of the team more proactively than other mod flags. May be worth editing into the answer, but I didn't do so myself so you could make the call (possibly with more up-to-date info than I have).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have flagged multiple answers for plagiarism simply with the text "Answer plagiarized from [source]", all got acted on very quickly and they got deleted. I'm not sure if there's multiple words triggering the plagiarism flags but it doesn't necessarily have to be exactly the word _plagiarism_.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne - Yes, "plagiarism" or "plagiarized" both get picked up (I think they added my misspelling, too, which was "plagarism" -- missed out one of the i's). :-)

Comment: If it is so common and the mods take it so seriously, why do we need to use a custom flag? Souldn't this be foreseen and have a flag already thought for this case?

Comment: @brunorey I don't believe it's that common at all, so a separate flag is really not needed. The only reason a separate flag would be needed is because plagiarism is a rather severe offense, but that's covered by listening to these keywords.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The flag queue volume has been quite manageable lately, so this is less of a concern than it used to be several years ago. Regarding the magic word "plagiarism", some of the moderators use user-scripts that allow filtering flags based on key words, but this is not a built-in feature. I wouldn't worry too much about specific verbiage to optimize for keyword searches, but it is difficult to imagine a clear flag on plagiarized content that *didn't* use the word "plagiarized"/"plagiarism" in some shape or form.

Comment: @CodyGray - Re the flag queue, good to hear! (People can easily say "copied from..." and I'd tend to assume most ESL speakers would. But it doesn't matter if things are under control these days.)

Comment: @CodyGray flag queue volume manageable? *opens custom flag chute*

Comment: Even when there’s no problem with the author’s rights, e.g. when the code had been published with the intention to be reused, with a licences allowing it, attribution still is an important thing, as questions about code from a well-known source likely have been answered before, partially or fully, or are easier to answer when the context is known. We can’t easily search for other occurrences of the same non-trivial code, but we can search for the same author/book/article/etc. I did already encounter questions which were answerable after looking for the original quote and its context.

Answer (score 33):

I think it's about expectations.

## "Mine" does not imply code *ownership* here

"My" code simply means it's the code on my screen right now that I try to get working.

As a professional, I literally *never* own that code. It's not *my* code. There is a written contract that clearly states that the code is my employers property. Even the sandboxed MCVE that I build is owned by my employer, because I did it on company time with company resources. And the real code? If I annotate that in our source control, I'd probably need to reference half a dozen people who worked on it and it would still be wrong, because all of them signed the contract so all of it belongs to the employer anyway.

Depending on tag, we even *expect* people to post code they copied from tutorials. If someone has problems with their graphics library, I would *expect* them to paste the exact code they are running, which should be the very first tutorial.

So from my point of view, "my code" is not about who owns the code. "My code" could be the linux kernel I'm trying to compile. Or my companies flagship product. <sup>(Matter of fact, right there, "my" does not mean that I *own* the company. It's just the company I currently work for)</sup> And "my code" simply says it's the code relevant to my current question.

So I'd go with the "Do nothing and move on." option.

I'm not qualified to know whether that person has the rights to publish said code. But chances are, neither are others here that would handle a flag or approve a comment. If the rights holder decides to file a DMCA notice, that's when we have a good indicator. And if you know the rights holder and think they should, then they will probably be happy to hear from you.

Comment: I largely agree with this answer, but it seems like you and most others are focusing on the semantics of the words "mine" and "my". That's...not at all the way I read the question. Gerardo specifically says, *"‘their’ code is just a verbatim copy of some original code"*. That's not a messy question about who technically owns the code, whether it's you or your employer. It's not just a semantic issue about the definition of "my". It's a rather clear-cut case of directly copy-pasting code that someone else has created, and failing to provide proper attribution, in flagrant violation of our rules

Comment: "*My* code simply means it's the code on my screen right now". +1

Comment: This is a very reasonable answer. However, I have to mention some cases (which actually led me to write this question in the first place) where OP (often a 1 rp user) misleads us, saying *"hey guys, I'm creating a chart and I need some help"*, pay attention to "I'm creating", and then... Bum!, verbatim copy/paste of a tutorial in a book. Do you see what I mean? On top of that, @CodyGray just nailed it in the comment above: that's the real focus of my question.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Why is it a problem that somebody creating a program starts out from a tutorial? Isn't that *the whole point* of a tutorial, that people use it? It's not like they copied it verbatim into their own book as a tutorial. My point is that it is normal to post code that you don't have explicit rights to publish. And it is normal to not attribute it to the owner. SO would be 30% more bloated if we all did. Can you imagine how empty SO would be if for every post people had to get written permission from their legal department and post it alongside their MCVE?

Comment: I understand your focus and my answer is: let it slide. If it's really *that* important, the legal owner can file a DMCA complaint.

Comment: @nvoigt the whole point of a tutorial is teaching people, that's correct. The author of the tutorial book expect that people copy his/her code and use it extensively, that's also correct. What's not correct is this: *"hello, I'm developing a program to do this and this and that. But I'm facing a problem with my program, can you help me to implement this and this and that? Here is my code"*, followed by an ipsis litteris copy. I already explained this several times here... I **do not expect** that *"for every post people has[had] to get written permission from their legal department"*.

Comment: This is so simple! In the same community (d3.js) I'm active, and where I often see the annoying behaviour that I'm describing in my question, I frequently see a different behaviour, when the OPs write *"hey, I'm building on this example here [link to the tutorial], can you guys help me changing this and this and that?"*. Just that, a combination of "building on" and a link! This alternative is simple, honest, and what's better: the answerers can clearly and quickly see the level/knowledge of OP, and tailor their answers accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my opinion.

I don't think it would be a good decision to directly flag the question; better edit the question with attributions or leave a comment.

Here is a scenario: I had a problem with some dependency mismatch, and when I dug deeper into Stack Overflow I found a very unpopular question and code on an answer which helped me ( When I didn't had stackoverflow account and didn't knew any of its policies) . I have been using this piece of code for few years in every project.

Now I asked a new question on Stack Overflow, and someone commented on the question, asking to post the `build.gradle` file. I would post it like "here is my `build.gradle` file", which contains the code from someone else. Now I don't have time to dig deeper again to find out from whom I copied that code to give proper credit. I am not even sure if that question exists any more at this point in time.

Suppose you were in this situation, and I was the original poster of that code and I flagged your question and you received a suspension because of it, how would you feel?

Just a simple comment might have fixed it, instead of writing and explaining all situation for moderator, wasting your time and moderator time reviewing it.

And if someone is removing the attributions even after commenting/editing then flagging the question would be a right choice.

Comment: I see, that's a good point against the "flag" option.

Comment: Side note: if what you've described actually happened to you and not "asking for a friend" than you just admitted SO content violation by not having attribution in your code (since with proper attribution all you'd need is to copy link from comment in the code)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't know where I copied that code from  to give proper credit . That is the reason I said not to flag directly , If you know who the code is from just edit the question with attribution or add a comment saying "hey the code you are using is from him (link) . Please give proper credit to him "

Comment: "I don't know where I copied that code from to give proper credit ." And that's the issue. You already violated the copyright by copying code from an answer without attribution in your code.

Comment: @Tom Ok what if the code was from some colleague/Freelancer who copied from stack overflow and I just pulled code I would assuming that they wrote code while it was from some other , In this case also Flagging directly would be a bad idea .

Comment: It doesn't matter how you try to wiggle yourself out of the plagiarism issue. The code is plagiarized, that's what matters. How you obtained the code is not important.

Comment: I never said code is not  plagiarized , I am saying not to punish directly by flagging we don't know what might have cause this situation . Just give him a chance  to fix it by commenting/editing  .

Comment: How would you fix your situation where you got the code from a freelancer? Write "This code is copied from .. somewhere?"? And a flag is _not_ a punishment to you.

Comment: If some one commented on my question saying "hey the code you are using is from him (link) . Please give proper credit to him " instead of flagging . I would verify if the content is exactly same and if it is, then I would add proper credit to the author in the question and code .

Comment: Note also that copyright and attribution are two separate concepts. They often come together but not necessarily so.

Comment: The license on SO requires you to include attribution in *your code* whenever you include code from here, so you should always know who or were your SO code came from, as Tom said.

Comment: @TylerH then perhaps SO should alert readers to that fact, then, above the code published on SO.

Comment: @David: The fact that you are not allowed to copy content without express permission from its author is common knowledge, *especially so* in the software development community, where copyright is literally how we earn our living. In addition to that, there is a link to the license at the bottom of *every single page*. There is an entire chapter in the Terms Of Service. There are several entries in the [help]. There is, unfortunately, *no* mention in the [tour] or the how to ask page, but the license is displayed there as well, and the tour has links to the help center.

Comment: @David You agree to it when you create an account. It's in the [Terms and Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) that you have to explicitly confirm that you read before you can create the account.

Answer (score 6):

I think sometimes it is just a vague wording.

"My code" means "the code I am trying to get working, then I can tailor it to my needs" - it has nothing to do with ownership, nothing to do with authorship, just represents the possessivity of that piece of code. And if that code is from a public tutorial, from a book or from a previous question or answer on SO - doesn't matter, because the OP can possess it legally.

Of course, if it is a characterwise copy of something, it should be mentioned, but if the OP changed anything meaningful (not including the comments), it is technically a new piece of code. But I am not that laser-eyed guy who can recognise every copyrighted code, and detect the changes made to the original code. If you are absolutely sure that this exact piece of code is copyrighted (or has derivative restrictions), flag it.

Otherwise just **kindly ask the OP about the origin of the code** in a comment. Also, be nice, because copy-pasters are usually newcomers.

It may still happen that the code is from a source that does not allow republishing, or has other restrictions for derivative works (as suggested in a comment). If the OP admits it, you can ask him to remove and/or flag its code. Otherwise we must assume that OP acts lawfully.

Comment: I would note that derivative work has rules around it as well, and in general failing to give proper credit for the original work it was built on is a violation of copyright/licenses terms.

Comment: @MatthieuM Agree, but technically it is impossible to check every bit of code for copyright and derivative right. That's why I recommended to ask the OP to give proper explanation for the origin of the code. But thanks for the idea, I'll update my answer with it (if you allow me to use your ideas :D )

Comment: I agree with the "technically impossible", however here the OP is pointing at a case where he already recognized where the code comes from.

Comment: For this particular case, when the source is obvious, I recommended to flag, if the source has restrictions.

Answer (score -4):

This is somewhat promoting unasked-for advice, but why are they modifying someone else's code? Several other answers here touched on this (very) tangentially.

Important:

1. See @nvoigt and several other answers about whether code is ever really, "my," code. That's discussed here extensively and above my pay grade.
2. Plagiarism is a flag, like a code exception. Stop everything, the question is invalidated, do not pass go, do not collect $200. @CodyGray and others gave that fantastic treatment and I'm not qualified to determine what is plagiarism or not. My answer and possibly the relevance of much of this discussion, does not apply to that which is, essentially, illegal.

Otherwise:

If it's a library that they've cracked open and they're messing with it, that may be a bad idea. If they're a maintainer of said library, it's as much their code as any other code. If they're not a maintainer -- and they're seeking help here to modify a library -- their better avenue is to petition the maintainers for hooks to insert code they need sanely or pick a new library that already has the hooks they need.

Thank you for being involved in the D3 community and I'm sure you understand the myriad problems that start by someone who isn't, simply deciding to poke in or change up a couple lines. Library communities have processes for this reason and when you adopt a library you're adopting with it the culture embodied in its processes and maintaining community.

If it's not a library or they're inserting code through appropriate hooks, it's as much their code as any code ever is.

Obviously, there are exceptions but my opinion is that helping teach good practices is as much a part of SO as simply giving answers. Evidence of this is in the quality of answers and especially comments on OPs.

Sorry if this is philosophically academic but I believe it's only as much so as the original question beyond the called-out above.

Comment: Why the user is modifying a given snippet of code is completely irrelevant to whether or not they are purporting that the code is their own when it isn't. We dont close or delete questions because we think that what the asker is doing / wants to do is a bad idea. If anything, an explanation why what they're trying to do is a bad idea with a suitable solution would be an acceptable answer to the question.

Comment: @TinyGiant: why they're seeking help in changing code is deeply tied to whose code it is and that's tied to the question asked here. Violation of plagiarism aside, exactly what you're suggesting is the best answer. If someone's doing it wrong, suggesting they weasel around the semantics of, "my," is the _worst_ response, even more so if English is not their primary language. Address the issue (plagiarism or doing-it-wrong) rather than a purely academic concern of semantics.

Comment: What you just said makes no sense in relation to the question asked here though. The question is about plagiarism in questions and how that is handled regardless of semantics. Likewise your assertion that why someone is doing something is deeply tied to whether or not they are plagiarizing is without merit. You have provided no reasoning for why you think they are deeply tied, only stating that they are, which doesnt clarify anything.

Comment: Consider something as simple as, you wrote code that frobs a widget, but I need to frob a gidget. Therefore, I modified your code to support gidgets. Or maybe I made it more generic, to frob any kind of object. Another common example is porting: say, I modify your C++ code to work in Delphi. All of these are valid cases where someone adapts (remixes) code, which is totally allowed by our CC by-SA license. Beyond that, this is a website to gain knowledge and expert insights, so cracking open a library and asking about its inner workings is totally fine, too, provided sufficient attribution.

Answer (score -8):

This is a tricky one.
Just because you "recognize" the code, doesn't mean it's actually plagiarism.

Let's assume that I have a piece of code I wrote myself (duh), containing the line:

```
System.out.println(myObject);
```

would that mean that, were you ever to post some code containing that line, I should consider it to be plagiarism? Or, worse, should I assume that you hacked my computer in order to copy this masterpiece of literature?

In the end, the only one who knows for sure if the code is copied/found online, is the one who posted it.

You are right that it should be known whether the OP wrote the code himself, or found it online, but, in my opinion, rather because based on the code posted, we get an impression of the knowledge of the OP, and with this impression in mind, we might formulate an answer he may or may not understand.

So, even though you edit a question to be an

> I found this post online and it doesn't work

post, it just might be that he did write the code himself, but has a coding style similar to the developer you think authored it, and uses similar naming conventions.

In that case, your edit might lead to a lot of people replying with:

> So stop copying code you don't understand and write your own

which might lead to the OP not getting the reactions he needs/deserves, which might bring down the quality of the SO platform itself.

Comment: In the cases I'm discussing in my question it **is** clearly plagiarism, dozens and dozens of lines without a single different character. And 90% of the times OP even leave the comments of the author in the copied code.

Comment: there will always be cases where the obvious isn't as obvious: person X starts at company Y, has to maintain a legacy project without any information about person Z, who worked there (years ago). So even if he would like to post information of "Original code by: " doesn't mean he can

Comment: I couldn't agree more with your response; I was going to post something similar myself (such as I++)

Comment: Yeah, there has to be a sufficient quantity of code with enough unique aspects that it becomes obvious they share a common source. The way I read the question, we weren't talking about little one-liners. We are talking about entire functions that are clearly copied (albeit with minor adaptations) from other *published* sources (e.g., books, articles, Stack Overflow answers, etc.).

Comment: @CodyGray I agree that we're not talking about one-liners, but I wasn't talking about one liners, I merely used one as an example to avoid having to write 500 lines of code to use as a simple example.
Matter of fact is, two persons who used the same textbook to learn Java, or were taught by the same instructor, may have started out with a very similar, if not identical coding style. Or, in case of legacy code to maintain, a developer may not know who the original author/source is, but 'll still have to maintain it. Should he be downflagged for asking questions about it?

Comment: @Stultuske: If you don't know who the copyright holder is and you don't have a license that allows you to post the code under CC BY-SA 3.0, then you are unable to obtain permission to post the code, and you cannot post it. That sucks, but that's how it is. Note that in the case where you have to maintain legacy code in a company, usually the company will hold at least some copyright, including the right to relicense the code, so you don't have to track down the original author, you only need to obtain a license from your legal department.

Comment: @JörgWMittag we are talking "author", not "copyright holder". The company he works for is the copyright holder, the original author might not work there anymore. Bit of a difference there.Usually, the company won't hold "some" copyright, they hold it all. Too many contracts state "every line of code written during work hours or on our machines while working for us, is property of [company name]". Yes, it is that simple. The company has the copyrights, the company makes you work on it.

Comment: @Stultuske: Yes, sorry, there are too many intermingled concepts here, and I am guilty of intermingling them even more. There is the question of copyright (are you allowed to post the code on SO), and then there is the question of plagiarism. The question of plagiarism again has three sub-components, one is "passing off other's work as your own" (which can be alleviated by "I didn't write this, but I have no idea where I got it from),  the second is "giving credit where credit is due" (which can't), and the third is "traceability of ideas", which is the most important of the three in academia.

Comment: … It basically means that whenever I find some idea, data, information, knowledge, concept, content, whatever somewhere, I *must* be able to trace it back the entire path to its origin, so I can understand how, why, when, under which circumstances, in which conditions, in what kind of environment, under which constraints, this idea originated, evolved, changed, etc. I am not sure how important this part is in the software development community, but it is extremely important in the academic community, and at least I personally wish it were important here, too.

Comment: I agree that traceability is a main issue. for all we know, the issue the (new) developer/author encounters had been solved in the original source beforehand, but should a question be flagged because the one asking doesn't know the original source/author? That's more the issue I was thinking about.
I too prefer to know whether the OP wrote the code him(her)self, but mostly because from time to time, someone asks questions about Dependency Injection, has a neat Spring Boot service as example, yet has no idea what you are talking about when you mention 'instantiation of objects'.

Comment: That way, people start formulating answers using lingo the OP should be able to understand, since the one answering will assume he wrote the code. Yet in the end, it might turn out someone who has just managed to get "Hello world" to run, assumes to be ready to create the next facebook.

Comment: The concepts are intermingled here on [main], because any content you find on Stack Exchange is licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0, which requires attribution in order to be allowed to copy, so plagiarism *within SO* is automatically also copyright violation, unless you have a separate license to that content in question.

Answer (score -13):

**TL;DR: Yes, my code is really mine.**

Having a lawfully obtained copy of some code on your hard drive, and referencing to it as "mine" is not automatically a plagiarism.

To own something, means to have the dominion over something in exclusion to another individual. It is a *peculiar* right. It is how things are. How things ought to be.

If you *have* a *copy* of the code on your hard drive physically, it is yours. You can do whatever you want with it. You can move it, edit it, delete it, paste it on some website, throw hard drive into the fire, etc. There is no force that can physically prevent this, because it is in custody of peculiar right of ownership.

**Example #1:**

I buy a book from a friend. I have it now. I can refer to it as *my book*. I can dispose of the book however I like. I don't claim I *wrote* the book, however that does not mean the book is not mine now. So, I can take notes from the book, or torn a page and show it to other people. I still don't claim I wrote it, however I still own it, and it is *mine*.

If I go to other people with this page, and ask questions about grammar, and I refer to this page as *my page of words*, does it make me one who plagiarizes? I doubt so.

**Example #2:**

Ownership and authorship mean different things. If I would use a name "John", I would introduce myself "My name is John". That does not mean I am an author of the name, does it?

**Example #3:**

Suppose I have a dog, let's call him Fluffy. Fluffy *is my dog*. However I didn't created the dog. God/Creator/Life/Nature created the dog. Problems arise when I'll start going around claiming that I am the author (creator, first mover) of the dog. That would be not true, hence - a theft from the author.

**On plagiarism**

To accuse someone of plagiarizing is a serious thing. I would refrain from that. I think you should first prove intent of claiming something untrue, like, if someone actually claims he/she is author of the code, *and* that you also know for sure true author of it.

Of course matters are a little bit more complicated on Stack Overflow, because as soon as the code is pasted on the site, it becomes the property of the site owners. Now the code is a copy of the copy, and is located elsewhere (on different hard drive). Which means, it is no longer property of the poster, and is subject to the rules of the site.

However, one should give poster the option to refer to the pasted/typed code as *his* as it would mean he references *his copy of the code*.

Concerning attribution, leave a comment suggesting to add it, or if you know it for sure, add it yourself.

Comment: all your examples are subjective and have been defined by the legal system. if we follow the legal system then code attribution is not only necessary but mandatory. however that would lead to the death of stackoverflow and a youtube like draconian content-id system where posts are auto flagged by oracle or google or microsoft or apple or whoever the giant companies are of the day for ownership. i guarantee most patterns you've "thought of" have already been patented/licensed.

Comment: "*If you have a copy of the code on your hard drive physically, it is yours*" I'm sure your employer's lawyers would just LOVE this . If you work in the commercial sector, then you can just take a copy of the code, then publish it free of charge. More seriously - no, you are very wrong. Having the code gives you *some* leeway. You can certainly move it or throw your hard drive in the fire. That's nothing to really do with the licensing. But *publishing* it or *using it* in certain cases (e.g., for profit products) might be an issue. You *don't* have all rights for any code on your PC.

Comment: "*I buy a book from a friend. I have it now*" code is not a book. When you take a copy of the code, the original source stays. A thousand people can take the same code and the availability is the same. Books are a limited resource - if a thousand books are sold, there might be no more.

Comment: "*Ownership and authorship mean different things.*" sure, but when talking about *licensing*, you don't *own* the code. You (broadly) have permission to use it. When talking about code, *ownership* refers to whoever can consent to you using the code. That's done through the licensing. An MIT license is pretty much "anything goes, I don't care". But other licenses are a lot more restrictive. Open source licenses are usually very loose but try to enforce the openness - you may be prohibited from using open source code in a close source system, for example.

Comment: "*Suppose I have a dog*" I have no idea what this is supposed to mean. Code is not a dog. You have to bend over backwards to make any sort of parallel...which is what you did. At this point, you could also try to go "Now, imagine the code is the moon. Code is not made of cheese, just like the real moon." which is a valid comparison but rather meaningless.

Comment: "*because as soon as the code is pasted on the site, it becomes the property of the site owners*" WHAT?! That is not right. That is so very, very wrong. No, code posted here is licensed under [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).

Comment: Suppose I find a dog wandering the streets, take him home, give him a new collar, call him Fluffy.  Would a Magistrate agree that he is my dog?  No!   Same reasoning applies to code (more or less) according to the law.

Comment: Quote:  "To accuse someone of plagiarizing is a serious thing. I would refrain from that." (Written above, just to be clear).  I could not agree more whole-heartedly!  Not giving an exact attribution is far from plagiarism!   {Btw, why is there an I after the g in plagiarism, no one in my state pronounces that I)