# Should a post be flagged if the OP does not remember the code owner and adds the code without attribution?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, attribution

Should a post be flagged as "plagiarism" if the OP does not remember the original code creator and adds the code to the question without attribution? What should be done?

Comment: Do you know the code owner? Then add the reference. If you don't, then how do you know it is plagiarized? There was a [very similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380687/is-your-code-really-yours) some hours ago.

Comment: @BDL This didn’t happened. I am assuming if something like this happened and the OP forgot the code owner.

Comment: If you don't know for sure that something is plagiarized and can point to the source, then you should definitely not flag it as plagiarized. Unless you know where the code came from, it is impossible to tell under which license to original was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag for plagiarism if you know what has been plagiarized and can point the mod to the plagiarized content.

If you suspect a post to be plagiarized, do your research and find exactly the URL of the original content. Preferrably, include the appropriate attribution by editing the post.

But if you can't find it, how are you going to include the URL in your flag? Do you expect the mod to do this research for you?

Do not flag on hunches or hearsay.

Comment: What if the code owner forgot the code creator but you know the code creator?

Comment: _"Flag for plagiarism if you know what has been plagiarized and can point the mod to the plagiarized content."._ If you know what has been plagiarized and can point to it, do so.