# Link only old answers

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, old-questions

Its been a while,since I got up to 2k reputation on SO,and unlocked the privilege of editing, and some reviewing tasks.While reviewing low quality answers,I recommend some answers for deletion because they are not well explained and are just **link only**.Then a pop up appears which ask me that if a comment is needed below the post which I am recommending for deletion....................................................................

---

Now while surfing on SO,I came across a useful,but link only answer.,,, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514606/how-to-display-data-in-android-page-using-accordion) which is old(around 3 years old). As a privileged user, I was thinking of flagging it as in appropriate,but at the same time ,its age,and the upvotes made me not to do so.

---

So what about these old answers which are creating ambiguity in my mind,that they are link only and are of low quality.Should I flag them or leave  them as they are.

Comment: Please don't take the top-rated answer as the official position on that post. The actual answer moderators follow is [this answer posted by Robert Harvey](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251701/16587).