# Are old, upvoted answers harder to get removed?

Tags: discussion, flags

Earlier I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python/109245#109245) as NAA, which seemed pretty straightforward to me. I read it as being some commentary relating to the question (but which doesn't answer it), followed by a separate question. However, my flag was disputed, so obviously some reviewers disagree with me.
My question is, was the flag disputed because the reviewers saw the high vote count and didn't look critically at the question, or am I mistaken in thinking that it should be removed? If it's the former, what should I do in this kind of situation: reflag it, let it go and move on, or make a post on meta about it?

I found a couple posts which are related, but neither seems to quite apply:

- [Should old, high-rep, link-only, accepted answers be deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted)
- [How to handle historical, highly upvoted but completely incorrect
  answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sure reads like an answer to me. I'd decline that flag.

"not an answer" is for things that anyone can tell at a glance are not attempts at answering the question: follow-on questions, ["I like turtles"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097342/pick-a-random-email-address-out-of-a-maillist/26532908#26532908), etc. Detailed answers that appear to address the question asked should not be flagged in this manner.

Being highly upvoted certainly helps to protect an answer, because it usually shows that people found value in it. It doesn't make such an answer immune from removal, but does make me more hesitant to delete it. A moderator would have to be the one to delete this answer, since community reviewers cannot delete upvoted answers. They can only vote on it, which signals moderators to look hard at the answer they reviewed.

If additional context is required to see why you need to delete this, a custom moderator flag can be used. However, even after reading the question I don't see why that answer should be deleted at all.

Comment: Who doesn't like turtles?

Comment: I agree with your assessment. At the same time, I can see how someone *would* want to say it is not an answer, because the last sentence is a question: "Does any one have an implementation that would allow for fall through while only using a single comparison?" So is it an answer with a rhetorical question at the end? Or is it someone asking for help who prefaced their request with some thoughts on the matter?

Comment: It's important to note that all the flags were 'disputed' by the community -- so it wasn't a moderator making a unilateral decision, the community even disagrees with characterizing the answer as 'not an answer'.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. It seemed to me like the question was asking "what's a replacement for `switch`" and the answer was `here's why Python doesn't have `switch`", which didn't seem like an answer to me. I'll try to keep this in mind if I encounter a similar situation.