# What to do with link only answers with positive scores

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I was just looking at the low-quality posts queue and I got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931425/1380867). Normally, I would recommend for deletion as a link only answer not spam but it has +5. I know the link is good but then again I am not clear what should I do when I come across more posts like this one.

Should I mark the question as "Looks OK" or skip?

Comment: What you could (should !) do is to post the link as a comment, so that it does not get lost, even if the answer is later deleted. _Skip_ is _always_ the correct action to take if you're not sure.

Comment: And what if the link is broken tomorrow, still a good answer? If you really want to put in the extra effort, see if you can take the relevant information out of the link and edit the answer to include it. Otherwise, I would still flag it as low quality. The *answer* is low quality, even if the link is not.

Comment: @JonasCz thanks I did that for this question. and I will do that moving forward as I see them.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Thank you too. If I have the time I would definitely  try to take the relevant info from the link and move it to the answer.

Comment: You should also [look at this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted).

Comment: related: [Can we please clear misunderstanding that deleting old highly upvoted posts causes reputation loss?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/839601)

Comment: @gnat I agree with that article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically, treat them the same as you would link only answers with low scores.

If you really don't feel like recommending deletion on a highly upvoted link only answer, then you don't have to, no one is going to force you to click the recommend deletion button.

So in the case where you don't want to hit recommend deletion, you can do one of at least three things.

1. Edit the answer to make it a good answer that is not link only anymore. (like Robert Harvey did)
2. Just Skip that review
3. Leave a comment asking the answerer to improve their answer. (please don't do this if there is already a comment about this though)