# What am I missing about when a link only answer is not an answer?

Tags: discussion

So I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761324/550062) that I made me think "Link only answer.  Kill it with fire."  So I went to flag it as Not an Answer and the flag box told me my last flag was declined.  So I went to check out why.  I had raised a Not an Answer flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050149/550062) because I believed it to be a link only answer again.

For reference, the question is thus (I know the question kinda sucks and maybe should be closed, but that's a different topic for another time):

> How can I load a CSV file into a System.Data.DataTable, creating the
>   datatable based on the CSV file?
>
> Is there a class library for this or can I use ADO.net to connect to
>   the file?

According to [Your Answer is in Another Castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) I read the answer without the markup to see what I got.  The answer sans-markup is thus

> Here's an excellent class that will copy CSV data into a datatable
>   using the structure of the data to create the DataTable:
>
> A portable and efficient generic parser for flat files
>
> It's easy to configure and easy to use. I urge you to take a look.

So without the link, I get an answer to "How can I do the thing? Use a thing library?" as "Yes, use a library that does the thing."  Since the library isn't named and the answer mostly just restates the question, the answer fails the link only answer test.  But apparently a mod disagrees.  Is there something I'm missing?  I want to keep flagging the garbage as such, but I want to make sure I'm doing the right thing.

Note: I've already seen [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted) along with countless others while trying to figure this out, but as far as I can tell, the answer in question along with the one that prompted all this should be burninated.

Comment: Your first link _absolutely_ is a link only not-an answer. The second link is borderline, but remember it was answered 5 years ago when the site was different.

Comment: The mod probably declined the second one for a couple reasons: 1) It's a very old answer. Times were different then. By itself, not a great reason. 2) It is a highly upvoted answer. People have found it useful. 3) It's the accepted answer. These reasons probably _at least_ factored into the decline.

Comment: The second one is an old ('09) recommendation question in need of closing.

Comment: @Kendra But look at the meta post I linked at the end of the question.  It specifically addresses the case of what to do with a highly upvoted, accepted link only answer.  The top answer there says it should burn in a fire anyway.

Comment: @Becuzz As BoltClock mentions in the answer, the question is asking for links so why punish the user who answered the question with a link?  The problem is the question, not the answer.

Comment: @Becuzz And mods are allowed to go against that _advice_ as really... It's not a 100% hard rule. It's community consensus, yes, but not a "You lose your moderator title if you don't follow this to the letter" rule. It's more advice for how the mods should be handling it to keep the community happy.

Comment: "*So I went to flag it as Not an Answer*" and this is your mistake, because it was ***an*** answer, but it was not *good* answer because of possibility of it becoming useless answer if link will break. You should use Very Low Quality flag instead.

Comment: @Pshemo According to Your Answer is in Another Castle (linked above), an answer where the answer becomes useless when the markup is removed (in this case, that is equivalent to pretending the link is broken) is not an answer.

Comment: @Becuzz from [When to flag an answer as "it is not an answer"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1393766) "*Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer. You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a bad answer, but it is still an answer.*" and from [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer#comment60480_265553): "*What you could do is flag posts with just a link as low quality*".

Comment: Keep in mind that the URL title in the second answer is exactly the same as the article title, which makes it easier to find if the original link breaks, assuming CodeProject articles are still drifting around in some fashion. That doesn't necessarily completely justify it, but it does make it better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your first link is indeed a link-only answer. If I pretend the link isn't there, all I see is a statement "Here is explained how to do that" which by itself is utterly meaningless.

Your second link, which you had flagged previously, is also a link-only answer, but it is an answer to the question because *the question itself* asks for link-only answers. Therefore, flagging the answer as not an answer is not only inappropriate, but also unfair to the user who was genuinely answering the question. If you come across a question that asks for links to external resources, you should be voting to close the question rather than flagging the answers, as that is where the real problem lies.

Comment: The only reason I didn't immediately flag the question was because he asked if there was a way to accomplish what he wanted without a library (he suggested ADO).  And many of the answers reflect that and don't use any special library.  So does just asking for a library as a potential solution automatically make it off topic because of the answers it will attract?

Comment: @Becuzz: Yeah, on closer inspection the question does indeed seem more than just a library request, so closing it may not necessarily be the best thing to do (unless it's still off-topic after removing the recommendation part). Someone else just started a discussion on such topics here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296583/removing-recommendation-requests-from-otherwise-on-topic-questions

Comment: The question in the second link was just put on hold as off-topic, so someone's watching.

Comment: @BoltClock "... because the question itself asks for link-only answers."  What in the second link's question indicates that it is looking for link-only answers?

Comment: @Trisped: "Is there a library" questions pretty much always result in answers that are external links by nature. You could answer these without links, but all that does is put the burden of finding the link on the reader.

Comment: @BoltClock Reading the question, it sounds to me like they are looking for a solution, even if it requires an external library.  It does not sound to me like they are requiring an external library, especially since they mention [ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx) which is part of the .NET framework.  Personally, I would reply with a simple C# example using RegEx or String.Split solution, which is why I am asking what makes it a link-only answer.