# Removing recommendation requests from otherwise on topic questions

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was trying to get rid of some recommendation requests when I came across a question that had an on topic programming question in addition to the request for a tutorial.

I edited it to remove the off topic request but found other questions with the same issue. At least one of them already had an answer to the part that was on topic.

It seems legit to do this for one question but would doing a string of these be seen as rep farming? I would do other edits (grammar, missing tags, etc.) as well <strike>if necessary</strike> (clarification: by "if necessary" I meant I'd fix other errors if they exist).

Comment: The question that was just being discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296578/what-am-i-missing-about-when-a-link-only-answer-is-not-an-answer) turns out to be an example of such a question on my closer inspection. Coincidence?

Comment: As I said in response to [Could someone edit too many posts too often?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267607), as long as your edits are valuable, you are welcome to try to suggest them in droves. I'd be happy for every single one you can spare your time for.

Comment: @BoltClock - I actually hadn't read that one though I think it was something on Meta that prompted me to look for rec requests.

Comment: If you can "rep-farm" by helping people get good answers and reducing the amount of crap floating around, please, *please* rep-farm!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It seems legit to do this for one question but would doing a string of
>   these be seen as rep farming?

It might be, but as long as the edits are *complete* and aren't rejectable for any other reasons, I personally don't see a problem with it.  If your edits are complete, you'll likely have the suggestions spaced out over a much more manageable timespan, and you won't have to worry about flooding the review queue.  Just be a bit careful you don't "clearly conflict with author's intent" in your edit.

> I would do other edits (grammar, missing tags, etc.) as well if necessary.

This is *absolutely necessary*.  Turning a off-topic, unreadable question into a (possibly?) on-topic unreadable question does not make the question useful.  Ideally, your edit should make the question worthy of upvotes for clarity (or at least unworthy of downvotes).  Without fixing all (most) of the problems, your edits will annoy other users a lot more.  I will say that these edits that make a question on-topic are much more important that removing "Thanks" or other nitpicky things.  More than likely, you'll have to do some fairly significant reworking to make it actually on-topic anyway.

I also suggest explicitly mentioning in the edit comments that you are making the question on-topic (like "removing off-topic recommendation").

Comment: I tend to consider only edits that are frivolous, superfluous, or otherwise not made in good faith as rep farming - because these edits aren't honest attempts at improving the question. If you put effort into your edits then the rep comes as a reward for your effort - as designed.

Comment: To clarify, by "if necessary" I meant "if the question needed it because not all questions have grammar or missing tag issues". I didn't mean to suggest that I'd take out the recommendation but leave grammar issues. _I also suggest explicitly mentioning in the edit comments that you are making the question on-topic (like "removing off-topic recommendation")._ - This is a good suggestion; an Asker approved my edit after I did this.