# Why is this link-only answer disputed?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, disputed-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299195/relationship-between-integers-and-their-names-prolog/23301193#23301193) as not an answer:

> <sub>This is about the most detailed explanation of the algorithm for turning an integer value (3,111,792) into English-language text ("three million, one hundred eleven thousand, seven hundred and ninety-two: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NumberToWords.aspx</sub>
>
> <sub>The translation to prolog should be pretty straightforward.</sub>

This seems the appropriate way to make it into a comment. So why is my flagging 
 declined?

For completeness, the option I clicked on reads:

> **it is not an answer** This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

According to that description this is the most appropriate option.

Comment: It IS an answer. A bad one, for sure. Just downvote. Not An Answer flags are for: *I have the same problem, help me* and *The above answer worked* and *What does foo mean?*

Comment: @rene: The downvote arrow reads: "This answer is not useful". And no, this is answer is very useful, simply it should be a comment.

Comment: It was disputed in review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4664057 by three reviewers who felt it was not worth deleting.

Comment: I should point out that flagging anything as "not an answer" won't lead to it being converted to a comment. Now that those flags pass into the Low Quality Posts review queue, all that users can do there is decide to delete the post or not. Only moderators can convert these into comments, and for that you'll need to explain this using a custom flag. Even in the old system, flagging something as "not an answer" didn't tell us that you wanted this to be preserved as a comment.

Comment: @BradLarson: But then the explanatory text is outdated. It reads:  **it is not an answer** This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. &mdash; This includes making it a comment.

Comment: @false The answer *isn't* useful as it's a link-only answer. Link-rot does and will happen. I'd agree with downvoting it, especially since two other people posted comments explaining why it wasn't a good answer. Unfortunately, it appears I'm out of downvotes at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear ... I agree with your assessment and the fact that the "is not an answer" text is ambiguous there. It *was* an attempt to answer the question ... but really it should have been a comment since it's only a link. I'd have flagged it as "low quality" but I can see why you flagged as you did.

Comment: The main problem with the answer referenced is that it doesn't answer the question which was asked. OP wants to go from text ("one hundred twenty-seven") to number (127). Answer and link describe how to go from number to text. Thus, link or no link, it's not an answer.

Comment: @BobJarvis: That would make it a *wrong* answer, so downvote it, but it is still an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Your assessment would be OK for other programming languages, but in Prolog, once we see it one way, we have it the other way round too. So in that sense the answer was fine.

Answer (score 23):

You're right, this isn't really an answer. I've removed it with a comment:

> It looks like a good article, but this guy asked a specific question; if you're gonna answer, you should try to answer what he asked. If you wish to use that article as a resource when doing so - or just include it as a source of more detailed information - that would be admirable as well. Note that this answer is under discussion here: [Why is this link-only answer disputed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252306/why-is-this-link-only-answer-disputed)

BTW: note that this is hardly a *link-only answer*, given that most of it wasn't a link - that doesn't make it any more of an answer though, as what *wasn't* a link didn't actually attempt to answer the question either.

Your flag was disputed because several people disagreed with this assessment; that's what *disputed* means, after all. Answers like this are quite controversial: they *can* be extremely valuable, but as others noted they are very vulnerable to link-rot - which can then render them useless. When you find these, leaving a comment reminding the author of this can be a good way to get folks to flesh them out - if you're able to do so yourself, that's even better.

Comment: IMHO something that is only a link with some text *that only briefly describes what the link is* is reasonable to call a "link only answer". That's really just arguing semantics though :)

Comment: But why is it now entirely deleted? The link as such was valuable as a comment.

Comment: The author can post a comment if he prefers, @false. So can you, for that matter.

Comment: Perfect, so this is the way!

Comment: Why write "gonna"?

Comment: Well if this becomes the official policy on these kind of answers I would agree wholeheartedly. I have stopped to flag these answers after having a flag declined on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10454675/1197518). So it seems that there is no clear consensus between moderators on this subject (or I am a headstrong that cannot understand the policy)

Comment: I don't understand stopping flagging because one time people disagreed with you.  It's not like you get flogged for misflagging.  Keep flagging how you believe.  If a lot of them are turned down, see if you can understand how you're different, but don't just stop flagging.

Comment: @Steve You echo what I've maintained for a while.  See [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled/251517#comment3383_251517).  Different mods act rather differently.  Shog9 [would prefer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251624/2235132) that you edit link only posts to make those complete.  Seems ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to respond to these situations is to follow the link the answerer posted, copy the most important content on the linked page, and edit that copy into a quote block into the original answer. Now, instead of telling someone to read an article and being vulnerable to link rot, the answer has helpful advice and cites the source the advice came from.

Comment: Or maybe copying the relevant quotes and making it as your own answer. After all, if you're going to spend your time reading someone's article to determine what is relevant or not (and whether it's relevant or not), it's as good as yours.

Comment: @MxyL - but that doesn't sort the same information that was provided to the top, making your new answer much less useful by appearing to be the 'trash' instead of the 'gold'. 

This policy actually increases the noise-to-signal ratio on the site and it is VERY troubling to me.

Comment: Such edit will be very likely rejected as "*improper*".

Comment: This is exactly what you should not do, unless you have rights to the external content.