# How to handle "old" highly upvoted link only answers?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I came across [this highly voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf), and found these two (also quite upvoted) answers providing nothing more than a link essentially (even worse, both are redundant for each other):

[image]

May be at the time, when these were posted, the site didn't have the policiy that *link only answers* are off-topic.
Nowadays if I view an answer like this freshly posted, I wouldn't hesitate to flag it as *being not an answer*, and require to give at least an essential code sample, or text cite replicated from the link.

I've been thinking about flagging both of them, but I'm not so sure this will fly off well, because the answers are really old, and deemed to be useful by so many users.

How should we handle that kind of old (but manifest) link only answers?

1. Edit in the essentiall stuff from the given link
2. Merge answers (I cannot really) and do 1.
3. Flag them, as I would do for any fresh answers
4. Whatever could be done, I don't think about yet ...

---

PS.: I actually decided to take action 1. now for the higher upvoted answer:

[image]

Comment: Technically speaking, the first one is *not* a link-only answer, as it provides the name of a method to use that you can presumably search for. However, I'd agree those answers are not very useful.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy _"Technically speaking, the first one is not a link-only answer, as it provides the name of a method ..."_ Not exactly, mentioning a valid method name should have been `boost::format()` then. By these means the 2nd question is no worse than the 1st one.

Comment: @sphanley No, that's not the point. None of these answers is accepted, and I seriously disagree, that just flagging should be the right action. Usually it's easy (having enough rep, or being a mod it's even easier), to at least propose a suggested edit to improve these kind of answers. The question and anwers will attract traffic from researchers because of their vote level alone, thus improving the question/answer will be more useful in the long term view.

Answer (score 10):

To answer my own question here (especially in contrast to the [proposed dupe's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled) answers):
I believe the right action to take, is to edit and improve (as mentioned I did/tried) the most upvoted existing answer to fit Stack Overflow's actual policies in this case.

For any researchers on the topic these answers will appear prominently, and I don't believe just deleting them (as these are obviously deemed being helpful) will improve anything for Stack Overflow's quality in the long term.

---

If at all, the only answer from the [proposed dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled) that seems appropriate for me is, [@shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled/251624#251624) (but certainly not the accepted one):

> Y'all are idiots. You're really gonna spend 13 hours arguing about this instead of just editing the answer (as someone presumably less interested in arguing has now done)?
>
> If a moderator isn't willing to fix a problem, go ahead and fix it yourself. You have the tools; if you don't care to use them, then you're as much at fault as anyone else.

---

<sub>Outdated links are a problem though, I hesitated to update the given link to the actual library version's documentation. If we start to do this, it's going to be an endless need for survey and updates.</sub>

Comment: When I come across a popular link-only answer from yesteryear I check the authors profile to see if they have been active recently. If they have I just leave a comment asking if they could update, if they are inactive then I'll just edit it in myself. It seems to work most of the time saving me any real effort! Works best with high rep users, I think.

Comment: There's not actually any reason at all to edit link-only answers if there are also not-link-only answers of acceptable quality. And that's irrespective of the number of votes the link-only answer might have accrued in the aeons since it was posted. Also, beware of doing a "radical edit", and just about any edit but adding a quote from behind the link will be radical.

Answer (score 5):

Those answers provide more than link, they refer to the module name of the (quite standard) library.

It's like saying 'use apache StringUtils for that'.

As for now, we expect **at least** a small code example how to use given library.

Deleting those answers would be a loss for SO - they are referring to the good library, they were useful for many people. However, they should be edited to provide a simple example. In most cases, putting one-liner will make them quite good answers.

If you can't provide that one liner and the API is not available, you can put that on meta.

The second answer is the duplicate, so I'd left the comment that it's the duplicate and flag it.