# Old link only answers to personal site that you don't want deleted and you don't know how to edit?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

This is very similar to the question from this [thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278976/how-to-handle-old-highly-upvoted-link-only-answers) (despite being marked duplicate) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted/251701#251701).  There they state that the best course of actions for some answers, if the resource is otherwise valuable, is to edit the answer to not be link only.

My situation is as follows:

- I see a link only question, and I feel something needs to be done with it.
- The link actually goes to the authors own site, and presumably the author could have actually done the right thing and made this not link only (though this is fairly old)
- its the best answer on the question by far, and I don't feel like it should be deleted because it's actually useful.

The difference between my question and the previous questions on this topic is that IMO I don't have the expertise to actually properly edit the answer to not be link only and include the relevant information from the site, and the individual who posted this A: does have the expertise to do this, and B: is still active (last post was feb 5th) and C: the link is actually a post on the answerer's personal site which I believe he indirectly makes money off of via consulting and other paid resources (so was the answer might have been against SO TOS?).

What am I supposed to do with the answer?  How could I take steps to get it fixed?

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4292674/2036035) to the answer

Comment: The author of that post was here two days ago, thus since he still is an active member, try to write him a comment and tell him that answers must include the essential part of the link to work as a "standalone post" and the link can be included as further reading.

Comment: @Tom Good suggestion, but it also appears that some one did that in june of 2017 and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

As usual you have basically following options:

- vote/flag due to low quality
- edit question in shape.
- post your own answer covering the same link

Based on your question it feels like you find the answer useful, but not meeting quality standards. Editing in summary of the link would be reasonable. Make sure to provide attribution if needed. It is a good idea to ask author in comments to update the post first, but in this case it was done more than half a year ago - way longer than couple weeks I'd give one to react to a comment.

If you going to post your own comments/interpretation in addition to just some quotes from the linked article it could be better to provide your own answer. Posting your own thoughts under someone else's name/votes is not really welcome.

Note: be careful with quoting code in particular - license of SO is significantly more permissive than many other licenses. Author of the article is free to do whatever they want with content and hence can post code on SO themselves while others may not be allowed to.