# How to handle multiple old accepted/up-voted Low Quality Answers from same user?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, specific-user

If I notice many Low Quality Answers from one single user, what is recommended practice for me to handle those if:

- all answers are from one single user
- all answers are old (2011-12-13)
- some of the answers are up-voted (but NOT highly up-voted; max 5 votes)
- some of the answers are accepted
- each answer belong to different questions

Following is what I can think of:

1. One way I can think of is to flag them as NAA if it is link-only. Many answers are like "Refer this link" type. But, NAA is not valid flag for one-liner-no-code type answers. Some answers are actually comments asking "Are you sure .....?".
2. Other way I can think of is to flag one of them for moderator attention and include list of others.
3. Down-vote. I am afraid this may be considered as serial down-voting which is not my intention. Also, single down-vote still do not affect the post in any realistic way; specially very old posts.
4. Comment asking to improve answer. Same as down-vote; it do not affect the post in any realistic way specially if it is old. Also, user is with good sum of reputation and I am sure he/she know very well about quality of answers. Such comments are helpful for new users; I am not sure if high reputation user need (or even read) them.
5. Should I involve SOCVR?
6. Do nothing; it happens so....leave it
7. Anything else?

I refer [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278976/5779732) meta post which discusses about similar issue. But, all answers belong to same question there. Also, answers there are highly up-voted and are from different users.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251514/5779732) meta post provides much broader view. I am worried here because the answers are from same user.

---

**Some background:**
I accidentally noticed one link-only answer of user and flagged it NAA and moved on with my work. As I was reading/searching/googling for same topic, I came across other link-only answer of same user; and I did same as earlier. When I noticed similar answer third time from same user, I searched for "all answers from [this] user with tag [this]" in SO and noticed that there are so many of this kind.

I must mention the user have very good understanding of technology (tag) and many of his/her answers are very good quality. Some of them helped me as well.

I choose way 1 for all link only answers and way 2 for other Low Quality Answers.

Was my decision correct? Is there a scope to improve this? Is there other better way which may save my (as well as others) efforts?

Comment: Without recent activity those answers are out of scope for SOCVR, see our [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-cv-pls-not-a-habit) *although that one seems to focus on questions, the recent activity is to be applied to answers as well, we strive to keeo users front-page clean, not to wade through the mud that nobody no longer cares for*

Comment: Beyond that, once flagged it doesn't really help to get more flags. And SOCVR is explicitly not a (down) vote ring, or at least we don't try to be and ask or members to respect that: https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-no-up-down-vote-requests

Comment: @rene: That said, SOCVR is not a way to go. Understood and agreed.

Comment: For answers we have this saying *It's the question!*. So instead of moderating the answer, sometimes handling the question (closing it / voting on it ([Roomba!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)) / deleting it) all of a sudden solves the *issues* of a lot of answers. When done with care a tactical meta post might work as well.

Comment: @rene: I will not say "all" but most of the questions "_in question_" are good. I read many of them before taking an action.

Comment: Ok, then that option is out of the window. Just offering (wild) ideas here ...

Comment: @HansPassant: I am shocked with your comment. I have explained in "Some background" how I came up to here. I am out of words to explain more specially when you say "i am targeting other user".

Comment: Sigh, I give up.  Don't target specific users, either with votes or flags.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at responses and other resources, I think I made two mistakes here.

First mistake is, I executed the action first and then asked help on meta. It should have been opposite.

Second mistake:

> **Some background:** I accidentally noticed one link-only answer of user and flagged it NAA and moved on with my work. As I was reading/searching/googling for same topic, I came across other link-only answer of same user; and I did same as earlier.

It was fine up to here, but then,

> When I noticed similar answer third time from same user, I searched for "all answers from [this] user with tag [this]" in SO

This I now realize was wrong. I should have done same that I did first and second time. I should not have went to search for posts of specific user no matter how good my intention was.

---

I would like to mention again that it was not my intention to target the other user. My intention was cleanup. Details are mentioned in "Some background" section of question. But, as said above, intention does not matter. The way I did it was still wrong.

...and about teaching the other (high rep) user to improve his **old** answers, I guess way 6 (Do nothing; it happens so....leave it) is best choice. It does not solve the problem but at-least, it do not create controversy.

Comment: I see no problem what you've done. *Says the most unpopular contributor here.* The main point is, if you flag / vote on contributions by a specific user, and you are acting within the rules (i.e. no abuse; *voting on content* even if it happens to be from one user), be happy and prepared to have this done to your own contributions. In the end, SO is bigger than a few people and quality generally gets rewarded.