# What to do with broken but highly upvoted link only answers?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I found [this specific Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384168/how-to-make-a-process-daemon) where two link-only answers were given:

- The [link](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html) from the first (and accepted) answer looks good at a first skim, but is broken at the second level when [crawling in](http://web.archive.org/web/20110519231811/http://web.archive.org/web/20060603181849/http://www.linuxprofilm.com/articles/linux-daemon-howto.html#s1).
- The second answer's [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/c-daemon-process/) works, but doesn't provide really useful information.

The question has a lot of upvotes currently, and so has the first answer despite it's completely useless (at least after that link was broken).

It seems to be a perfect example why it's [bad to post link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/186472), though it's used as a duplicate link for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100898/create-c-application-as-a-service-in-linux).

How can we get rid of that effectively (besides calling the meta-effect here)?

I have downvoted and flagged those answers as NAA (which might no longer apply nowadays), of course.

---

Especially, should I downvote the question, to let it get less notion, or should I start a bounty to encourage getting a real answer for it?

Should I add a custom moderation flag to delete that useless construct completely as a whole?

---

**Update:**

The questionable answers were deleted now from the question.

Comment: May I know about the downvote? What I've been missing? How's my question unclear?

Comment: Maybe the down vote is for not well researched as this has been asked before?

Comment: First comment one sees on this answer: *"+1 Great Article."* :/ For me, this looks a lot like  a legacy answer that should not be considered a valid one by today's standards and should be deleted, independent of whether the link answers the question or not. The answer should contain a complete answer, if that is not possible, the question should be closed.

Comment: That being said: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled

Comment: I guess the answer was highly upvoted while being useful, eg, while the link was not broken. Now it is useless as is, so you should just flag normally as you would do with any other answer consisting in just a link.

Comment: Another highly upvoted link only answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8120244/3359432

Comment: also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Trilarion I'm aware of that of course, but THX anyway.

Comment: Wayback machine.

Comment: *"Similar Question"* aka. dupe-source is dealt with too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The review queue takes care of link only answers very fast. (I feel that it's often overzealous, but that's another problem.)

As gnat [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376), in this case we would have to wait for a mod:

> If the outcome of review is deletion, and a post's score prevents it from being deleted, the original flags will be marked "helpful". In these cases, and in cases where the flags are disputed, a new, moderator-only flag will be raised on the post.

Now I know that the mod will agree with the deletion, but I don't know how long that usually takes. It might be fast, because it's a clear decision, but it's likely lower priority because it's old.

It would be wrong to down vote the question for the quality of its answer, however. Questions should be judged separately (otherwise the concept of protection would be counterintuitive).

I honestly doubt that a bounty is needed, either. It's a highly up voted question, and once the answer is deleted, it will be a sitting duck, perched atop a golden egg. A lot of people cared enough to up vote the question, so they obviously would value a good answer (and might up vote it too). It will have high visibility, in any case.

You are free to spend your rep as you please, obviously. But there are other questions out there that might need the visibility more (just look at all the questions that receive "me too" non-answers).

Comment: positive score and accepted answers are [special case in review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/839601). Even if all 6 reviewers recommend deletion, answer stays until diamond moderator decides on it

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the info. There doesn't seem to be much more detail beyond what's there, but I added it anyway.

Comment: @Laurel _"in this case we would have to wait for a mod"_ That was the perfect answer, and was finally solved like that. The question stayed, link only answers were removed and some encouraged user gave a better answer.

Answer (score 14):

### **Fix the links (use archives), when reasonable:**

This is about "**highly upvoted link only answers used as duplicate**". This means that multiple others have already found the answer useful (upvoted). In addition, it is being used as a target for duplicates. This indicates that still others felt that the current answers were sufficient and good enough to close other questions with these as the answers.  In *that* situation, it is better to retain the information, if possible, for people who are seeking the same information in the future.

Obviously, we prefer to have answers here that are complete, at least basically, in and of themselves. However, that does not mean we should deprive readers of being pointed to high quality external information. Particularly when there is no other answer currently available for a question, or when an answer has been highly up-voted.

To me the question is: Is it better to provide no information (i.e. delete the answer), or to have an answer that links to high quality information external to this site?  In my opinion, it is *much better* to provide those seeking answers with the link than to have nothing at all. It is not ideal. But, it does provide a solution to those seeking answers.

Note: There is a whole other discussion about should link-only answers exist. I am not attempting address that here. That is a much broader discussion which is not really, in my opinion, within the specific scope of this question.  This question is specifically about what to do with already existing, highly up-voted link-only answers.

### **Finding archives:**

My goto solution for finding archives is to use the following bookmarklets which will look for archives of the page currently being viewed:

#### Archive.org snapshot listing

```js
javascript:void(window.open('https://web.archive.org/web/*/'+location.href))
```

#### Mementos

Find Mementos (searches multiple archive sites, but may not find some, so should use the other bookmarklets also):

```js
javascript:void(window.open('https://www.webarchive.org.uk/mementos/search/'+location.href+'?referrer='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)))
```

While it sometimes gets more complicated to find archives, using these bookmarklets covers most situations.

#### Google's cache

While it's *not appropriate as an actual archive link*, for relatively recently deleted data, you can look in Google's cache:

```js
javascript:void(window.open('https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:'+location.href))
```

### **Creating archives:**

When adding a reference to an answer, I try to remember to make an archive of the page I am using as a reference or for supplementary information.  This is so it can be made available if the original site goes down.  To do so, I use the following bookmarklets:

Archive.org:

```js
javascript:void(window.open('https://web.archive.org/save/'+location.href))
```

### **Specific to the first answer you list:**

For the first answer you reference, fixing the link would have been trivial.
[I saw your question after the answers which you reference had been deleted.  Thus, I am basing this off of the information you have quoted in your question.]

The link you quoted:
http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html
Provides a single page with internal links. *All of the content is on that single page.* It is, in fact, just a copy of:
http://web.archive.org/web/20060603181849/http://www.linuxprofilm.com/articles/linux-daemon-howto.html

The links you state as, "broken at the second level when crawling in", are supposed to be links internal to the page that just go from the Table of Contents to the section *in that same page*.  Thus, while those internal links are invalid, the entire content was there and presented to the reader. Interestingly, the links are perfectly valid if you disable JavaScript when loading the page from *[www.netzmafia.de](http://www.netzmafia.de)*. Unfortunately, that site uses JavaScript to mangle the links.  For example, from:

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20060603181849/http://www.linuxprofilm.com/articles/linux-daemon-howto.html#s1
```

to

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20060603181849/http://web.archive.org/web/20060603181849/http://www.linuxprofilm.com/articles/linux-daemon-howto.html#s1
```

The second, mangled, link is, obviously, erroneous.

All that would have been needed to restore the answer to the same level of usefulness as it had originally would have been to change the link in the answer from:
http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html
to
http://web.archive.org/web/20060603181849/http://www.linuxprofilm.com/articles/linux-daemon-howto.html
Which would have served the exact same page, just not mangled by the JavaScript on *[www.netzmafia.de](http://www.netzmafia.de)*.

Determining that this was the case took only a couple of minutes, max.

Comment: I don't think that fixing the links or creating an archive is the right action. The problem is already proven as link only answers shouldn't be given. I could consider to write an answer, as I did for the question where I'm looking up for a dupe.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I am not saying that link only answers should be new answers. You asked specifically what to do about *highly upvoted link only answers used as duplicate*. This means that multiple others have already found the answer useful (upvoted). In addition, it is being used as a target for duplicates. This indicates that still others felt that the current answers were sufficient and good enough to close other questions with these as the answers.  In *that* situation, it is better to retain the information, if possible, for people who are seeking the same information in the future.

Comment: Those upvotes could easily have come from a time before link-only answers were discouraged, then banned. "It's upvoted a lot!" isn't the same as "It's a fantastic answer!"

Comment: Imho, the solution to fix broken links with new links that might eventually become broken as well is only a temporary solution. It doesn't solve the problem, it only delays it.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: I upvote answers that help me. A helpful link is helpful. *New* link-only answers should be discouraged but we shouldn't be overzealous with old answers that have proved their usefulness (this question). Until new (better) answer is posted; the old one should stay. "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds."

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian well, we are programmers, consistency is the blood that fills our veins, and the dreaded UB our bane.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian And "this answer was helpful" _does not mean that it was a good answer_. Plenty of bad answers are helpful -- like ones that do nothing but link to another site. It doesn't mean they're _good_ answers. You're right, we shouldn't delete them (unless the link is broken and, somehow, not archived) -- we should copy relevant content into the post so that, for as long as the answer is live, it's an answer to the question. Then it's a good answer, doesn't depend on any other site except as additional explanation, and is still exactly as helpful, if not more.