# Similar answers but different scores (+21 vs -1), failed audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

When I compare [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18556767) answer to the now deleted answer [#52135796](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52135796) on the question [How to simulate POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556680/how-to-simulate-post-request) I consider them very similar. Just a link with which both attempt answer the question asked.

The first one is years old and has earned +21 in votes, the latter was in the review queue as a late answer and was posted last week. Its score was -1.

I audited the answer as 'no action needed', but I honestly think both answers are similar and should be treated as such. I propose to:

- <del>A. Undelete the latter answer, or</del>
- <del>B. Also delete the first answer as to treat both cases in the exact same way.</del>
- C. Delete the first answer and undelete the latter

Or is there a fundamental difference between both I fail to see?

Edit: At the time of writing I hadn't checked the link in the outdated answer. With this new knowledge I propose C. Delete the +20 answer and undelete the -1

Comment: It is worth noting that the link in that answer is virtually dead. It leads to spam, not to something you can use.

Comment: IMO the +20 one should be removed just as the -1 one already is

Comment: @NickA it needs a mod then or we need to vote it to -1 first before we can cast delete votes

Comment: @rene That's a lot of -1s ;o - We'll have to get shog to allow organised voting for situations like this jkjk

Comment: @gnat that will fix the issue with the now outdated answer with the bad link, however, the deleted answer is in fact a solid attempt to answer te question. At the time of writing I hadn't checked the link in the outdated answer. With this new knowledge I propose C. Delete the +20 answer and undelete the -1

Comment: @gnat are you sure? The question asks how to simulate POST. That link once did. Do you think an NAA flag will be successful in the queue?

Comment: @rene I am absolutely sure. Per standard guidance, if you strip the URL, remaining text of the post wouldn't qualify as an answer. The fact that link works or is broken is irrelevant here.

Comment: I'm not thrilled by that deleted answer, btw. I wouldn't vote to undelete.

Comment: @gnat ok let's try that then. I flagged as NAA, if more users do that it needs a lot of *Looks OK* to have that flag declined/disputed. Let's see if the reviewers follow your guidance or not.

Comment: The post was deleted :)

Comment: diamonds interfered with the experiment :(

Comment: @rene From my experience, review tends to get that right, too. So for the future, everyone flag away freely. :)

Comment: And back in '13, the rules for link only were not as strictly enforced as they were today.

Comment: @epascarello well, one can argue that rules were there since at least [July '09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165773). Announcement made in '13 merely added a practical approach to strip markup when evaluating the post and explicitly encouraged moderators to delete link-only stuff

Answer (score 6):

It's a link-only answer to an ad domain. Whether or not it was any good when it was written, it's delete fodder now. If the answerer comes back to defend it it can be undeleted when he fixes the link.

Answer (score 3):

Both are link-only answers and should be deleted according to the current policy of Stack Overflow.

However, do note that the +20 one is from very early days (2013), where the site's stance just began to narrow. Prior to that, there were a lot of now-considered link-only answers voted high up, and was welcomed in fact. That they were taken as good answers doesn't mean that they are still taken as good answers. You should always follow the current policy during the handling of posts.

There are a lot of deleted answers scoring 10+ or even 100+. That they're deleted now doesn't mean they're bad answers. It's just that the site's policy has changed through the ages. Many historical issues. Read [What to do with broken but highly upvoted link only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323508)