# Why does downvoting an answer cost reputation while questions not?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, downvotes, voting

When I downvote an answer, I lose 1 reputation point. But downvoting a question is free.

Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: I have another interpretation for the -1 rep hit when I downvote an answer: it's like a nudge for me to consider improving the answer or writing a better one, so that my successful edit or answer could regain me the internet points that I spent on frowning upon other people's work.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Downvotes are an integral part of the automated system that evaluates question quality and blocks user accounts that can't formulate coherent questions.

People weren't downvoting questions because it was costing them reputation, so we removed the rep cost for questions.  Evaluating questions costs people time; there really shouldn't be any more cost than that to voice your disapproval for an ill-conceived question.

Answers are different.  When I'm posting an answer to a question, I am competing with other answerers for the precious reputations, so there should be a cost for me to downvote their answers.

Comment: I see you point, but the free down vote for questions may encourage unnecessary down votes.

Comment: @mmohab: In practice, free downvotes on questions seem to correctly reflect the quality of the question.

Comment: In general are there some checks if somebody downvotes all other/better scored answers just to have the highest votes answer? I can remember two cases/users who did that.

Comment: @rekire The system will detect this and reverse the serial downvotes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/13

Comment: Free upvotes on questions seem to encourage a lot more unnecessary upvotes of awful content. The system should **give** reputation to people who downvote the crap.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I'm pretty sure the serial voting script only applies to targeting **specific users**, not simply downvoting all / most answers on a post.

Comment: IMO, downvotes are essentially free. `-1` is nothing but a psychological effect.

Comment: Same goes for getting down-voted. I was more unhappy when I got +1/-1 for getting -1 and living with a fact that someone's boldly disagreeing with me with out a comment. I still got a net of +8 rep.  Of course with the exception of being wrong, getting fast -5 and begging to delete proofs of my incompetence. Down-vote's peer pressure is much greater than score pressure/"penalties". *Sorry for a double but I went over 5 mins.*

Comment: Downvoting all of the other answers to give your answer better shot doesn't really help except very early in the answers' lives; you can only downvote them once, after all.

Comment: I have experience with down-voters, just missing some points in question, before I finish editing, someone vote down my question...

Comment: you could make it so that if you posted an answer, it will cost you to downvote someone. if not, it should be free imho

Comment: Not sure for questions, but for answers the default -1 is ok for me, but it would be great if a comment added after the downvote would void the -1, this way I would think it twice about not leaving a comment after downvoting an answer

Comment: @HieuVo - what's stopping you from first typing up the FULL question on text editor, and then posting the CORRECT final version to avoid wasting everyone else's time looking at your half-finished ones?

Comment: Stack Overflow essentially is for programmers of all grades, which is  a great thing, however there is the issue where learning programmers start to down-vote legitimate answers based on a poor understanding.

Comment: Shouldn't the system check if the downvoter has answered the same question and then decide whether to cost them reputation for downvoting other answers or not?
It does not seem fair with people who are trying to improve the community content by putting their opinions or experience on what they think is correct.

Comment: When I have a problem and I am trying the different answers to see if any of those answers solve my problem, I don't downvote the answers that turn out to be incorrect, because of the -1 reputation cost. 

I agree with @NikhilGirraj. I think only those who answer the question should have to pay to downvote other answers; for unbiased users, they should be able to downvote answers that are incorrect without any cost.

Comment: @AndrewBucklin in most cases downvote on truly incorrect answer leads to removal (you can add comment too to make clear why answer is wrong, which encourages fix or more downvotes ). Note that the fact the answer did not work for you does not immediately mean it is bad answer (i.e. question may be asking for something that you are actually not interested in due to the way question is worded).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov When the answer has gotten so many downvotes and 'removal' happens, are the lost downvote reputations refunded to downvoters?

Comment: @andrewbucklin yes.

Comment: I just lost reputation for downvoting what I consider a "dangerously incorrect answer". I have not answered the question myself (as I have yet to find a valid solution to the issue), and I commented as to why the answer was dangerous. I fail to understand the logic of how this makes me a less reputable contributor. I would get it if I hadn't left a comment explaining, as my view is that downvoters who don't provide a reason SHOULD take a reputation hit as silent downvoting adds nothing.

Comment: @pancho: You can't enforce commenting on downvotes.  Here's why: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm not suggesting forcing comments. I'm saying "apply the 1 point reputation hit to people who don't comment, but don't apply it to people who do". People who comment on downvote are far less likely to downvote for tricky reasons ie. to advance their own answer. Thus people have the choice - either comment, or take the 1 point reputation hit (regarding your lorem ipsum, if you do that - you will no doubt be reported and ultimately banned by moderators)

Comment: _"I am competing with other answerers..., so there should be a cost for me"_ is only applicable in the case where you have an answer in the same question.

Comment: It takes the same amount of motivation to either upvote or downvote. Free upvotes and cost for downvotes promotes crappy answers. I thought I could help marking bad answers, but I won't care anymore, why should I? I downvoted a clearly troll answer of a user with reputation 4, who just created an account and threw something in, with spelling errors and making no sense. -1 is not much, but yes, it makes a psychological effect, like I did something wrong.

Comment: Seems ridiculous to be punished for downvoting an answer that doesn't work if I haven't written a competing answer.

Comment: I often see plain **wrong** answers being left alone because people know it costs them some of that 'hard-earned' points. This is **not** helping the community. I DO downvote, but I feel like the sucker taking the punch.

Comment: So does that mean I should not down-vote stupid answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49233857/4427870)  ?

Comment: @Rishav: That's not an answer.  Precisely what the Not an Answer moderator flag is for.

Comment: Yeah thanks I did flag the answer. I just wanted to know if should one down-vote such an answer at one's reputation cost knowing that the answer is going to be removed? Or is the flagging sufficient?

Comment: @Rishav: The goal is deletion.

Comment: I thought I was helping community when down voting wrong answers and just now I realized I'm loosing reputation points with, I'll just stop doing that then.

I understand there is some competition on answers, but then maybe it would make sense to only loose reputation points if you had answered to that question too.

Now I understand why we often find wrong answers still with more points than some right answers which have been answered a bit late.

Comment: I get your point about the war on answers but this is discouraging for reviewers

Comment: "competing with other answerers for the precious reputations" ... is SO about answers or is it about score?

Comment: @ChuckAdams: It's been awhile since I wrote this answer, but I'm pretty sure I wrote that with tongue firmly planted in cheek.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I should have read the snark in, sorry.  Some of the responses seem to be deadly serious though :-/

Comment: I received a downvote for a question, likely because my question was similar to an older post, not for the quality of my question. However, my search didn't find the older post, which either means: (1) I (and other beginner programmers) lack the vocabulary necessary to find the original post, or (2) the search algorithm is imperfect. When I went to delete my downvoted and flagged duplicate question, I received the message "We do not recommend deleting questions with answers..." So I'm penalized for asking a "duplicate" question, but chastised for deleting that question?

Comment: The question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913861/find-substring-not-at-beginning-of-string

Comment: Downvoting an answer must require a comment and should not cost rep. Dinging the community for downvoting an answer will only discourage them and the answer prevent the better answers from bubbling up.

Comment: Down voting non constructive comments costs me rep. I don't get paid to build stackoverflow's business, and I lose reputation for trying to help? What do you think my response will be?

Answer (score 60):

The reasoning for this difference has been laid out in [Stack Exchange blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) as follows:

> ...we’re determined to keep question quality high, even at the cost of refusing a little sand. It’s true that you can’t have Q&A without *questions*, but having the wrong sorts of questions is far more dangerous. The fastest way to kill any Q&A site is to flood it with low-quality questions. I think Mark Trapp summed it up best in [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91808/about-new-downvote-policy-on-meta/91813#91813):
>
> > To put it another way, when I go to a Stack Exchange home page, I see a **list of questions**. If most of those are terrible questions with little to no indication that I’d be wasting my time by reading them, the value proposition of visiting and participating is diminished: I have better things to do.
> >
> > Compare that to *answers* on a specific question: I’ve made a conscious choice to look into what I think is an interesting question. I already made the decision that the question is worth my time. If I find the answers to be useless, I have a few different options, as an interested party, to register my displeasure, including writing my own answer. Being able to write your own answer is key: if your answer is good enough, it’ll rise above the junk answers and everyone will be better off for it.
> >
> > There is no such action for question lists. I can’t say “these questions suck, show me this question I just thought up instead”: that’d be silly. So, it’s imperative the question list have a high signal-to-noise ratio, and removing the penalty for those users who do take the time to read a question and later find it to be useless so they can down-vote is conducive to that.
>
> Fundamentally, answers can be filtered in ways that questions cannot...

Comment: The cited blog post is 8 years old by now and times have changed. I'm still waiting for better filtering techniques even though there has been some effort lately.

Comment: I only downvoted once ever, and it was today for someone's own self response that he marked as the selected answer which was 99% based on someone else's answer. I feel like that should be encouraged, except for times when no one else answered that person's question