# How should we handle the current void of content at Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, meta

How can Stack Overflow meta be relevant when half a decades worth of posts were removed and now have no plan to return ([New Custom Close Reason: Specific Only To A Certain Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230130/178816))?

There are only 400 posts left out of 60,000 for the largest community in the exchange. It took 5 years to accumulate that level of coverage for a depth of issues.

[image]

The truth is that Stack Overflow meta, home to issue solvers for literally millions of questions, 6.6 million users per day, and 8 thousand questions asked daily, needs that content to maintain some semblance of order.

[image]

Before it has been argued new users did not even find Meta Stack Overflow. How are they supposed to find Meta Stack Exchange to know to look for old Meta Stack Overflow content in order to figure out why downvoting costs reputation ([Why does downvoting an answer cost reputation while questions not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-downvote-an-answer-costs-lose-of-reputation-while-questions-not) - asked 4 hours ago)?

These types of questions - of which many have been previously asked, answered, closed, dealt with, or had the help center edited - are now very hard to do anything with but answer. A tedious process considering the volume of the site and the repetitive nature of these type of duplicate questions.

[image]

They can no longer be closed because there are only **400** posts to choose from.  Users no longer get help preemptively because they don't know to look on Meta Stack Exchange instead of Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: I was just thinking about something similar earlier today. A link to the Meta Stack Exchange FAQ knowledgebase, or possibly even a sticky "question" of some sort that just points there, might be useful (at least, to the people who will bother reading and navigating intelligently).

Comment: As soon as I find it, I'll post the answer, but I recall recently seeing an answer from one of the CM's about a long term plan for linking all of the meta's together, which would eliminate most of the issues here.  As I recall, the MSO/MSE split was just the first step.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230105/searching-in-any-meta-site-should-include-results-from-meta-se#comment755815_230105) by Nick Craver?

Comment: @TravisJ no, it was on the old MSO and if I recall, the date was in the October timeframe.  IIRC, I saw it only a few days ago, so probably still in my browser history.  I'll check there.

Comment: @TravisJ [Are meta site questions linked to each other?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198530/are-meta-site-questions-linked-to-each-other) was the question I was thinking of.  Tim's answer really provides some clues as to what the long term plan is.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - The main thing mentioned there was posting a bulletin across the metas similar to the hot network list :( "Tying searches together to the central collection of faq posts may or may not be feasible" was also mentioned, so hopefully that is on the *may* end of the spectrum.

Comment: @TravisJ yeah I know, wasn't quite I remembered honestly.  I think I was remembering the feature request more than the actual answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Well hopefully there is some sort of plan for it, it seems there is. I was just hoping someone could clarify what the plan was for me - or at least clarify how this meta can be made to not seem so .. broken isn't really the right word, but it isn't working as well as it should at the moment.

Comment: what is it exactly that you are asking for?  im confused

Comment: @RobertLevy - The context of this was really when the metas were just split. Now that there are at least 4000 posts here, it is less likely for new users to be posting the same question in such high frequency, and there is a lot of good new content to actually compose a meta. At the time there was a lot of spam and some discontent (re: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/1026459)

Comment: i understand the context.  but what are you asking for or suggesting?

Comment: @RobertLevy - Nothing anymore. At the time, this post was paired alongside a few other posts from other users which were trying to determine if we could migrate content from MSE back to MSO. The question here was asking for some guidance on whether or not that was possible or if there were any alternatives to this (hence the support tag and open ended "what can be done" topicality). This issue was mostly resolved by simply waiting, which was the semi-official response to the content issue here. This question has lost most of its relevance at this time as MSO has a decent level of content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow - I just double checked and my original answer is totally invalid - there is no *Migrate to Meta.SE* option under the off topic close reasons.

To me this is odd - a lot of the questions being posted here will need to be moved there but there is no way for the community to do it...

This means you're currently restricted to voting to close as off topic and leaving a comment, or flagging for a ♦ mod to move it. If they receive enough flags the mods will likely add a custom off topic option for it.

> How are they supposed to find Meta Stack Exchange to know to look for old Meta Stack Overflow content in order to figure out why downvoting costs reputation

Don't concentrate on closing it as a duplicate - instead vote to migrate it to Meta.SE. When it gets migrated a marker question gets left here and clicking on it redirects to the new location - the new user learns about Meta.SE.

If it is a duplicate on Meta.SE then it can get closed as such once it is migrated there.

Once you've cast your close vote you could optionally leave a comment directing the new person to Meta.SE (just in case it doesn't make it to the threshold for closure).

These repetitive questions are gonna get asked day in, day out, like they always have - there's nothing we can do about that. At least if there have been a few migrated and closed here then they will show up as possible duplicates when the user is typing up the question.

Comment: From what I've seen ... somewhere, they prefer that you post issues on the child Meta (not Meta SE), and typically decline flags requesting that things be migrated from here to there (i.e. your VTC / flag paragraph is somewhat inconsistent with what you "should" do). SE is somewhat hypocritical regarding trying to prevent duplication. Although maybe enough flags will wear them down...