# Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?

Tags: discussion, voting, asking-questions

I've been using Stack Overflow for a few years, and initially most questions you asked got a positive reception: happy comments and answers, people that tried to help you out regardless of the way you worded it. Of late the tendency is to simply close or put on hold most questions, or downvote them, or make fun of the writing or the style.

I use GameDev SE too, and I find it much more positively minded. As a simple metric, compare my [questions on GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/15277/geotarget?tab=questions) vs my [questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294758/geotarget?tab=questions). See the multitude of closed questions and/or downvotes on Stack Overflow, while on GameDev every question was well received and has at least one answer.

Now I don't have files of hard facts to prove anything apart from a [growing feeling](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=stackoverflow%20sucks) that Stack Overflow is becoming very negative of late. Pretty much every [intelligent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957350/is-the-vc-code-dom-accessible-from-vs-addons) I've tried to ask of late gets downvotes, while [silly technical issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915543/how-are-denormalized-floats-handled-in-c-sharp-apps) get well received.

Firstly, why is this? Is it that moderators are getting egoistic about their powers and like to close or "put on hold" questions as a kind of power display? Is it growing frustration with "noobs" who ask "silly questions" that "should be deleted"? Or is it just that programming is a tough job and makes once happy people into irritable people because they're facing horrid technical issues day in, day out?

Secondly, whatever the case, whatever the cause, what can be done to improve the attitude (positivity) of the Stack Overflow users/moderators such that you don't feel scared to ask a question?

I'm not trying to criticize anybody or make a statement, I'm actually asking this out of desperation. The most useful, incredible programming community on the web is turning sour, and I really don't know what I should change (even in myself) to help make it work.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Thank you for this discussion!

As a *clear* noob, I have a few suggestions which would be very helpful for me (*as a noob*) to understand how **not** to annoy people so much.

1. HIGH-REP PEOPLE: I came here to get better at something very difficult. I *look up to you* and think you are awesome. *I am not trying to annoy you*. Don't make the mistake of treating me like a child by simply anonymously downvoting something I ask that you don't like. Tell me, *please*. I don't care - say something MEAN if you have to:
   "too long", "already asked" "google search this", "obvious homework problem". I would rather be embarrassed five times in a row and finally GET IT than annoying everyone forever.

   Which brings me to my concrete requests …
2. A mandatory voting dropdown menu should be required for ALL DOWNVOTING. This should not affect overall rep points, but if people simply cannot be bothered to say why a question/answer is bad, offenders will NEVER get better. The menu should be simple; again, it would just be helpful to know "too long", "already asked", "too general", "too short", "not clear", "bad grammar", "other" …anything is better than nothing. Please consider this! It does not need to be anything fancy, but if someone can click once to downvote, they can click twice to select an option from a dropdown.
3. A ranking feature, in addition, or in place of or in addition to the voting. Simple ranks maybe - beginner, moderate, and expert. That way, if I am a noob, I can easily find all the noob questions to answer. When I become moderate I can look at those. Then, for all you experts out there complaining of repeated questions - you won't have to be BORED! If you answer noob ranked questions, you will know what you are signing up for.

   I would not mind getting downvotes so much if they could actually be USEFUL. I have other noob friends on this site and sometimes it feels like people downvote solely because of rep point bias. I don't care as much about "negative" or "grumpy" attitudes as I do that this site and community ADAPTS and PROGRESSES with the changing circumstances.

   If the only presence that a noob can have on here is a *burden* then this site and community has already failed and you are going to be responsible for that, not the noobs.

Answer (score 553):

> Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?

I hate to pile on, but I couldn't resist summarizing the problem.
And I apologize ahead of time for any potentially offensive language that I might use.

Basically there are 4 camps of users on Stack Overflow:

1. The "caretakers" who want to keep the site clean and with good content.
2. The "help vampires" who flood the site with bad/duplicate questions who only want their question answered and care nothing for the site.
3. The "repwhores" who answer everything they can (or can't).
4. The ones who no longer give a shit.

These camps are not mutually exclusive. Personally, I started as a 3. Now, I'm half-way between 1 and 4.

But for the most part:

- 2 and 3 love each other. They should get married.
- 1 hates 2 because they're flooding the site making good questions impossible to find.
- 1 hates 3 because they're encouraging 2 to keep going.
- 2 hates 1 because 1 constantly downvotes/closes/deletes/flames 2.
- 3 hates 1 because they keep closing/deleting the questions that 3 likes to answer.
- 1 and 3 have all the moderation powers, but only 1 cares to use them.
- 4 is sitting on the sideline shaking their heads...
- 1 hates 4 because 4 isn't helping the situation.

With so much hate, there's going to be conflict.

---

Artist's impression added with permission ([dot source](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7325869/))

[image]
<sub>[Image credit to sehe.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16055493#16055493)</sub>

Comment: I think you are missing a camp: 5. Those users who visit the site to solve their problems, and who like to help others. Like 1 they want to have nice content, but their number one criterion is "is it helpful (and civil)"? They don't care much about "is it a good match for SE/constructive" and are frustrated by the deletionism of 1. They dont't care much about 2, answer the questions if it is not much effort, otherwise ignore them. They don't care about 3 either, and find the grudge of 1 against 3 silly. Let them have the rep they can get, if they're having fun and contributing useful content.

Comment: this may be the best answer ever posted on MSO

Answer (score 455):

I interacted with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229058/sql-select-lowest-20-record yesterday.

- The OP had done so little research that it was answered correctly, without enough information to answer it correctly, in 49 seconds
- A 70k and a 30k user interacted without voting to close
- It got 3 answers, 2 incorrect (one of these because the OP didn't provide enough information)
- The question got *5* upvotes
- Both incorrect answers got an upvote

This is extremely depressing. Acutely depressing. To the point of "I quit".

This site was meant to provide a canonical resource for programmers to find answers to their questions. It's becoming a place where people who should never have been employed as a programmer, and who can't even be bothered to read the documentation, post mind-numbingly awful questions asking the community to debug their code. Here's my code dump, fix it for me.

That's not to say that these people can't be rescued. I think I may have rescued someone yesterday - they responded well in the comments and now have a chance of creating decent questions. However, it took me probably 15 minutes over the course of a few hours to *maybe* rescue one person. There simply isn't the resources to do this with everyone - especially as most don't seem to want to be rescued.

Add into this mix the race to get reputation, which leads people to answer everything, however crap. Everyone's done this on occasion, myself included, but it's depressing to see moderators continually answering duplicates. Because even the high-rep users do this, and they're normally better at answering questions, and doing so quickly, the lower rep users have a smaller chance of gaining reputation. So, they emulate their supposed betters and type *something* in the hope of eking out that little bit of reputation.

Hence, rudeness.

There are maybe at most 30,000 users trying to stem the tide of unbelievably poor questions and answers crafted by hundreds of thousands in a vain effort to keep this site the way it was originally imagined to be and the way they'd like it to remain. They're failing and slowly giving up.

I *really* care about this, about this site being a good community; somewhere where people can come and get answers to their questions. I've learnt so much from here and helped so many other people that I'm proud of this place. The perceived negativity is just an attempt to keep it that way.

Or I might be being overly dramatic.

Comment: please.. allow me to say that depression often lead to strong sentence. When you **believe** that "people who should never have been employed as a programmer" should be not allowed to write (for example), you are making a really, really strong assumption. We should agree that this could lead to problems and try to find a right, non drastic, working solution. **Nothing** should **never** **justify drastic solutions**. Because human make errors. **Always**

Comment: I'm well known for being grumpy, but I have to agree with Ben. To the extent that the ability to express thoughts in a clear manner is a requirement for being a programer, then there are a lot of people on [so] who should not be programmers. I blame the Internet copy-paste-from-an-example culture for this. More copying, less reading, less intelligence. How much intelligence does it take to copy and paste?

Answer (score 250):

In two words: because crap.

Now to be serious, keep in mind that there is a limited set of "regulars" who actually answer all the questions. They make the core of Stack Overflow and they see hundreds and thousands of questions, then they answer what they can.

Once upon a time, there were not many questions being asked, so it was easy to pick the good questions, give proper answer and continue happily ever after.

But as Stack Overflow becomes more and more popular, more and more questions are being asked and naturally, major part of them are, plainly put, crap. Too trivial, shows no efforts whatsoever, unclear, pick your choice. Finding the good questions that can actually be answered becomes harder every day.

So those regular users do their best to preserve quality by attacking the bad posts and trying to educate the users, sometimes being harsh while doing so.

I fear it's an endless loop and honestly can't see any improvement in the future, so those who want real help and do ask proper questions will have to grow thick skin to pass the initial sting and all will be good.

Comment: "So those regular users do their best to preserve quality by attacking the bad posts and trying to educate the users, sometimes being harsh while doing so." - I don't quite agree on this part. The problem, as I see it, is that **the vast majority of these "regulars" don't appear to care about quality of posts / this site at all**. If they did, these questions won't often get answers and we'd likely weed them out quite quickly.

Comment: Don't forget that sometimes its hard to decide which of the 20 duplicates to use in the duplicate-close-vote

Comment: I have to agree with both @Liam and Shadow here. If I have to ask a question on SO, I've not done my research - because *almost* everything these days has been asked before). It would be nice for low rep users (<= 500?) to be rewarded for finding duplicates so that their first questions aren't crap. Once they get to grips with asking (> 500 rep) then hopefully they'd ask better questions.

Answer (score 158):

> Of late the tendency is to simply close or put on hold most questions, or downvote them

Yes, that's what we are supposed to do with poor questions.

> or make fun of the writing or the style.

No, that's what the community used to do, back before the "Summer of Love" campaign started to outlaw the practice.  I see no evidence myself that this is coming back.  It is a self-protection mechanism of any community, meant to make newcomers feel unwelcome.

Outlawing the practice certainly has been quite effective, SO has changed a great deal since then with a glut of help-desk questions being asked every day.  Especially noticeable, to me anyway, in the past 6 months.  I spend an excessive amount of time as of late trying to find a question that interests me enough to do the research to answer it.  And the number of downvotes I have in my profile caught up with the number of upvotes, all on poor questions.

I don't think it is just me that's noticing this.  I also see other experts leaving.  This is a death-knell for any community that relies on such users to answer the hard technical questions and their unusual productivity.  This sobering trend is visible in SEDE data I collected for 12 high rep users that are still active, plotting the number of answers they posted by month:

[image]

I eliminated the vacation months and the last month with incomplete data (March 2014).  Clearly this is not a problem caused by a lack of questions, I posit that it is caused by the kind of questions we allow to enter the system.

There are other side-effects as well, SO has experienced geometric growth since its inception.  That has stopped in fall of last year, something you can see from the [quantcast.com statistics](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?qcLocale=en_US).

Sobering stuff, I see no good ways to turn this around and still stay in line with the goals set by the StackExchange owners and enforced by the moderators.  Hopefully they are aware of it.

Comment: I am not in your league or the top 12 people you mention, but I do post a fair amount of answers. The problem I encounter is this, `I spend an excessive amount of time as of late trying to find a question that interests me enough to do the research to answer it`. I would really like to answer, dissect, and work through complex well researched issues but they are a diamond in the rough. I was unaware that this was a larger problem because I thought "must be the wrong time of day", or "everyone must have already gone home", or something along the lines of a third-party not being involved.

Comment: A longitudinal plot of just 12 users doesn't seem very credible. Any number of personal reasons could explain decline of individual usage. More useful would be a survey of top users, to which you have contributed your input here.

Answer (score 151):

### A summary of what's been said so far

Have you ever met someone who *used to* believe in [Utopia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia)? Someone who bought into the inherent goodness of human nature, the potential of humanity to create their own heaven on earth, in the inevitable triumph of peace, love and all that other hippie crap... Only to have it burned out of them by repeated exposure to the *reality* of human nature?

Good lord, ain't they *bitter!*

So we have folks who expect to be greeted with open arms, their contributions lauded and all their needs met. And they're disappointed, because not every question gets an answer, and not every answer gets immediate recognition.

And we have folks who expect every post to be useful and informative, the folks asking questions to have done their research and those posting answers to elaborate on how they arrived at the solution. And *they're* disappointed, because this isn't the case either.

Some of them leave, searching for greener pastures. Others stick around, making sure everyone learns *just how disappointed they are* that [things aren't the way they used to be and never were](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251897/off-topic-questions-have-to-be-cleared-out-of-the-way-but-not-via-closure/251908#251908).

And some accept that there's value in what we're doing, even if it's done *by and for* a bunch of selfish, bigoted, short-sighted [jackasses](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/).

None of this is going to change. The conversion of wide-eyed idealists into bitter, angry militants is as inevitable as it is pointless. But there are things we *can* change...

### Solvable problems

There are two huge problems facing Stack Overflow right now, and they are not unrelated:

- **Information is poorly organized.** Yes, I'm talking about duplicates. No one in their right mind should be asking about "headers already sent" (though of course, [they still are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241369/warning-when-upload-portal-on-webguru-host)), but there are thousands of more obscure topics that are duplicated without being marked as such, and useful information is obscured as a result.

  *Solution:* divorce duplicate-marking from closing, provide rewards for *solving someone's problem by pointing to an existing question.*
- **Too many low-quality questions.** By which I mean, questions that are useful to *no one else*. This isn't about effort, or even research (although lack of effort can *lead* to this, and lack of research clearly exacerbates #1) - in many cases, it's a fundamental misunderstanding of what these sites are *for*, a [tragedy of the commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) leading to "personal advice" questions whose answers will never be found or used by anyone else.

  *Solution:* Treat question-creation as a shared resource, limit access to those who do not make good use of it. Existing limits attempt to strike a balance between generous enough for those contributing constructively and those behaving abusively; new, more strict limits should be enacted and loosened for those who actually *demonstrate* constructive behavior.

Will these changes make Stack Overflow less "negative"? Absolutely not; people are awful, and there are a *lot* of people on Stack Overflow. But if successful, they will make the site more accommodating for those willing to take a positive attitude *in spite of* that.

Comment: This was a pretty depressing discussion but your suggestions bring some much needed light. Rewarding finding duplicates sounds like a step in the right direction and I would like to hear more details about your second bullet.

Answer (score 116):

I think one thing that adds significantly to the negative trend is the flood of homework questions. Homework questions tend to be of a poor quality and have many problems: no research or effort made by the poster, the poster is unwilling to actually learn anything, outright code begging with copy/paste of homework assignment, "what's wrong with this huge blob of code" etc etc.

SO used to have a homework tag, which you were supposed to tag your homework questions with, thereby allowing people who were deadly tired of them to ignore that tag. But the tag was removed in some policy change and deemed irrelevant.

Then there was another strange, sneaky update recently that changed the available close reasons. The close reason saying that the poster must demonstrate minimum knowledge about the topic was removed. It was replaced with "there is not enough details to answer the question", which for some reason needs to co-exist with the the already present close reason "unclear what you are asking".

Generally, the trend of the site seems to be to expect less out of new users. We are supposed to manually educate everyone and their mother about how to use the site, instead of expecting them to put some minimum effort of their own into it, such as reading the [fundamental "about" page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

A veteran user who spends many hours on the site is supposed to spend even more time in "educating" some kid who just posts a copy/paste of his homework, completely ignorant to site policies and completely unwilling to learn anything, or even stay on the site once his homework is done. Chances are, it's a hopeless case and the new user adds nothing of value to the community, so why waste time on them? The sensible thing to do would be just to delete the crap question and move on.

People come to the site to learn/teach about *programming*, not to teach people how to interact with other human beings. That's what schools and parents are for.

Answer (score 84):

**It all started with the [Summer of Love](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)**

> Every community starts out needing to recruit members, so they tend to be very friendly to newcomers.
>
> After a few years, an insider group of old-timers forms. They get to
> know each other. They know the rules. They know the history and the
> legends of the community. And it’s only natural to get little bit
> irritated when newbies show up who don’t know the rules.
>
> Newbies will show up, make a newbie mistake, like wearing shoes
> indoors or forgetting to close the toilet lid, and the old-timers will
> look at each other, roll their eyes, and snort, “Typical!”
>
> At this point, if it’s a normal human community, it will start to feel
> a little bit unfriendly to outsiders. Insular.
>
> And the newbies will say, “well, gosh, that’s not a very friendly
> place.”

So we were nice. We were welcoming. We flagged the snarky old-timers into submission and we welcomed the first-timers with hugs and quick bug fixes. We were so nice that we forgot the [core values](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

The site became a place where anyone was welcome, regardless of skill level or desire to learn. And the user base grew.

**I went to the Summer of Love and all I got was this nasty itch**

Predictably, the fundamental character of the site changed. It is no longer a place for professional or enthusiast programmers. Some of them are still around, but they are being drowned in a sea of unenthusiastic, rather-be-using-Excel users who ask dull, uninformed questions over and over again. Their dullness has transformed the community from a vibrant interesting place to one where the experts are either bored, angry, or absent.

**We need a Winter of Death**

If this site is to become vibrant and useful again, it must return to its core values. We must reject the non-enthusiasts and kill their questions. We must wound their spirits and make them stop posting drivel. We must disabuse them of the notion that SO is a free help desk designed to solve *their particular problems.* By doing so, we will help to ensure that the enthusiasts get the attention they deserve and their good questions will re-energize the professionals. The site will be saved.

**We will help them even as we reject their input**

The stated goal of the site is to publish useful question and answer pairs. Those pairings, if done right, will answer the casual Googlers' questions before they even create a StackExchange account. We will stem the tide of duplicate and half-closed questions that crowd out the good questions and answers. To make it work, we need intelligent askers and informed answerers working together. Everyone else should simply enjoy the show.

**You have the power to solve the problem**

Gamification is a big part of this site. We reward people when we:

- answer their questions
- upvote their questions, answers, and posts
- view their questions (the view counter increments)

We express our disapproval when we:

- downvote
- comment to explain why they were wrong

Closing is useful too, but that is mostly for us and future site visitors and often takes a long time to have an effect. If you want to send a message to the ones who are causing the problem, actively downvote their bad posts. This includes:

- Uninformed questions. If they could get the answer by searching our site or Google, downvote. The question isn't useful and shows no research effort.
- Uninformed answers. If the answer is wrong or incomplete, it isn't useful.
- Correct answers to uninformed questions. This one is controversial, but stick with me for a minute: When we answer bad questions, we reward the bad askers. Most of the site regulars know not to answer bad questions, but we should help inform other users of the site by downvoting their answers, too *even when they are technically correct.* The downvote tab says "This answer is not useful." If the answer encourages bad behavior, it is *definitely* not useful.

Forget the love. This site is special and unique. When the non-enthusiasts post their drivel, smack their little hands and express your disapproval; remind them that they are allowed to look and admire, but they may not handle it lest they break it.

Answer (score 53):

It's not the moderators to blame [for this].

It's because the initial [wrong] decision to choose an *[ochlocracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ochlocracy)* as a ruling force for this site.

On Stack Overflow we have a mob rule at its best:

Apparently, experienced users are outnumbered by noobs. Either because experts are scarce in general and because they don't have time to hang around all day long. As a result we have a site filled with uneducated "enthusiasts", and thus we can see all that mess:

- Uneducated folks tend to flood the site with pointless questions, making rare good questions sink so fast that only a bounty, manually attached to the latter, can give it a chance.
- Uneducated folks tend to answer mostly simple and repetitive questions
- Uneducated folks tend to vote on mostly obvious answers
- Uneducated folks tend to give a kick to a question they don't understand - your case.

The problem is: this site is attracting them in great numbers. With all these shiny badges and rep points that never attract a mature person but always make a teenager inspired.

If you take another example of extremely popular collaborative-edited site - Wikipedia - you will see that there is not a trace of ochlocracy! There is a community of trusted editors who keeps an eye on the quality. **This is how things have to be done.**

Yet I bear no illusion towards Stack Overflow. It will keep the same way. Live with it or leave it (or get thrown out by the mods will watch silently at your struggle with ignorant folks, never giving a hand, but who never lose an opportunity if you lose your temper at last).

Answer (score 52):

My take: (largely speaking from experience ... unfortunately)

- Too many very low quality posts and too many people encouraging it (with answers and/or upvotes), leading to an overall more negative outlook by those who view the posts as very low quality (i.e. more downvoting / close voting or flagging for those who don't really deserve it, and more negative comments).
- People downvote instead of voting / flagging to close because:

  - They think that's 'nicer' (... ?).
  - They think the question should be closed but either can't find the correct close reason (due to the somewhat recent changes to the close reasons) and / or the question needs a custom close reason, which they're unable to provide (short of using a custom moderator flag) as they have < 3k reputation ... or they're feeling lazy.
- People comment to indicate what's wrong with posts rather than or in addition to downvoting / voting or flagging to close (ironically generally making very little impact to the overall quality of posts). And trying to lead the endless masses onto the right path in vain (because most people just don't seem to want to improve) can make one negative.

  These people might eventually give up and just resort to downvoting / voting or flagging to close (without the comment), perhaps more generously than one should.

Comment: how can anyone improve their questions now or in the future if nobody comments on downvotes? If someone downvotes me, tell me why so i can learn and improve. Isn't that what Stack Overflow is all about?

Answer (score 52):

> Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?

You are generalizing. This is certainly not true of some sub-communities in less popular tags.

> Why is <strike>Stack Overflow</strike> popular tag X sub-community so negative of late?

The Stack Overflow model with *fixed parameters for privileges* does not always *scale* well.

1. *No threshold to ask questions*: Asking questions is *the most important privilege*, but Stack Overflow requires *nothing* to ask a question. Therefore, there is *very little vested interest* in asking a *good* question, which includes *not asking duplicates*. As long as it costs them *nothing* but the time it takes type/copy the question, there will always be bad questions from new users. The popular languages/technologies attract a *lot* of new users. The followers of related tags are overrun by bad questions.
2. *Fixed thresholds for other privileges*: Take close votes for example. No matter how popular the tag is, it takes the same 5 votes and the same rep threshold to cast a vote. This means it takes *relatively* few votes from *relatively* low rep users in popular tags as compared to less popular tags to close a question. This help does balance #1, but not in an ideal manner. In a popular tag, you will always have *many* users that misuse privileges.

> What might be done?

1. Require *some cost* to ask questions to encourage *more vested interest*. A *minimal* cost would be the effort to register. A *minimal* cost would be clicking through the [two-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Give some rep points for these activities and require *minimal* rep to ask a question. You registered *or* took the tour? Now you have the rep to ask a question. You got downvoted and lost that privilege? Take the tour if registered or visa versa to gain it back. Or answer a little quiz about the FAQ and gain it back *one time*. Right now we have *no cost to the new user* to ask but an *investment of the community* to weed out or educate bad new users. These costs need to be reversed.
2. Consider assigning *some* privileges on a per tag basis, first tag prevailing, with different thresholds so that (a) sub-communities are protected (b) large communities scale.

   - Example of (a): New users ask a Clojure question that relates to Java interop. Woe unto thee, new user, that tags [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure)[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)! For you have brought down all of the Java followers upon yourself with all their close votes that may find your question dealing with Clojure specifics unclear. So, perhaps the Java users should be given the privilege to edit out the Java tag if it does not pertain, but not close the question unless they also have some experience/rep with Clojure?

> What can *I* do?

Answer more questions, and/or eventually perform more moderation duties yourself. If you have a large ratio of questions to answers, you may find yourself with different opinions if you were to try to even out that ratio. You can also get a little perspective on why an answerer might need a timeout if you spend some time in the review queues and can help weed out some of the frustrating questions.

Comment: In fact, [registration is required to post a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163/159251) (on Stack Overflow, not other SE sites). And there is [a badge for looking through the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103797/how-does-the-analytical-badge-work).

Comment: Good. Now make the question ban transparent by tying it to rep. Most new users aren't even aware such a thing exists and therefore don't know the stakes of asking bad questions. For example, set the rep floor to -15 and require -10 to ask a question. Give clear warnings, "Your reputation is low. At least -10 reputation is required to post questions. Read the FAQ for help writing better questions and other ways to gain reputation. As a bonus, we'll give you +10 reputation for taking a short quiz at the end."

Comment: +1 for _This is certainly not true of some sub-communities in less popular tags_

Comment: @A.Webb Put that comment in the post!

Comment: No, you are wrong. It should be `Why are popular tags [list all tags] sub-communities [add "all"] so negative of late?`

Comment: The negative trend is certainly there for all the main tags, such as the mainstream programming language tags.

Comment: Nice potential solution.  Guarantee new users have read the FAQ by making it the only way to gain enough rep to ask a question. Simple and (I'd think) effective.

Answer (score 36):

I'm a somewhat high-rep user (approaching 90k now) who long ago posted many answers (thousands) but now hardly posts any.

From my perspective, the simple fact is that pretty much all of the well-written well-asked generic questions have already been answered. This leads to only two kinds of questions: the kind where the asker didn't do their due diligence, cause if they did they'd have found the duplicate, and the kind where they didn't find an answer because it's too specific. There are a few more questions running through the cracks between these two but hardly any.

In addition, the high popularity of the site means it attracts all comers- even the ones we don't want, the ones who treat it like Google or a book or something.

Therefore, I believe the only effective solutions will either offer a kind of Code Google, where you put in some code and you get back existing questions/answers that are similar, or offer proper discussion functionality- for example, have a button to ask a question in a tag-specific chatroom. (Please, dear God, keep the C++ room and the Lounge separate) or a forum or both.

Edit: There's always the broken window of how chat never, ever gets any new features or bugfixes. It's a big reminder of how nobody gives a shit every time you log in and you see the same old broken flag system and stuff.

Comment: "This leads to only two kinds of questions: the kind where the asker didn't do their due diligence, cause if they did they'd have found the duplicate, and the kind where they didn't find an answer because it's too specific." I am guilty of making those two kinds of questions. :(

Comment: I agree with the second paragraph somewhat.  We will never return to when the most basic and fundamental questions are available to be answered.  Maybe we could remove all questions from the site so that there is plenty of rep to go around again :)  Or maybe just do it for one day and we advertise in advance so people can get rep ... Just kidding.  But, this topic reduced environment does create more effort needed to gain reputation and helps to urge on both rep whores and those who would like to be trusted users to go after less quality questions.

Comment: A third type of question that adds to the negativity:  **Questions that ask how to break accepted SO conventions**.  As a new user, my best and favorite question got a number of downvotes because too many experienced users thought "don't do that" was an acceptable and complete answer.  But you're otherwise right-- I either research and answer my own questions, or they're 0 vote 0 answer minutiae.

Answer (score 27):

Here is perspective of a relatively new programmer.

One of the hardest part about learning how to program is figuring out how to ask the right question.

Many times what I ask and what I need are not the same thing. Nothing is more frustrating then sifting through hundreds of pages of documentation looking for solution that *sounds* right. In short, asking good questions requires having proper context which is very, very difficult.

So, yes. Having a guide that says, "Hey, you are asking the wrong question. I'm closing this question for now, but come back after you read this" is extremely valuable feedback to the user and it helps the community.  First, the link to the reference will help the original poster and other new users.  Second, follow-up questions will be more focused and contextually relevant.

My modest proposal is that the community should assume the better nature of the poster.  Instead of implying they are lazy, assume they lack context to ask good questions. That attitude shift alone would help a lot.

And for the 1% of you making English competency an issue.... 90% of programming literature is written in English. Imagine having to learn a spoken language before you could even begin to address your technical issues. Then, when you finally do ask a question your technical issues get dismissed because you used the wrong verb tense in your sentences. Is it too much to help the poor guy out? Edit their questions and point them to the right resource so they know what to get translated. The amount of gratitude felt by the poster for your small gesture is impossible for Westerners to comprehend. The conditions I have observed Indians and Asians learning how to code would surprise you. In many cases they are literally coding their way out of poverty.

Answer (score 26):

This is not the first time this has been discussed. "Why so mean?"

**The answer always turns out to be the same: The influx of crap is too high.** We *know* the answer to this question.

Now, let's rather discuss how to **build tools to manage** the "crap stream" more efficiently. We will not find a perfect solution but we'll be able to mitigate the problem partially.

Here are some ideas:

1. Reduce the vote-to-close count from 5 to 3. In my experience, almost all questions reaching 3 votes also reach 5 eventually. Reduce the burden and close faster.
2. Detect questions likely to be closed using Bayes machine learning and reduce the close barrier further to just 2 close votes.
3. A/B test multiple text messages for educating askers before they ask. Determine which one is best.
4. Reinstate the close reason "lack of minimal understanding". It might not be pristine but it addresses the bigger problem: Closing off crap.
5. Make closing as duplicate less time consuming. At the moment I personally never bother to find a duplicate although it must clearly exist.

With these ideas I just want to show that it is possible to mitigate the crap problem partially. I do not endorse any specific idea from this list. That's not the point.

Answer (score 19):

I think part of it is resource exhaustion, analogous to mining for natural resources. Think of unanswered topics as oil, and rep as money that you can get by drilling for the oil (asking/answering).

When SO first started, it had the last forty years or so of software development to mine for useful questions and turn them in to rep by answering them. The community has done a great job covering all these topics, and those big reserves of unanswered topics are rather well exploited at this point. Truly new topics are only going to pop up at the rate of technological change or novel applications of our existing software tech. So potential rep is more scarce than it used to be.

At the same time our user population is growing. Like with natural commodities, more people competing over scarce resources could make things turn nasty, especially in the face of highly visible "wealth" inequality. To a new user, SO might look like a post-mining-boom economy, with the incumbents sitting on a bunch of rep wealth that they made back during the initial boom time when those reserves were there for the taking. And because the territory is pretty well staked out and exhausted now, there's not much way for them to catch up.

Comment: @MichaelT, Andrew meant separating them into two different sites. *"The 'toilet' which no one wants to go"*? You'd be surprised when this 'toilet' get more views and users than the main site. **And that's not a problem**, A small site where "nub" questions are disallowed can perfectly co-exist with a big *toilet* site where they are allowed. **The problem is Stackoverflow wants to be both**, directly violating ['do one thing and do it well'](http://goo.gl/t0nREH). And that's a problem **we can't fix**, because management (*jo* *cough \* el) has priority on SO becoming big and famous and all.

Answer (score 17):

I do not know for sure if things are getting more negative(that is pretty subjective obviously) - but I will admit that I am having a lot harder time answering/understanding questions in the past year or so.

I remember when I started answering questions in the Excel tag it was actually a lot of fun. I learned a lot - from people like Siddharth Rout, brettdj, barry houdini and Tim Williams. I gained reputation very easily. I figured if I spent a couple years on here I would be well over 10,000 rep points. (I don't care about rep but that was just my prediction at the time).

But recently, the questions seem (to me) to have become lower and lower in quality. By "lower and lower in quality" I mean a few different things:

1. the question is poorly written/explained - often showing very
   poor English grammar skills.
2. the question (or a very similar one) has already been answered an
   innumerable number of times - which could have been found out with a
   simple web search
3. the question shows such little knowledge of basic Excel
   functionality that I often feel it is more useful to the question
   asker to suggest that they should "learn excel" before they try to
   do anything else with it. (in reality I don't say this because it
   would be dickish - but that is what I am thinking)

The Excel tag is somewhat unique compared to other tags - there are many people who don't consider Excel a proper programming subject. I do certainly. But I do feel it is being overwhelmed by people who would be better off going on superuser because their questions are not computer science by any standard. You could probably move a good percentage of the questions to superuser.

I do notice the same trend in the VBA and Excel VBA tags - so it might not be unique to just the Excel tag.

Another problem that is related but somewhat separate from just being "stupid" are the people who basically want you to do their work for them. These people are not "stupid" - they are often quite intelligent - which makes their exploitation of the system all the more "criminal".

I honestly don't care about reputation as much as I care about improving/learning new things - and that has somewhat declined on stack overflow - I find I learn much more from the [Mr. Excel forums](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/forum.php).

I think people like myself could do more good for stack overflow as moderators than by answering questions - but frankly I started using stack overflow for selfish reasons(to learn more) and being a mod is not a task/job that I envy or would ever be willing to do. Especially not for free.

I am glad this question has gotten up voted so much. It seems many people are starting to feel the same way.

Comment: Reputation is the culprit. I wonder why it's been 7 years but no one has suggested **removing the reputation system** on SO. Want to destroy Wikipedia? Give editors/posters reputation and I guarantee you its quality will half every year. It's as powerful as Moore's law, except this time, inversed.

Comment: Reputation can be a good thing but it needs to be managed. This entire thread says: "HEY MODS! Something is very broken and we need to fix it!" ie the problem is the result of an unbalanced system; one that is currently rewarding bad questions and bad answers.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry, going meta here, because apparently there is nothing new under the sun.

This is typical of the way that online communities evolve.

Experienced users get fed up with new users because they're not experienced, and make the same mistakes because they don't know they're mistakes yet.  Participating becomes less and less fun, and more and more like Work. G*d Forbid.  And the newbies feel unfairly excluded because they're not part of The Club.

It was true in the days of Wild West Usenet, and it happens even now. It's a "FAQ entry" you will have internalized if you've ever participated in online communities before.

I've been involved in several over the decades, and they have without exception trended in this direction.  Everything I've read in this discussion has had its analogue in the events of those others.

A humorous take on this can be found at http://everything2.com/title/E2+is+unfriendly+to+New+Order

Answer (score 16):

I can only offer some additional statistics illustrating the voting behaviour change over time.

The first vote on StackOverflow questions and answers was usually "up" in 95% of cases between Aug-2008 and Apr-2011 but has been steadily declining since then.

The first vote on answers has always been up in roughly 95% of cases.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/185792/239997/initial-quality-timeseries

[image]

Of course this doesn't explain *why* the behaviour has changed.

The OP compared SO to GameDev so here is the same graph for that site:

[image]

P.S. "all" includes non-question, non-answer post types too.

Comment: _2011-05-12: Question downvotes [are "free" to the downvoter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free/90927#90927) and will not be subject to a -1 rep penalty. Downvotes to answers are unaffected and still "cost" 1 reputation to cast._ ([SE features changelog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange))

Comment: @gnat so that presumably explains the initial deviation down from 95% around May-2011. I guess we would expect a trend downwards as more people get used to down voting questions for free. But what about the large change in 2014?

Comment: this is likely combined effect of [burning down CV queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251489/839601) and [LQ review queue changes](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2584/168). Note that question closed with VLQ flag, automatically gets downvote from a system

Comment: It might also be useful to understand **the volume of questions being asked over time.**

Answer (score 13):

*If* the problem is poor questions by new users, then maybe new users need a more guided approach to asking a question. Some kind of wizard, perhaps, with more boxes to fill in

- This is my problem
- This is the relevant code
- This is my desired result
- This is what I have tried
- It applies to [these tags]

Then, when the user has a certain reputation, then they can opt to use the standard single box question?

(Perhaps this is a question for https://ux.stackexchange.com/ ...?)

Comment: This has indeed been proposed a handful of times, e.g. [A question "wizard"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55992)

Answer (score 12):

**Subjective comment warning!**

I can appreciate your view. I remember when I first joined SE it seemed there were far more questions which prompted more thought, were more subjective etc, the community felt 'more engaged'- it certainly 'felt' like there was more discussion and willingness to help. Is is a bad thing this *feels* less the case now? I'd argue **no**; I'd go so far to say it is actually **better** now.

As already noted here, SE has changed heavily in terms of the sheer number of questions, answers, traffic and...active users. Not only that, the network has expanded considerably so there are often more appropriate sites for some types of question to be asked.

There are clearly defined rules for asking questions (the oft quoted 'off topic' section for example) and the position and purpose of SE has been clarified and focussed in order to mean dealing with the increased traffic has stayed possible.

What this means is that it may feel a little more 'abrupt', but that more users can be served better, more concise answers, faster. Not only that, but the content of the site is kept relatively 'clean' in terms of its principles.

Although in the glory old days (!) through my rose tinted spectacles I feel there were many more interesting questions, there probably weren't as many as I think. I am actively engaged in SE, and review every question coming in for a few of the tags.... and you wouldn't believe how many are poorly asked- imagine trying to solve a coding question off the back of only having a screenshot of the output? I don't joke, this happens many times a day.

As such, I empathise with your feelings but I have to say I think it creates an environment better suited to higher quality QA. Albeit one which continues to need to grow and learn (and has done thus far).

One thing I would say though- is I do tend to avoid getting into discussion on SE as sometimes it does turn sour, but this is simply a function of the vastly increased number of people and personalities involved (have you got on well with every person you have ever met in life?). The whole point is SE has recognised the need for division of purpose in order to maintain its strengths, which is why not only do we now have more network sites, but SE specifically for Q/A, chat for, well....chat and Meta for more interesting discussion..

Answer (score 11):

I'm surprised that nobody mentioned that Stack Overflow rules have changed over the years. The broad but interesting questions (those closed for ["historical significance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion)) that are now instantly downvoted were what made me so addicted to this website.

The rules as they are today almost induces low quality questions and answers. Why is it rare to see a good question nowadays? I would say because there are almost no good questions that fits the rules.

People will downvote and tell you to avoid broad questions, search more before asking, debug properly, or narrow down the issue, but if you do that then you don't have to ask the question because you will probably find the issue by yourself, which is great, but if everyone did that then SO would be almost dead. There are very few tough questions that you can't solve without searching or debugging.

Each time I see a user who knows how Stack Overflow works, what questions should be asked, and look at his profile, I see that he hasn't even asked 10 questions even though he's been there for two years.

I know, Stack Exchange is a vast network and there are now other places to ask these questions. But these restrictive rules have IMO reduced the overall quality of Stack Overflow.

I read GameDev from time to time and noticed that the rules aren't as restrictive. The most upvoted question is [How can I effectively manage a hobby game project?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/85/how-can-i-effectively-manage-a-hobby-game-project). Ask the same question on Stack Overflow, and it will get downvoted to hell in five minutes. But these are the kind of questions that anyone likes to read.

My thought is that creating specialized sites like "Super User" or "Server Fault" were great, but it wasn't a good idea to create other Stack Exchange sites for opinion-based or broad programming questions.

Let me explain it a bit better. The problem is that even if we successfully teached all Stack Overflow users how to write good questions, 100 bad questions will not become 100 good questions but rather one good question. When going through the process of writing a good question you have to try different solutions, do some research, and so on. So most of them will find the solution by themselves and will not need to ask the question anymore.

So what would be left? Stack Overflow with 50-100 times less questions would become less active than other Stack Exchange sites, which is why I say that the rules are too restrictive.

I also think that experts enjoy reading, asking or answering broad and opinion-based questions, which may be why they are leaving as these questions are now considered bad.

So my suggestion would be to merge "Programmers" with Stack Overflow, or whatever site that will allow these questions closed for "historical significance" to become on-topic again. I know it's a big change, but my opinion is that small changes will not be enough to stop the process that is going on.

Comment: Personally, I like [the 10K tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=last7days) for seeing what folks actually *like* on Stack Overflow - and what they *hate*. What's on the right side that you wish was better-received - and what's on the left that you wish was less common?

Comment: I'm an example of your 3rd paragraph. The truth is, those of us who are capable of answering a broad range of questions are typically the same people who are capable of researching and solving a problem on our own in a shorter amount of time/effort than it would take to formulate a good question. I don't ask questions because i don't have questions to ask, not because it's difficult to ask a good question.

Comment: @KevinB But anyone who knows how to ask good questions will say that he has almost no questions to ask because he solves most of his problems on his own. I have edited my answer to explain it better.

Comment: "100 bad questions will not become 100 good questions but rather 1 good question" - WIN! And 99 people will have a better understanding of how the stuff they're doing works. And will gradually take less and less time to solve their problems. And in time, will be capable of answering that one hard question left.

Comment: @Shog9 I think the questions I'm talking about are more questions that aren't asked at all because they don't fit the rules anymore. The bad ones are still there, but the users who would be able to write good ones don't ask anything or they go to another StackExchange sites. The ones in the 10K tools that I wouldn't close/downvote are questions that are kind of duplicates but not exactly. I often see questions getting closed as a duplicate even though I know the answer to one but not the other.

Answer (score 8):

First I'd like to say that I really like that question. I sometime have the same feeling but I must also admit that I don't hesitate to downvote a question and a bit more to downvote an answer.

Here are my 2 cents on that topic:

**Downvoting/closing questions**

IMHO most negative feelings on downvotes seem to come from the fact that some people just downvote or vote to close without caring to provide a reason.

It's true that there are some questions which have obvious flaws (just code being pasted, a single sentence with no obvious effort put into it, assignments being pasted etc.) and closing those really helps reduce the clutter in between the good questions. In most cases the close reason is simple enough to provide feedback on why a question has been closed.

In other cases the reasons are less obvious especially if the confusion comes from the fact that some users are new or less proficient in their writing or use of the English language. In those cases it would be *really* helpful to at least provide a short comment on why the question is closed or downvoted.

To sum it up, I tend to downvote/close-vote questions which display a real lack of effort. If questions suffer from lack of skill I try to help the OP first and only downvote or vote to close if the OP doesn't display any will to improve.

**Downvoting answers**

Downvoting answers is a slightly different story IMHO. Those who write an answer put at least some effort into it and thus don't deserve downvotes for the same reasons. A downvote would be justified if an answer is plainly wrong but in *every but the most obvious cases* (answers that don't even match the question) the downvoters should give a comment on the reasons. Only that way one can improve on their answers.

Btw, it should be obvious that if an answer is improved the downvotes should be reconsidered.

In any case the primary goal of voting on answers should be to promote good and helpful answers that others can find easily. In some cases there are several good answers which cover different aspects of the problem, but unfortunately you can accept only one.

A secondary goal would be to reward people who are positive and really want to help the community, especially if they put effort into their answers.

**"Making fun of questions"**

> ... make fun of the writing or the style

Well, that's a hard and controversal topic. Without going too much into detail I'd say that some of us try to be positive and when they stumble over a funny formulation they tend to give a comment that is not meant to make fun of the OP but to maintain a positive spirit.

**GameDev SE vs. SO**

IMHO a main reason for the difference in attitude comes from the fact that GameDev SE is more specialized, i.e. you have less questions in general, less non-effort questions and more specialized topics in general. People who hang out there and answer questions often have more in common with those who ask questions (e.g. some interest in game development) than is the case at SO.

SO has such a huge and diverse user base that it's more probable to find questions that lot of people can't relate to and thus you'll get more seemingly negative response here.

Comment: I disagree that an effort was put in answers. There are so many answers that just copypasta from other answers or internet resources, sometimes not even understanding the original question.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that stack overflow is more negative of late, I think that it has *always* been negative. It might just be that my personal experience of SO has been bad but I think that a lot of users have similar experiences and eventually take on a 'don't care' attitude, use SO as a last resort, and simply don't want to contribute to a 'community' with such a negative air.

**Gaming the System**

It feels like many high rep SO users are gaming the reputation system to one extent or another. It's not bad on SO but it gets quite obvious on other sites. I'm not going to name names but I'm sure everyone has seen an instance or two and to occasional and low rep users it looks like the system is less about Q&A and more about rep gaming. Hiding rep from each other would alleviate this a lot.

**Moaning**

There's an awful lot of moaning about how dreadful most users are, including this thread. None of it helps and it actively discourages many people. While new and low rep users are allowed to participate many of them are driven off because they think that their contributions will be dismissed and destroyed.

**Downvoting**

Every single downvote is a hurtful action. When you have plenty of rep it's a pinprick but when you have a little it's much worse. Users also use downvotes as petty revenge - someone made a snide comment? Downvote them on another question! Removing downvoting entirely would stop the negativity dead.

**Upvoting**

Most users don't upvote nearly enough and for the right reasons, especially when new and low rep users ask questions. If a question is good enough to answer why isn't it worth an upvote? SO shouldn't be a popularity contest but it almost always is. A maximum rep cap on questions and answers would really help.

**High Rep Privilege**

It feels as if many high rep users both act as if they are infallible and are treated as unable to get something wrong. Like a well paid movie star they should only be as good as their latest effort. Rep is not right.

I realise that to anyone on meta this list is going to be highly unpopular and downvoted into oblivion but the view from the bottom is not pretty. SO users appear obsessed with reputation, any suggestions that might entail the slightest curtailment or reduction (gasp!) of rep are roundly rejected. Until the community can put aside it's obsession the system cannot be changed.

Comment: I agree with the opening paragraph of this, and parts of the rest. I think you're missing the purpose of rep privilege though: it's important that folks with influence over the direction of the site have a vested interest in not screwing that up - rep is a proxy for that.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sad that the top answers to this question all seem to be some variation of "Well then people should stop asking stupid questions if they don't want us to be negative."

The problem we're talking about is the trend of overzealous downvoting and closing, not deserved downvoting or closing. It's beginning to be difficult to ask *any* question on SO without *someone* downvoting or voting to close it.  Often if they explain their reasoning, you realize they didn't even take the time to understand the question before trying to kick it off the site.

I'm beginning to think the attitude of "they're all stupid questions" might actually be a key part of what is causing this problem.

**EDIT:** I thought I'd clarify: the answer "because crap" doesn't answer the OP's question.  I never anywhere said there wasn't a lot of crap.  Instead, I tried to redirect back to the OP's original question of why is there negativity towards *good questions*?

My suggestion was that perhaps answerers are so used to looking through the vast amounts of crap, that they gain a general negative attitude that permeates some of their answers or attitude toward other questions.  As a result, they are much more eager to downvote and close as a general attitude.

Comment: This is relevant: [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).

Comment: @dallin questions are hard to ask ***by design.*** [main] forces you to ***do your best*** to do your own research and to ***try to solve your own problem first.*** I've actually been in situations where I'm in the middle of writing a question, and by the time I'm done, the process of writing the question has already helped me to find my own answer, so that I never even needed to post a question in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

I am a relatively newb user of this site(I like to think only in account age). Only recently have I begun to take notice and care about the health and how this site works (after I had admittedly commited the rep-whoring everybody is guilty of). I too have already become rather disgruntled at the utter lack of "care" that some users of this site show, both new and old.

It seems that the other newbie, ma-at, is one of the only answers that actually suggest possible solutions to the problem we have at hand. Perhaps we want to better define the actual problem first and then brainstorm solutions?

I don't think the problem is as simple as a **because crap**, or **poor programmers**,  or **homework questions**, or even **laziness***. These merely skirt around the problem. From my brief stay here, it is clear that **these are merely side effects of the problem that this site seems to be experiencing**.

It seems to me that the extreme low quality questions that seem to comprise a great majority of the currently asked questions are asked by people that show absolutely **no** care for the charter of this site or its rules to the point where they do not even display the capability to **learn**. This, to me, is the initial problem that serves as a catalyst driving certain people to respond to such low quality questions in hopes for easy reps, and the related chain of hate that awesome diagram shows. Even though I might not be the most active on this site, I still see that there are obviously more questions that seem to fail to actually diagnose a problem such that answerers can actually answer them. This conceivably causes experienced users, or heck, even newbie users such as me that **actually RTFM** to become frustrated with the community.

So this lack of care is spreading, people are becoming lazy. Good questions are sometimes burned because people either a) don't spend the time to read them, assuming that they are just a repeat of "how i debug this" or "give me the codes" or b) actually lack the understanding, but may carry high rep and the possibly associated high ego.

Now, I have actually experienced this first hand in kind. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095119/understanding-eclipse-debug-source-lookup-with-dynamically-compiled-and-loaded-c) once before the currently linked question, but it merely lacked the preface telling our fellow downvoters to not downvote my question because it's actually a good question and not a pasted "how do I debug my homework" question. That question was downvoted to oblivion and recieved TWO close votes. Having been literally the 4th question I asked, I almost lost it there and then and wanted to rant on and on. Even though this is just one example of the negativity that I have been seeing and sometimes am guilty of exhibiting, **just this one example happening, to me, is completely unacceptable.** We cannot be so lazy as to shoo away newer users that ask good questions. Perhaps lazy is the wrong word here, a more fitting word would be that it seems that the community **lacks confidence in newer users' ability to ask coherent questions**

**How do we solve this?**
Well, I have one possible solution. Instead of attempting to address the problem that exists with the CURRENT active userbase, how about being slightly more selective as to who is allowed to participate on this site? A short and sweet 10-20 min "Introduction to StackOverflow" course that EVERY new (and existing user that is under some calculated cutoff) must take before they have the privilege of asking questions on the site? This course could have a quiz in the end, with questions that test the understanding of the charter of this site, and how to ask questions. I do not believe this is too much to ask from new users, because frankly, as a new user (unless you have been browsing SO for a long time, in which case you probably don't really even need to read the manual at all) you are NOT capable of asking a coherent question that follows this site's rules UNLESS you read the manual. If certain new users are not even willing to do that, then do they REALLY deserve to even belong in our great community? Conversely, if they DID care, then EVEN if they did ask trivial and stupid questions, they would respond well to feedback(however harsh that feedback is) and learn, slowly. Slowly and steadily, the general sense of a **real** community of programmers asking questions and giving answers to programming questions will return to the masses. Running with this idea, the moderating/review community could be given greater powers to maybe *infract/warn* new users that are STILL not exhibiting the bare-minimum qualities of a SO user, with a system that resembles that of many forums.

Regarding *****: and this laziness would not be exhibited in such great frequency if the new users were FORCED to be educated in the ways of SO.

**Update:**

Just an interesting piece from my absolutely riveting question (not really). I am astounded. [image: In case it is deleted]

This is just the type of thing that makes you ask : "are you kidding me, SO community member?"

Answer (score 6):

## Why?

I try not to be negative on this site but I easily could be on poorly researched and poorly communicated questions. Based on reading in this topic, this seems to be one of the common issues.

## How to improve the situation?

The most effective first step I can think of is to bake much more guidance into the question asking process. When I want to point new users to guidance on asking good questions, I always wonder why it isn't just built into the process. So here is one potential way to do that:

> ### Example: Non-binding, Scored Checklist
>
> When asking a question, we add a very visible and clickable check-list + score. The checklist
>   covers the fundamentals of asking a good question. As they check off
>   steps, the score increases. The question can be submitted without the
>   checklist, but it will encourage people in a constructive way to
>   submit excellent questions.

## Please remember what it is like to be a beginner or new to a community.

If SO is your first programming community, you probably aren't aware of the expectations or impact of your (lack of) forethought when asking a question. I like to think that many people will work harder to do what is needed when the expectations are more obvious. By **non-intrusively** guiding askers through some fundamentals, I think we can raise the quality of questions, reduce the number of duplicates, increase happiness of answering users, etc.

Comment: I think that is one answer, but I think it should be paired with a second answer: better methods for dealing with poor questions that teach people to ask better questions and allow them to fix existing questions.  The CLOSED stamp seems pretty final and offensive for most users. Most of them become defensive and don't learn from it as a result.

Comment: @dallin That's an excellent point about encouraging improvement instead of punishing when a post doesn't meet standards. Maybe `On-hold` with the points that need to be improved? I think these two ideas would go well together to make SO more welcoming and maintain quality at the same time.

Comment: I love `On-hold`.  Perfect way to express it.  I think there is already a hold option of some sort but its rarely used.  In addition, I never see people, nor have I personally tried to, resurrect their questions.  Maybe the problem is poor communication of features and methods to users?  I think in general the process is rather harsh and confusing, which doesn't lead to helping people ask better questions.

Comment: It's _already_ called ["on hold" for the first five days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154), @dallin, and reasons and links to relevant documentation are provided in the close banner.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a newbie myself and I've asked some stupid questions myself. I haven't been on SO for long enough to see this trend, however, I write this because I think my own experience may help explain this trend a bit.

Programming is becoming more and more mainstream and so is Stack Overflow. When I opened one of my very first programming books, which was completely for newbies, I read that Stack Overflow was the main Q&A-site for programming (which is true) and that I could go there and ask questions. So I did. The problem then is: being an absolute newbie, I often didn't even really know what I actually was asking about. There was just this problem in my code and I asked here for a solution. I couldn't really do research because I didn't know what to research about.

I think that today many many more absolute newbies who don´t really have an understanding of some of the concepts in programming ask questions on Stack Overflow than a while ago. That, as I tried to explain above, leads inevitably to questions that appear stupid to experienced programmers who know what search term to use for this and see the question as a duplicate. That, very understandably, annoys those experts who spend their time on Stack Overflow.

I don´t know how to improve it, I see it as sort of an natural side-effect of Stack Overflow, and programming in generally, becoming so popular.

Answer (score 5):

I think **it would be helpful (for increasing quality)** if the speed of Question->Comment->Comment->..Answer->Comment.. would be decreased by the process itself.

Now it is not uncommon that a question gets answered within seconds or minutes, just because it pops up somewhere. Stack Overflow users probably know this. They can get a good answer very quickly for free.

At the times of mail chess both parties had to think about their next move. The same was true with snail mail. Both parties had a time to think (days) before the next move. Some letters from that time went into the history.

It is the same with customer support (or helpdesk) service. Customer files in a ticket. Helpdesk has few hours to give first feedback, negotiate the problem and then a timeline is agreed, like - this is a low priority bug (no big damage) we will get you the fix within a month. Within that time the customer can add some more details, put some pressure, request temporary workaround, etc.

I'm new to the community. I did not ask any questions myself, and I'm used to solve problems on my own by research, etc. Just my first feelings.

**Slow down. Force both parties (Question/Comment/Answer) to take breath and think** instead of tweeting.

Comment: I've sometimes posted a question, hoping there might be an answer within 24hrs. When the correct answer comes back within 5 minutes it feels like I've just got a hug from a stranger while looking at a rainbow :-)

Comment: @Darren nice, but the transcendent collective mind that composes the stranger is getting nervous and negative due to too many kids rushing around. Saying "hush get calm" might cool the mind down and make everyone more happy. Usually there is no need to hurry up and get answer in 5 minutes. The SO mind does not have enough brain cells and sufficient telepathy capabilities to stand this stampede on and on. That seems to be the reason why is SO so negative and the "take breath and think" might help (IMHO)

Answer (score 4):

This is what I have seen from this site and from my own experience.  If you at least show you put in some research effort, you are less likely to be down voted to an oblivion.  If you are going to post a question asking about code, make sure to post code examples of what you are referring to.  Also vague questions and placing things in the wrong area will get you negative attention as well.

Now my feedback on the things mentioned above:

Research goes hand and hand with programming.  I have throughout my career had to be on a project where I hadn't used a specific language before or had to integrate with 3rd party software I never had training on before or used before.  I had to learn as I went with books and/or online resources and if I got stuck, kept going and trying to figure out the best solution or technique through, at times, trial and error.  All this with while working extra time to not only keep the project on task but also to give myself more time for the learning curve.  I think these sites tend to be used to quickly as a quick "crutch" to be used instead of doing the grunt work ourselves.  I believe that is why some get down voted and causes the frustrated reactions.

For the vague questions and placing things in the wrong place.  That seems to have gotten better where someone will just move the question yourself.  I think a little more tolerance needs to be given for these types of questions, especially newcomers.  I could see how it could get frustrating to the higher end user base (those with more reputation) because they deal with it more often.  Though someone should not be drilled for other questions that aggravated them before.  I have had someone mention "this was not a programming question" but was something related to programming.  That was all they mentioned and I got down voted.  That is not really helpful at all for anyone else who may have had a similar question I asked.  A simple, this area would be better suited would work.  As I mentioned earlier, I have seen this has gotten better throughout the site at least in my experience.   Also, just down voting without any feedback isn't really helpful for the poster either.  That speaks more of just a "I want to make this negative" without posting any constructive criticism to help the posts get better.

That is my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4):

My opinion - my very humble, first-day newbie opinion - is that this progression towards negativity is pretty much the norm for an internet forum of growing popularity and functionality.

I was not among the pioneers or even the early users of SO, so I cannot speak from experience, but from my observation this community started as a smallish group of dedicated, interested, programmers who genuinely enjoyed using their knowledge to help out their peers and getting some advice in return when needed. Slowly, the small community grew and attracted more of these educated, experienced people as well as new programmers looking for help. Now, all of these people were more than likely very familiar with computers and the internet - after all, that kind of knowledge generally goes hand-in-hand with programming know-how. It wasn't very hard to keep the community high-quality, because people who didn't care about it weren't invested in it.

But then, gradually, computer use became more and more widespread, and the internet became a staple for daily living. As the popularity of computers increased, so did the computer-related jobs, and so did the educational field of computer science. Now, programming is huge, both in the job market and in education, and millions of people have some sort of stake in it.

I'm kind of feeling like I'm starting to stray from the point a bit here, so I'm going to get right to it. The problem, as I see it, is that this is The Internet we're dealing with. No longer is it just that first group of heavily invested, educated computer scientists, or even the later group of knowledge-seekers. The Internet is the land of trolls, spam, scams, hacks, and general dickheadedness, and even a focused-topic forum like SO will be affected by that to a degree.

Nowadays, who can use a computer? Pretty much anyone. And who can go to community college and take some CS courses? Pretty much anyone. Whereas the programming community was once small but  invested and experienced, now it is massive, relatively inexperienced, and only invested as far as passing the class goes. (Please note that I'm not trying to put down the members of the community who are dedicated, educated, and heavily invested. I'm simply attempting to describe the more recent influx of "programmers".)

Anyways, as I stated in the beginning, this kind of thing basically happened to the entire Internet. More access led to less-educated (or just lazier) people frequenting the web, which led to overall lower-quality content. We'll call it my Theory of General Negativity. :P

And that is pretty much all I've got on that as of now. I could be entirely wrong about a lot of things here, but I did not see this in any of the previous answers, and I thought I'd put in my two cents. Thanks for reading this little spiel, and I hope to continue to be a productive part of the SO community. Ciao!

Answer (score 3):

What a crap.

Logged in to upvote a comment under the OP after reading links from it and found it wiped with mod's reproach. **"Discussion site is not the place for a discussion!"** - I thought only rotten Russian parliament can be associated with such an oxymoron. To see it in a programmers community is a foul shame.

Well, there was a comment that, according to the new censorship rules had to be posted as an answer. All right, here it goes

> it's all [due to repwhores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers) who are digging for the same easy to answer ( coming from novice programmers ) questions on daily basis. Most of the good questions have already been asked and answered. What drives newbies here is the rep whoring part of this community -> [the troubleshooting masters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217751/troubleshooting-master-good-or-bad)... [who drive us away from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223544/what-drives-me-away-from-here) – [me how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/me-how)

Comment: +1 @Your Common Sense I just want to copy-paste your About Me into my About me profile :)

Comment: @gnat As far as I remember this link weren't in the original comment

Comment: but it suits it well! leave it there :)

Comment: @mehow well I wish that too. where can I find it? It is showing me a copy of my SO account profile, while my old good meta profile rant is missing.

Comment: I hate you both, Your and @mehow - because of you, I made two rollbacks :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/214960/your-common-sense)

Comment: Yes, yes.  Repwhores never let you close FAQs, they would upvote the silliest of questions, and write the same answers over and over.  Look at [this rep whore](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/105999/sayed-ibrahim-hashimi) who is complaining that [it isn't possible to copy/paste an answer to multiple questions in less than a minute](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251744/throttling-trusted-users).

Comment: @devnull mmmyeaahh, but... that user looks pretty solid to me overall, looking at his top answers. So maybe he got that aspect of the site wrong - not a deadly sin in my eyes.

Comment: @ddriver I parsed this as Your Common Sense as perhaps *being* Russian (and lamenting the state of things in his home country), not as some political statement.

Comment: I hate reading comments that should have been posted as answers, leaving the question open. Thank the mods for enforcing the site's purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I've read through all the replies (admittedly not all the comments) and want to add my perspective which is a bit different.

First off I'm a very experienced programmer (C++, Java, and C#) and, I think, am a pretty good one. I use Stack Overflow as a resource and have never cared about points or badges. I try to answer questions at times to pay back for the help others give me, but I do ask a lot more than I answer.

I think a lot of this is people being quick to down-vote or criticize. We hire computer science interns at my company and they're among the top at school. When they get stuck on something I point them at Stack Overflow and give them guidance on how to ask the question, so they don't come across as a noob.

Almost without exception, people on here find reason to close it and without a whole lot of explanation as to why. And in every case I think it was a valid question well phrased. There's something wrong when people are closing questions from top computer science students that first did a diligent effort on Google and could not find an answer. [People like this are a problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158833/i-want-to-have-more-than-50-close-votes-per-day)

You also have know-it-alls, [like this](http://blogs.windward.net/matta/2012/07/02/stack-exchange-moderators-with-ocd-and-why-some-poor-sap-wont-be-able-to-find-a-quick-solution-now/) case, who have become the acceptability police determining what answers are appropriate. They reduce the useful information on the site and drive away experienced knowledgeable contributors - a two-fer.

And you have the grammar police. This question ([link to my blog with the original wording](http://blogs.windward.net/davidt/2012/12/15/when-stackoverflow-goes-bad/) as I re-wrote it to get it opened) comes up first in Google for "FIFO C#". Was the questioner's grammar imperfect - yes. But the question was clear and IMHO spot-on for this site. Yet it was closed.

And I get the same treatment in a number of my questions, where someone decides that what I'm asking isn't valid. From [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747768/is-object-object-safe-in-c-sharp) where a lot of the downvotes were - that can't be happening (the fact that it is apparently is not relevant) to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286673/can-you-do-a-join-in-an-xml-schema) where I figured the answer was probably no, but it's always better to ask.

I think people need to realize that not everyone comes at this with their exact same approach, knowledge-base, or fluency in English. If someone's made no effort first or is posting homework or you have no idea what they're talking about, yes let them know that. But very smart people will still ask questions you find trivial, but they're stuck on. People new to the site here will stumble at first. And the response to those cases is what determines the tenor of this site.

I'm presently learning [TypeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) and JavaScript, and boy is that a learning experience as both the language and runtime environment are very different. I've noticed the people who answer the TypeScript questions are all very supportive, even for questions that once I understand it, I realize were dumb. The JavaScript ones are more across the board, some very understanding, many fine, and some quick to downvote or close.

I think what's needed more is the attitude of the many really terrific contributors here who do understand that the people asking the questions they can answer by definition know a lot less on that subject.

Comment: YES.  "Acceptability police."  Any question that seems to invite an answer that would go against standard practices is downvoted.  Ask a question that requires a global variable?  Downvoted.  But why?  If the question is rubbing your aesthetics the wrong way, it's probably a *good* question.  Noncanonical questions are the only good ones left.

Comment: THIS! 1) Put a lot of effort into writing up question (like 4 hours at least) 2) Someone decides "this is not a programming question" moves it "programmers" 3) Immediately title-edited, and answered by a guy who clearly didn't understand it; try to stay civil about this 4) his irrelevant answer gets 2 upvotes 5) my question tagged as "duplicate" by 5 self-appointed karma police who don't understand it 6) further study reveals an appropriate answer 7) write up answer 8) answer immediately gets two downvotes by random people 9) question classified as "duplicate". 10) WTF

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think it is about time that editing questions gets somehow incentivised and that people spend time making specific questions general and adding keywords/phrases/tags to questions such that they are more easily found on Google.

Merge duplicate questions... the text of the questions and the answers. This will also improve the chances of someone finding out the solution before asking the questions.

Insert a 'flag question for editing' in the workflow, and incentivise it. There are enough number of people who do not know the answer, but they can help phrase the question more appropriately. So badly phrased questions instead of being closed or downvoted get a chance.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing really excellent editing of questions takes a lot of effort; it's not easy, and there aren't a lot of people who can or want to do it. On the other hand, maybe that means it _should_ be rewarded, but then [gaming is always a danger](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/gaming-the-edit-system-with-tiny-edits). Something to keep thinking about, for sure.

Comment: I am sure that there are lots of people like me who realise that they cant really improve on the answers and are on stackoverflow on weekends.  I (and many like me) would jump at the opportunity of getting karma this way.

Comment: 8k questions *a day*. I think you are woefully underestimating the number of *active users daily* with 2k+ rep that A) aren't already part of the problem B) would rather edit garbage than try to help the users asking good questions.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with many that the amount of 'stupid questions' has risen immensely.

I define a stupid question as:

1. A question to which you can find the answer by just pasting the title into Google and look at the first page of results.
2. As above but when adding the tags.

So maybe it's just too easy to get an answer. Because of the big number of people visiting SO and answering questions, there is almost always answering your question. And I find myself doing that too. Sometimes I see a question which is stupid (by above rules) or poorly written or unclear, and I will downvote or closevote it, and usually post a comment as well, or upvote existing comments that already denote my opinion.

But on other times, when my mood is different, I can read such a question, and just type in a simple answer.

And I think that feeds bad behaviour. If me and everyone else will just ignore the question, or downvote it and tell what is wrong, then eventually people will feel themselves forced to write good questions and Google (or, God forbid, read a book or tutorial) before askings yet another duplicate.

But then again, answering those question is also a hobby and a learning process for me. I've even (succesfully) answered questions for programming languages or techniques I've never used myself before. But sometimes a question (stupid as it may be) triggers my curiosity and it will cause me to Google a bit, read about a subject and learn something new in the process.

So to solve this problem, I think I and others should be even better police agents and be even more strict in judging the quality of a question. That should bring the volume down and the quality up.

But I'm afraid it won't work.

First of all, I don't know if I (and those others) can be that strict. If I see a question and would like to answer it, I don't want to ask myself whether the question is 'good enough' to be answered. Sometimes, answering it is just easier than checking whether it was already answered.

Secondly, I'm afraid a lot of damage has already been done, and I'm not sure if there are measures that would turn the tide without damaging SO's reputation even further.

Comment: If someone posts their homework problem for you to just do for them, and you find the problem itself intriguing, then solve it and just don't post your solution.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, although I don't see the difference between homework and professional work, apart from the latter dude actually getting payed for the solutions SO provides him.

Comment: There isn't, I'm just less likely to find professional work as entertaining.  Many homework questions are *designed* to be cool/fun/interesting/unique.  A lot of LOB work is boring an repetitive.  The general approach of solving and not posting can be applied to any question that should be closed for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that maybe one solution to improve the questions on SO (and thereby the answers and general tone on the site) could be to improve the chat part of the site.

If I have say a WINAPI question that I don't think would help anyone else (or one that I can't formulate into a good quality question) then the logical thing would be to ask it in a chat instead. But I just can't figure out the chat function. There are plenty of rooms, but little indication to which would be the best to ask my question in. Say there are maybe 5 rooms that possibly might be able to answer questions about WINAPI, but which one is best? Most of them also seems to be more or less empty with nothing written in hours or days. Result: either I ask my question in the wrong room and gets treated like an idiot or I ask it in an empty room and get no help.

I think larger (higher populated) more general and easier-to-get-into chat rooms would be more helpful. Or maybe better information to how they work or how they are structured (searching on tags, a tree structure or something). If people were informed that they could use the chat instead before they post their question on SO maybe some of the crap questions never gets asked and the tone improves.

Maybe have a general "noob" chatroom where you can ask your question and be directed to a more correct chatroom (or to post the question on SO proper)

Answer (score 1):

You all have very good points in this matter, and I agree with a majority. Many of these questions are asked because of laziness.

Unfortunately for newer users, Stack Overflow seems very negative these days. I mean you come to Meta to talk about problems and voice your opinion, and you get down votes? This is why they made Meta.

I know as a newer and developing programmer, I am not sure how to look up several questions I have, to accomplish all the tasks I've been given. I can't just post a junk question asking how you would word something or it would get shot down and closed extremely quickly. So I ask questions to get help to understand what we need to be focused on because, as the only programmer at my work, I don't have anyone to ask for help with issues that are over my head.

We don't mean to ask junk questions but we just don't know how to word them for your better understanding. I am not disagreeing with down-voting questions -- I like it -- but post a reason and maybe you can help the asker better understand what they have done wrong, or how they can better research these questions.

Stack Overflow has helped me more times than not in my work; it also makes me leery of posting questions, for fear that it's a bad one and will be ill received, no matter how I word it or show what steps I have taken.

I just think we should focus on getting people on the right track to answering their questions or them finding it themselves, instead of being negative and acting like we have been doing this for years.

I'll state it again: I'm not against down-voting; it needs to be in place for better understanding. I just think we could focus more on helping askers understand what they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I get far more than I give here.  I.E. I ask questions when I need them answered.  If, in so doing, I happen to see something where I feel I have something useful to say, I'll say it.  This happens rarely.

I think most of the questions I ask are decent.  I get more up-votes than down-votes.  A couple of weeks ago I asked one that got down-voted really fast.  There seemed to be two packages available for accomplishing something I needed to do, and I was looking for guidance as to which was better.  I had done some research and it I couldn't find any A vs B flame wars on the internet such as is usually the case in such situations.  I was initially offended.  Eventually, I did a bit more research and learned that my basic assumption was wrong.  There weren't two options.  One was a living, breathing package and the other hadn't been touched in years and was dead except for zombie links.  That's why there were no flame wars.  I deleted my question.  The quick-on-the-draw downvoters were right, and I was wrong.

I can take it!  And if someone is unreasonably nasty I can be nasty in return if I have to.

I still find the site valuable.

If I had time I'd contribute more and I wish I could do so.

Let's stop beating ourselves up.  This is a good community.

Answer (score 1):

Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?

It is **the age**.

It is not a baby anymore, nor a child, or even a teenager. Considering websites and online communities scale of time, Stack Overflow seems to be moving from adulthood to senior season, already.

I remember the good old days when people entertained themselves when a question arrived. It was a joy to make them and participate in the problem solving discussion, when not simply being amazed when receiving a well done simple and straight answer...

Last time I've made a question I felt humiliated. People, instead of trying to understand the question, rumbled because they couldn't answer it. Very different from the beginning, for sure. The polite and smart people from the old days are not as available as before, and the added noise makes sane and joyful threads each day harder to happen. Unfortunately, and paradoxically, it is also a **price being paid for its own success and popularity**.

Luckily, I am able to feel the good taste again, because we have **Stack Overflow in Portuguese** - which is my native language! There, the community is newer, and we can easily find and feel that joy we could originally find at SO in English.

Instead of being thrown critics, downvotes and offensive rants, when a question arrives there, it is considered as it is: a technical question, deserving its proper attention and consideration. I think we will also have this better community sense and enjoyment there for a longer time, exactly because of the language constraint. Our success and popularity **in Portuguese** will never reach the same proportions as the English one...

Comment: This is effectively saying "There's no possible way for any site to maintain quality with age". Disagree.

Comment: No, it is not. This is only your interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

After reading a lot of answers here, I've thought a lot about the issue. I think there are two things I could say that could help:

**First**, I think the general attitude towards poor questions is people didn't know or didn't care about following the rules. I think we should be aware that for a lot of users, that isn't the case. I still get closed questions occasionally despite agonizing over every question I write to make it perfect and acceptable. I literally have a paranoid fear of my questions getting closed. So why does it still happen?

Usually because I don't understand a key detail about what I'm asking. I *think* I know enough to ask the question, I've done my research, I know the rules, I just have something that hasn't clicked yet.  The result is someone who understands the issue correctly reads my question and it doesn't even make sense to him, since he understands the issue fully. And then he does what he should and closes the question.

Closing these questions is currently the *correct* behavior, but it has a few unexpected consequences. First and foremost, people who try very hard to follow the rules get disallusioned and feel the site is negative. Sometimes because their question was simply closed instead of their misunderstanding being addressed, they don't agree with the decision to close their question and get upset. Last, sometimes people do address the misunderstanding in answers, which leads to other users being upset that someone tried to answer a question that should have just been closed - because the question just turned into "help this one fellow understand why he made a mistake" rather than Stack Overflow's purpose of creating a reference to help everyone. I feel the current system doesn't address this problem - the individual who writes legitimately poor questions and an individual who takes hours out of his life to write what would have been a quality question if he understood the whole issue are treated the same. This leads to negative feelings.

**Second**, a lot of the problem comes from the general Internet not knowing or caring what Stack Overflow is. Ben put this perfectly when he said: "This site was meant to provide a canonical resource for programmers to find answers to their questions." The problem is, the average users on Stack Overflow do not use the site like this. Do they?

To change the average internet user's behavior on Stack Overflow, we have to understand how he thinks. The average internet user *does not read instructions*.  The average internet user *makes judgements about what a site is and its purpose within 5 seconds* of first visiting the site. These are things we all know from UX studies and can't change.

We obviously shouldn't have to hold their hands or allow their poor behavior, but we *should* understand that if we want to solve the problem, we HAVE to address their behavior and habits. In other words, instead of complaining about the general internet user's behavior, we have to accept that it's not going away and change Stack Overflow to reflect that. We have to do a better job at communicating the purpose of Stack Overflow within 5 seconds.

Perhaps a solution to this problem could be somehow changing the format or expected wording of the questions to better represent a general resource rather than one user's question. Or perhaps it would help to make the site a little more exclusive or forceful in purpose (Quora seems to have taken this approach). I honestly don't know what the best course of action is.

Comment: You only have three closed questions, and I only see one that might fit your description of "closed even though I put in a lot of research effort", [Best way to record changes to a sql server database and send them to the client](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14859898). Do you have deleted questions, or are you inflating one example?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I've deleted a few because once I understood them they were no longer good questions. Here's one of mine I was thinking of: http://goo.gl/gKkUPD. Generally, I think I ask good questions, but because it has happened, I'm scared to ask questions. I know there are a lot of other users who are scared to ask questions despite trying their best to follow the rules. Some people struggle with the language skills to word their questions in a clear way as well. In other words, I think we should treat people differently when they *are* trying, as opposed to asking legitimately bad questions.

Comment: What do you find "negative" about your question being marked as a duplicate? It's just "your answer is already available". If you don't find your answer at the linked question, edit to clarify why.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Because when you tried your best to make sure there wasn't a duplicate and then it gets marked as a duplicate, you feel like "why should I even try anymore." In other words, it's not negative if you didn't look, but if you tried your best to look, it is.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm just trying to explain my personal mentality so others will be aware some people do get hurt by these things.  I'm not saying it's the *right* mentality. It can be quite negative though when, like in the case of my link, you do not agree with the decision and your question gets thrown out with little you can do.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like more moderation-hours or *harder* moderation hours will resolve the bigger problem of power-user/moderator burnout.

A confluence of factors internal and external to the site have exposed flaws in its regulatory mechanisms. Internally, there are too many new users asking too many low quality questions; there are too many users who value rep over the integrity of the site; there are too few compelling questions to maintain the interest of expert users.

I think the external part of this is more interesting:

- SO has become the de facto resource for programming q/a (I.e., It is no longer a resource enterprising programmers find on their own, but is now a resource complete novices are sent to directly because it is the one obvious resource.)
- There are large economic and political incentives at play in the market for programmers and the skills they possess.
- Relating to the above, SO profiles are sometimes used as a measure in the hiring process; SO reputation can be said to have real-world value. We would probably be hard-pressed to quantify this value on our own, but I suppose a shrewdly-composed study with smart controls could probably suss out what the rough real-world value of a quality SO profile which asks smart questions and gives smart answers is (especially for those of us without long resumes.)

The *answer* is probably just a question: can we align the incentive system in such a way that it leverages the economies which currently work against the goals of the site in such a way that the incentives instead properly drive the behavior we need to see?

Answer (score 1):

By just filtering on the behaviour of a self-selected group of high ranking users you're skewing the results (not that they're not potentially valid when extrapolated to the community at large). I've been an occasional poster for several years now, and agree the percentage of fluff in the questions has gone up. But the main reason it appears so massive it the massive increase in the number of questions overall. 

Simply put, if there's 100 questions asked per day, and 5% are fluff, that's 5 questions and most likely nobody will see more than 1 of them before a moderator removes it.
If there's 5000 questions asked per day, and 5% are fluff, that's now 250 questions that are fluff and most people will see several and think the quality of the site is degrading.
Worse, at that point the literal amount of fluff will start to affect search ratings for the site as a whole, skewing the Google index for several topics people who generally end up posting fluff use to find places to post (typically these amount to homework problems...). Once the site ends up being listed by search engines among "free homework services" you're doomed unless you spend a lot of time and energy in an extremely aggressive campaign to get rid of it (and just closing the questions doesn't help, they're still indexed by the search engines, they need to be actively deleted).

So why is the mountain of fluff what it is today? In part it isn't, the percentage is probably not as much higher as it was a few years ago, even if the total amount is.
BUT the very real danger exists that it's already at or past the tipping point for causing search engines to list SO among those places where lazy schoolkids and others with no interest in doing their own research go in order to get others to do their work for them. And with the "be nice" campaigns (which were a good idea by themselves, a lot of the old timers here were and often still are way too hostile towards people with lower reputation, just look at the meta posts where people suggest allowing users to do things like block out all content generated by people with low reputation...) causing a reduction in the actual deletion and deterent effect on the homework kiddos (as I call them) the problem was allowed to grow.

So more aggressive moderation of blatantly off topic or unresearched questions, deleting the questions outright rather than just closing them (with a possibly automated email to the asker as to why might well help stem the tide, but it will take time to clean things up and revert the search ratings to what they should be (and yes, that will reduce the total traffic, something many site owners don't like).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: gamification. Some users care about programming, but the most care only about their reputation. And creating lots and lots of new rules will never solve this problem, as this is a fundamental design defect.

Answer (score 0):

Every community hit periods of growing pains (repeatedly) as old mechanisms for signalling and communication break down at new scales. One of the main issues here is the crapflood on the question queue. It may be that I've just missed part of the UI, but where is the option to filter out questions with less than X upvotes?

The problem: over time the ratio of questions worth answering approaches zero.

A solution:

- Give people filtering options that include scores when they look at
  the queue (remove the frustation of trying to find non-crap to
  answer).
- Set a default threshold for the site that people can change, e.g. +2.
- Give people a motivation to read the crap, for people who browse at a low threshold:

  - When a question has an accepted answer, everyone who upvoted
    before the answer gets +1 rep.
  - When a question is closed, everyone who upvoted before the close
    gets -1 rep.

tl;dr Separate out filtering crap from answering non-crap, and provide an incentive for people to filter. A better signalling mechanism will soothe growing pains until a new community scale is hit.

Answer (score -4):

Competition.

The initial idea of the member reputation thing was to encourage good answers and good questions. But as the site is getting more popular, people show their SO score on their online profile, in their resume, on their blog etc. There's also the careers site: People with high reputation score have higher chance to get the job. So what happens is that people feel they are in *competition with each other* -- which encourages them to *downvote rather than to upvote*. Why increasing someone else's job opportunities?

Comment: If this was the case people would be being harsh on *answers*, not questions - and even then if your argument held, I risk losing rep by downvoting on answers. Finally, nobody puts/should put their SO rep on a real-world resume. If the employer cared, they would be using Careers.

Comment: At least Spolsky [does](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/spolsky)

Comment: Is it really your feeling that people are harsh on questions, but positive on answers?

Comment: Like I said. If the employer cared, they would be using Careers. And yes, people are positive on my answers! Unless I've said something idiotic, in which case they're 60% constructive, 40% harsh - and I can handle that

Comment: I would have to agree.  I recently interviewed with a company who asked if I used SO (and had a spot on the application for my SO id).  If I were a hiring for a software developer, I would like to know if the person used SO and what his/her score was.  With this in mind, it puts SO rep on a whole different playing field than it originally started out to be. We need to try and stay focused on the OP and his/her question not rep points.

Comment: I ***strongly disagree*** with this argument that users downvote other people just in order to be competitive in terms of job-marketability. Most [main] users are either here to help people, earn reputation, or both. Downvoting posts that don't deserve downvoting is just silly and unreasonable. Downvoting posts that aren't good, clear, well-researched questions, or clear, correct answers, on the other hand, is reasonable, especially given [the clear guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on [how to write good posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a valid concern in theory, but it's also why there are such strict limits on voting: you'd be hard-put to make a dent in the reputation of anyone with any perceivable amount of competence, and [the anti-fraud systems](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) would tend to kick in long before that. As a general rule, folks up-vote much, much, much more than they downvote.

Answer (score -5):

Stack Overflow wants to be a wiki of technical information, but it is laid out as Q&A. It really doesn't want to answer questions. In other words, it wants to be one thing but is advertising itself as something else.

Comment: I don't see how that is true. Questions and answers are the lifeblood of the place. What is true that those questions and answers are intended to be somewhat "canonical" answered only once of a few times, but very very well (and constantly improved, that's where a Wiki aspect indeed comes into play)

Answer (score -5):

As a new user of SO, who absolutely fell in love with the StackExchange communities, and recently had many questions downvoted and forced to be deleted, I can't express my frustration over this. I came to find answers not to pester the mods, and more importantly, yes I would try to make my questions better and better, but the veterans of SO can probably attest to the fact that this takes time and experience to get a good question and good answer in. This is not your typical forum.

I feel that StackOverflow and StackExchange as a general was created for smaller communities. StackOverflow being the forefront of SE is overflowing (yes, "overflow" again) with questions and users who are not as cultivated as the older members. Quite simply, the format of Q/A  is a bit outdated for our current usage.

Others in this question mentioned that users in StackOverflow are having harder times finding good questions to answer, AND having a hard time making good questions for others to answer.

Put simply, I think SO has to  refine the search functionality so that people can filter through the levels of expertise. There are always bound to be newbies to the forum that are going to ask easier and 'stupid' questions, but usually, these questions can be answered by users that are similar to themselves.

The solution is not to turn newbies to other forums and to www.google.com, but rather to let them work amongst themselves by creating microcommunities within SO.

TLDR:'
 **The Problem**: Helpers can't find good questions to answer, newbies can't ask without being bashed super hard.
 **The Solution**: Help helpers find good questions, through refinement of search functionality and creation of microcommunities and by doing so also help newbies get answers from other newbies.

Comment: The community does not exist just to provide you with an answer to the question you couldn't bother to do any research on.  **You** are obligated to form a proper question if you want it answered.  We are not obligated to answer your poorly formed question.  That is exactly how this site has separated itself from its competition, and why it has been so successful.  The site *already* goes to pretty great lengths to encourage users to search for duplicate questions before posting, and it *already* creates microcommunities through the use of the tag system.

Comment: "Quite simply, the format of Q/A is a bit outdated for our current usage." ... I think you have that the wrong way around. The way people are currently trying to use SO *isn't* its purpose. And unless we want to let SO simply become "ExpertsExchange II" we need to put a stop to it.

Comment: *"also help newbies get answers from other newbies"* That's exactly the thing you *don't* want in a programming community. That's what degrades the site into a steaming pile of an endlessly duplicated, useless rubbish. Let me put it that way: StackOverflow is not a programming assignment solving machine. It is meant to help people *learn*, not help them get their jobs done. That's only a side effect. If users recognize you solely ask for the latter, you will naturally get flak from them. Questions that permeate thoughtfulness and modesty still get great answers and hardly any downvotes.

Comment: In fact, if your question was downvoted, that's pretty good evidence that you've been doing things wrong and it has nothing to do with being unwelcoming to newbies. Sure, its uncomfortable to be criticized, especially when you come with the best intentions. But taking that personally is a mistake. Think about the critique and try to improve in that area. Asking a good question is surprisingly hard. If it takes you less than half an hour then you're already trying to outsource thought processes you ought to have to the community. And *that's* the issue I (at least) have with most bad questions.

Answer (score -6):

I don't think SO is so different from any other social network. Except that

1. here you can downvote
2. here you have an explicit reputation
3. here we can elect the sheriffs

So what's different here is that SO is a social network where power is more evident. But the social game is the same everywhere. It's a big social experiment.

And as many believe, every social network also has some duration. If that chart showing the top users leaving SO is accurate, maybe it's a trend.

Comment: Yes, the task at hand is to not make the same mistakes as the other Networks that lost it. This is a trend, and it is possible to change it.

Answer (score -7):

Sharing a few month old experience [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214619/205030), I had asked this question because of the comment by a user, who is reaching 80,000 Reputation, says

<sup>Disclaimer : Am not targeting users personally, am just taking few examples to prove my point</sup>

> Unfortunately, questions asking to fix your code considered offtopic
> on this site [sic]

And few people supported him, I somewhat got upset with this but there is much little we can do about.

---

Coming to similar situation today, take a look at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223292), here, it was closed as

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
> or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
> on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
> future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely
> inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem
> before posting.

So this sentence is too broad for me, it's just a personal opinion, looking close to the sentence it says

*This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.*

So fine, no typography error in the question, so I deem this reason to close vote as *invalid*.

---

*While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.*

I don't see any reason how this may won't help the future visitors, OP also stated that he searched and he got *Over half a million - kind of random - hits. I haven't found any page describing the value itself. It has 0 hits on StackOverflow.*

So again, this reason is deemed invalid as well.

---

*his can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Again, deemed invalid, now solution is weird to the question, the string which OP found is nowhere in the source code, and may be a result of something.

---

After I commented there, I went to the PHP room because am aware of the CV-Ring because I was the [victim for the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179861/). User commented that I am rep whoring, judging someone from the reputation is not a good reason to downvote, I may have good reputation, but I was a beginner and was learning PHP.

What if user learns new languages, he may answer some questions, to just try out his skills, but users judge from the reputation. I don't mind if I receive downvote, but peer force is what upsets me the most.

I've being the part of CV-Ring and I know how it works, I've closed the questions as well, but I've always read the question before voting whereas other users go with the flow.

So I went to PHP room today and posted [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16010029#16010029) and I came to know that the same user did the fuzz [with the above question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16008610#16008610) I discussed. What was the reason?

[of topic, no use to future visitor, higly localized](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16009191#16009191)

The question was useful, even the [PHP professional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223292/what-is-ytowont9#comment35528820_23223602) appreciated the efforts.

---

The point I want to prove here is that users generally go with the flow, few care, rest follow other users. I remember well, when I joined this website, users used to comment

*What did you tried?*

After seeing this, I used to comment similar things on the questions who didn't shared any codes and asked for help, as and when I got some understanding, I left doing so. Similar thing is with PHP OOP comments, one user comments, rest of them just insult the user saying you have a vulnerable code, and stuff. And they downvote just because the users code is ineffeciaent.

Same with the upvotes and the downvotes, one user upvotes, its likely that the other user having low experience will go with the vote score and will upvote and downvote rather than judging the question.

I try to write canonical answers most of the time, because I love to explain things in brief, and I get a comment *(Now deleted)* saying

> -1, explained too much in detail which is confusing for a beginner

So, its matter of judgements, few users are concerned, rest follows the herd ... what I call is Sheeps, one jumps and rest of them follows *(except few)*, so its the effect off all the things together, like, One comment abuses the user, creates negative impact on the other viewers as well, and likely they follow the same.

---

Also, we have some really vague definitions as far as the site rules are concerned which does disturb the users, we often say this

> The question won't be useful to future visitors

So what we do? Close, or delete, now these action makes sense when questions are duplicate or they are really really generic in nature, which can be found by simple search, but as far as I know, most of these questions gets highest views. Site will be left with mere 1/2 a million unique questions, rest are left with < 50 views, so should we close or delete them all? Because the definition says so, we should close them if they are not useful for future visitors.

[In what way does this question helps future visitors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728150/unusual-shape-of-a-textarea) - [Reopened by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20728150/revisions)

[Whereas the similar one was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813572/how-can-i-accomplish-this-jquery-hover-click-effect-linkimage)

---

**tl;dr** : rules are bit vague, where users are confused themselves what to do, they judge the posts either by peer reviewing, or by judging the actions of others, or some review the posts with the interest, post some fancy things, attract the visitors. So there is nothing like negativity, it's the high rep users who dominate, and downvote/close questions of the users who are new, and as the post is closed, we get more crap as the OP will ask another question, and thus arises debates.

Can't help :)

Answer (score -7):

While the founders and many people on SO may still see the site as a [Q&A library](https://stackoverflow.com/about), from this new poster's view, SO is in fact something quite different than that. SO is first and foremost a community - a community of teachers, learners - people. Since the rationale of the site is for experts in a field to provide guidance to others, I would humbly suggest that a thorough answer to this question should come from a specialist in [group dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_dynamics).

Maybe someone out there knows an expert in the field who could weigh in on the subject. Maybe the community even cares enough about the answer to sponsor an engagement of that sort with someone who could study this thread, browse the community, interact with various users - really dig into the problem - and provide specific recommendations back to the group to address the perceived shortcomings of the current model.

I have found SO very useful as a research tool and have started to post answers in an effort to give back to the community that has helped me. My interactions have largely been positive. I posted a half-baked answer in that sleepy hour after lunch one day and got some corrective comments from the community, including from at least one PhD specialist in the field whose insistence on precision really impressed me. Notable is that the question was initially posted by a 13 year old looking for very general information about how JavaScript can interact with the DOM.

While that entire discussion may have driven some of the more experienced users on the site a bit mad, it seems to me those are exactly the kinds of posts that keep the community going. Was that question a duplicate of something earlier? Almost certainly. Was it well researched? Not at all. What really matters is that a 13 year old kid was interested enough in knowing the answer to ask the question. The old passing on knowledge to the young is what builds a community and keeps it thriving.

You can, for instance, strictly enforce the idea of closing duplicate questions, but as long as people can still ask questions, you will continue to get duplicates, and someone will have to answer or close them. If you cut off the ability to ask questions, you are then declaring the goal of the project reached, leaving behind a read-only Q & A library. If that happens, the SO community, the Internet, and the world of learners at large will be much poorer for it.

Comment: The about page is very *explicit* about **not** being what you claim it says we are.  I fail to see how you can determine, from the about page, that this site is what you are claiming.  Also, your assertion that duplicate questions should be closed as such, rather than answered again and again and again and again and again and again and again by people too lazy to do a web search would mean making this site read only is simply not true.  While there are a *lot* of duplicates, original questions crop up every single day.  The topic is simply that expansive, and ever changing.

Comment: Quite simply, [you're using the site wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179003/stack-exchange-is-too-harsh-to-new-usersplease-help-them-improve-low-quality-po/179009#179009) (start reading at the last quoted segment).

Comment: @Servy, The site is not the same thing as the community. The site is the vehicle through which the community builds the library of knowledge. The problems being discussed here are not technology problems, they are people problems. That's why you need a group dynamics expert to properly answer the question.

Comment: Yes, there is a community; a community of people asking and answering specific, concrete questions such that artifacts useful for others are left behind. It's not really clear how your interest in discussion, guidance, and extended interaction fits in with this topic of negativity, but one thing is clear: your decision to play polo on a cricket pitch does not constitute a problem so complex that it requires a "group dynamics expert". It constitutes a decision point for you: to play cricket or find another field.

Comment: @John Caswell, Trying to enforce the way the site is used through convention is like trying to make everyone healthier by telling them to eat better and exercise more. You might make a dent in the problem, but you will not solve the problem. If you want to change the way the site is used, you need to change the way the site works. To do that, you need some recommendations on what to change, which brings me back to the notion of having a group dynamics expert offer suggestions about ways to change the site that would improve the experience for everyone.

Comment: @Robert your analysis of the situation is not wrong. And if millions of people show up and want to play polo on a cricket pitch, then you have to question whether it isn't time to convert to a polo field. But - the community you speak of isn't a static asset. It consists of experts showing up frequently. The main reason why they do that is arguably: good questions. There will always be an infinite demand for free programming help, but a very limited supply of it, so your main focus needs to be how to be attractive to those experts.

Comment: Now personally, as one of those experts, I signed up here to help build a canonical archive to help future generations; I've done the other thing before, answering questions in a traditional Q&A forum with no serious concept of "duplicates", and I've grown deeply tired of it. I'm not sure whether a group dynamics specialist can really provide the insights necessary to provide continued incentives to those people to show up.

Comment: I like this part of the answer "a 13 year old kid was interested enough in knowing the answer to ask the question". To me it means that nobody is error-free and all are still learning to some extent. It takes a bit away the pressure to deliver perfectly researched questions. Still one should make the check for duplicates rather yourself instead of relying on the community to do it for you.

Answer (score -8):

What is crap for some is enlightenment for others. May be answering some basic question is a waste of time for someone, but can be intellectually stimulating for someone else, less advanced in this area.

Wouldn't be the solution to split a way or another a community into several levels, like beginner, intermediate, advance, wizard ? If you think a question is too dumb, you vote to downgrade it to a lower category. There some people may find rewarding to make a reputation for themselves by answering questions some more advanced users would regard as "crappy". During that time, the experts can concentrate on a stream of more sophisticated questions.

In short, don't mix the high school with the university.

Just my 0.02 €.

"Education is cheaper than ignorance"

Answer (score -8):

Stack Overflow used to reflect the archetype of **The Perfect Programmer**.

Everyone wanted to be one - hence everybody acted in unity to achieve that.

With popularity and dividing site into countless subsites, this reflection got lost and replaced with some kind of [holy shrine of scrupulosity](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7651176) or whatever how anyone sees it. Main thing is - **people don't want to identify themselves with this site anymore**. Those that care and do want to - are in pain.

And when there's no common goal - there's no [empathy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191098).

---

The idea that this can be fixed by more segregation through dividing questions into levels of quality is just stupid - that would just furtherly encourage the brightest minds to go elsewhere.

---

[This looks sad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfDdP.jpg).

Answer (score -11):

DUPLICATES - SO got it wrong at the first place. In order to stay interesting for all, **SO must accept duplicates**.

Trying to remove duplicates is **cumbersome** (ask the admins), **frustrating** (ask the users), **useless** (from the user's point of view), and **harmful** to Stackoverflow.

**Yes, harmful**: Everything evolve, fast: languages, practices, libraries, environments, OSes, databases. Even answers do expire. Take this example :

> (MVVM) How can I manage to close a Window from the ViewModel?

Ask this question in 2008 and ask it again in 2014. You would not receive the same answers: MVVM has maturate, users have found shortcuts, some practices have proven better.

- **If you don't allow duplicates**, you would got one question with, say,
  8 answers, the last one having been posted in 2010. The irremovable
  "Best Answer" will reflect what was the state of the art... in
  2008-2010!
- **If you allow duplicates**, you may end with three similars questions
  having 8, 10 and 2 answers respectivly, and three "Best Answers",
  each of them being the best at the time they were choosen. The whole
  thing would simply show the evolution of MVVM.

I said "irremovable Best Answer". As you already know, "Best Answers" are not the best answers. They are "Best Answers YET", and this matter. A lot. The best answer is the best until a better one is posted.

- **If you don't allow duplicates**, a question asked in 2011, that got 12
  answers and for which a Best Answer was choosen 3 months later, will
  never be read by those who may now have better "Best Answers". This question is dead.
- **If you allow duplicates**, the same question can be asked again, and again, each time opening the door for better answers and letting more and more new players play the game of sharing and learning.

Of course you can get the same answer. But so what? Users will always find the best answer for their case (do not underestimate them). SO will pay just a little more for the storage, but admin will have great time focusing on problems that matters, new users will be able to win points and medals, answers will be kept up to date.

Answer (score -14):

Starting from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/251795#251795) with which I totally agree I would also add another possible explanation for the negativity here.

I can find on StackOverflow some really strongly amazing and interesting question like this one: [How do 20 questions AI algorithms work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887533/how-do-20-questions-ai-algorithms-work)

69 Upvotes, 27 bookmarks, 5 answers each of which is very voted. A lot of enthusiasm and so on.

But if the question would be opened today probably it would become closed. Since maybe it's more suitable for the Programmer site.

Doesn't matter if I'm wrong with this specific example, don't focus on the detail, don't be nitpicking / quibbling. The important stuff is that a long time ago SO was full of enthusiastic people who wanted to share the knowledge.

We can read this also on the guidelines. The main purpose of this website is to spread the knowledge. It's written on a 2 years old article of the blog. A milestone.

Have a look at it: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

The point is all in this two words: quibbling and main purpose = spreading the knowledge. Today the objective of SE is to allow only high quality questions. To stay in topic. To follow the rules. And this is achieved with a strong fight against wind mill..

Many effort to create some questions which could really attract interest is considere OT.

And now, for fun, the movies to see to understand which kind of world suits the model SE has taken: Matrix, Equilibrium, V for Revenge, Divergent. A world where someone which is better than you can tell you what you are allowed to write or not. Think on my joke and try to be more flexible. Life means different opinion, and not: who doesn't think like me should leave this community. This, in real life, would sound really really bad.

Answer (score -17):

To be completely honest:  I hesitated to even participate in answering this 'question' because of the omnipresent threat of downvoting (core of the problem IMO). I'm sure I'll get downvoted for SOMETHING in this response, but whatever I'm just trying to help - shame on me. Often times people don't even know how to ask their question or which keywords to Google! This leads to bone head questions, but it can lead to useful answers to obscure questions. These poorly asked questions are then crawled by Google and other people typing in the same poorly worded question will search, find, and learn... somewhat reminiscent of how I first learned of Stack Overflow.

Side note, I completely agree that "heres my code dump fix it plz" is lazy :\

Comment: Why are you afraid of downvotes?  Since MSO is a real meta, downvotes don't count negatively towards your reputation.  That said, I'm not entirely sure your answer addresses the points raised.  It kind of seems like you're agreeing with the question as stated, in a more terse fashion.

Comment: This is the internet. If you write "I'll probably get downvoted for this" then you will. It's a magical incantation, like a Bat-Signal that summons sadists.

Comment: @Charlesism Nevertheless this magical incantation doesn't make much sense, does it. Maybe the site should automatically insert an "Probably I will get downvoted" at the beginning of each question and answer here. This answer here makes the case for a higher degree of tolerance on this site and thereby answers the original question. So why was it downvoted?

Comment: @Trilarion Downvotes on meta are different; they mean "I don't agree with this". They are not a commentary on the quality of the answer.

Comment: @BrianRoach Thanks for the explanation. I understand it now although the tooltip of the voting buttons still say useful/not useful.

Comment: @Trilarion Yeah, I may not be right; according to the FAQ that's only the case for "feature-request" tagged questions. I'm new to the meta thing and I had read others saying that without looking it up myself (shows you what I get for that). I'm not sure now.

Comment: @Makoto I think he's pointing out that there's people out there who downvote and upvote in order to game the system and get themselves and their friends more reputation over others. Create 2 accounts, upvote each other constantly, downvote other things. Each upvote gets the other account 10 point, which is enough to downvote several things and still get positive rep. Seen that a lot on other sites, I'm sure it happens here as well.

Comment: I just wanted to find the most downvoted question :P