# Is this (active date) a bug?

Tags: discussion, bug

I read *[How should we handle the current void of content at Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251628/how-should-we-handle-the-current-void-of-content-at-meta-stack-overflow?rq=1)*.

I can see `"active : 4 years, 1 month ago"` left side bar.

I can see `"edited Mar 20 '17 at 10:32"` just after the question.

If it was edited last year, why does it show it was active 4 years before?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That edit is a bulk edit by Community changing http to https. It's not considered activity, as it's not *user activity*. That's good, because else we would've bumped thousands of questions simultaneously when this rolled out.

Such bulk edits are rare (I know of 3 so far, but there have probably been more), but they're not supposed to trigger *activity* (they don't adjust the date, bump to front page, or make questions eligible for a review queue).

Comment: Thanks _I know of 3 so far_ One is this http to https. What are others?

Comment: Changing cpearson.com to an archived version (while it was unavailable), and rolling that back when the site became available again (a rare situation, since it was a really common resource, the author passed, and there was uncertainty if the site would ever be available again). A fourth might be [removal of the internet tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287423/7296893), but I wasn't around back then, so I don't know exactly how Shog did that.

Comment: What about [tag burninations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Usually, these are handled by the community, and tags are removed one at a time (after evaluating the question and concluding it shouldn't be deleted altogether), and not using a bulk edit. I know the internet burnination was an exception, and while there might've been others that were executed using bulk edits, I don't know of any.