# Should downvotes be used to punish people who answer bad questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, downvotes

In response to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819565/combine-2d-array-of-x-and-y-coordinate-and-corresponding-values?noredirect=1#comment36645764_23819565

The asker comes in with no code, unformatted and no real data structure, admits in the comments that they haven't really tried anything and still get 3 answers - which get upvotes.

At the moment downvotes cost 1 rep to partially prevent you downvoting other answers to boost your own.

However, we are now getting so many shitty questions that get equally shitty answers.

**Answering bad questions encourages people to write bad questions.**

We can't stop 1 rep user849032 newbies from showing up asking a poor question and disappearing once given a response, but we can discourage people from answering those low effort questions. Answerers are more likely to care about rep.

[As this question states - "Answers (even correct ones) are not useful if they contribute to the demise of the site."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252656/punish-answerers-of-bad-questions?rq=1)

Can we make it so that downvotes for answers cost 0 rep, *unless you have also answered it*? The StackOverflow platform seems to have some smarts behind it, so surely it could tell when you downvote, then answer.

**I'd love to downvote more bad answers, but I admittedly like my rep.**

edit:

Qantas 94 Heavy linked to these questions:

[Why does downvoting an answer cost reputation while questions not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not)

> Downvotes are an integral part of the automated system that evaluates question quality and blocks user accounts that can't formulate coherent questions.
>
> People weren't downvoting questions because it was costing them reputation...
>
> Answers are different. When I'm posting an answer to a question, I am competing with other answerers for the precious repz, so there should be a cost for me to downvote their answers.

**I understand why it *was* the case that answering is different, but now there are many, many more answerers, and the code should be able to deal with me downvoting an answer to a question I haven't answered.**

## In summary:

- Proposal: **remove -1 cost of downvotes**
- which: **lowers psychological cost of downvoting**
- which: **increases downvotes**
- which: **increases penalty for answering poor questions**
- which: **reduces likelihood of people answering poor questions**
- which: **reduces answer rate for poor questions**
- which: **reduces likelihood of poor questions being rewarded with an answer**
- which: **reduces number of poor questions being asked**

Therefore: Removing the -1 cost of downvotes is likely to reduce the number of poor questions being asked, which will improve the quality of the site overall.

[Keep in mind that there is a precedent for removing rep costs to change behaviour, as once upon a time downvotes on questions cost rep too.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)

Comment: Related: [Should I downvote attempted answers to bad (too broad) questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252003),  [Punish answerers of bad questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252656), [Why does downvoting an answer cost reputation while questions not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251610), and [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)