# Downvoting reputation cascade

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

Let me start by adding some context to my question. If the context doesn't interest you, scroll down to the bolded sentences.

I am by most standards a junior systems-administrator. I spend more time learning, and verifying my actions than I do actually executing tasks.
As such Stack Overflow, and in actuality more [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) are a great lurking ground for me.

As it stands I tend to spend more time downvoting / upvoting and commenting than I do answering. Mostly I'm trying to improve the quality of questions and the way people use Stack Overflow, because I'm interested in the answers. And the better the questions the better the answers they tend to attract.

My issue is that I often spend time downvoting questions/answers. Such as:

- Questions with easily research-able answers
- Questions that are badly worded and show a lack of comprehension of the overall situation
- Answers that are snippets of previous answers
- Answers that are plain wrong

*Let's face it, if I know the answer off the top of my head, and you're asking it in a badly worded, badly formatted way, you probably deserve a down-vote.*

And this invariably leads to me losing some reputation.
Not really a big deal, however it sends a weird signal.
The way I see it, I'm mostly trying to improve the quality of the site, while leeching a lot of knowledge from people who have more experience than me.

However the response from the system is that I should lose my precious Internet points for this (*I know, not really that important, but let me explain*).

For the people with a high reputation cap this doesn't really matter. However I am clearly in the low reputation bracket. And the difference between seeing review queues or not might just be in a few downvotes.

**As such I would like to propose a change in the reputation calculation for downvoting.**

1. **Whenever you downvote an answer, you lose one reputation**.
   This doesn't change.
2. **Whenever you downvote a question, you also lose one reputation**.
   Honestly the reasons for downvoting are most often the same so why make the distinction.
3. **Whenever a question/answer you downvoted gets upvoted, you lose one reputation**.
   The question/answer being upvoted might indicate it has since been improved, or that other people agree more with the OP than with you, and you might be wrong.
4. **Whenever a question/answer you downvoted gets downvoted, you gain 0,50x the amount of downvotes after your vote, in reputation, rounded down**.
   The more people agree with you, the less likely it is that you downvoted the question/answer incorrectly.
5. **Negative reputation change from votes on the voters is capped at 5 per question**

*These reputation calculations would only be considered upon the time of casting the vote.* That way people who downvote already downvoted questions have a lower chance of receiving reputation benefit (to discourage gaming the system).

This way, downvoting bad questions/answers might benefit you. Downvoting good questions/answers will have a larger impact on your reputation.
And downvoting divisive questions/answers will never cost you more than 5 reputation. And we have the added bonus that maybe people who downvoted a question that later on was edited and updated to the point that it has now become a proper question, get notified (unobtrusively).

Comment: So I should lose 5 rep instead of 1 for downvoting a popular but incorrect answer?  No thanks...

Comment: @l4mpi Yes, I believe if a question has been up-voted quite a bit the odds of it being incorrect are much lower. So indicating that it could be should be more costly.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers odds don't matter, there _are_ wrong but heavily upvoted answers. Maybe worse, there are accepted php answers with obvious sql injections that have hundreds of votes. Now I should lose more rep for downvoting those because other people are idiots? Again, no thanks. Oh, and losing rep for downvoting a lazy, no-effort question from a help vampire which gets upvoted by "helpful" users who don't care that the question is absolute crap? I consider your proposed feature offensive.

Comment: @l4mpi Why wouldn't the odds matter? Designing a system with the exceptions in mind is only really important if the exceptions are more important than the general usage. In this case if the answers are truly false, and upvoted, the proper course would be either removing them, or making sure the comments indicating that they are wrong are upvoted. At any rate, if it has been upvoted numerous times, and then you downvote it, comment that it's wrong. It should decrease the amount of upvotes. And you are less likely to loose points.

Comment: The odds don't matter because you're proposing to handle every case in the same way and thus make it way worse to actually do something about special cases like heavily upvoted, incorrect answers. Who would downvote an answer like this when it's guaranteed to lose them 5 rep? And no, mods won't delete them; read the discussion I linked and the multiple dupes. In many cases, there are already comments indicating that it's bad code, but if you spend a bit more time on SO you'll find out people don't care in the slightest about that, as long as they can copy-paste something that runs.

Comment: And you don't even start to address my second point: _all of this is way worse for questions_. Horrible, no-effort questions are regularily upvoted by people for various random reasons like "being nice" or "there are no stupid questions" (which btw is a totally stupid thing to say). If you propose I should lose rep for this I'd not even have the 5 rep required to participate on meta.

Comment: You would be effectively cementing the herd mentality and stifling all dissent. There are plenty of highly upvoted answers that deserve downvotes or are even flat out wrong. If you penalize people for disagreeing we'll never be able to correct these sorts of problems.

Comment: @l4mpi What do you mean guaranteed? You only stand to loose points if people up-vote it after your vote has been cast. By that time if everything works well there should be comments indicating it is wrong. 5 rep for every fringe case vs gaining rep for the general usage will still very likely end up in a net positive. I also disagree that 4 reputation more is "way worse". However I agree, I don't have an answer to your second point... People up-voting for random reasons is a problem.

Comment: @eddie_cat You're already penalized for disagreeing, you loose one rep. What I'm proposing here is limiting the amount you're penalized for down-voting a question that others are also down-voting, and increasing the penalty for down-voting something other people are up-voting.

Comment: One rep is trivial and exists for a good reason, namely so that people are less likely to downvote all other answers on questions they answer just to make themselves look better. Your rationale for this is that people shouldn't disagree with each other. People upvote bad content all the time, just look at some of the trivial obvious duplicates posted in the more popular tags every day that get upvoted by all the newbies who are happy to see a question they can answer regardless of its quality. I should be penalized for disagreeing with those people? I don't think so.

Comment: "if everything works well there should be comments indicating it is wrong" - as I said, _people do not care about that_. Too many users do not care that the PHP code in an answer has a mysql injection and allows everybody to hijack their server, because they can copypaste it and it solves their immediate problem. There are many discussions here and on meta.SE about highly upvoted, incorrect answers, all of which have comments indicating why they're bad, and many of which are still gaining upvotes.

Comment: Proposals like this, dramatically overhauling the way things have been done for *years*, always start at -100 points.  It is your job to find at least +101.  A crucial part of it is weighing what your proposal will do to the reason the rule is there in the first place.  Hemmed-and-hawed over a great deal in the early days of the site.  You did not do that.  It is not our job to come up with reasons to shoot down the proposal, it is your job to show +101.  And right now, a convoluted new rule just to avoid the loss of *one* rep point gets you to -99 at best.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Whenever a question/answer you down-voted gets up-voted, you loose one reputation.

This is pure nonsense. **Voting is a moderation tool!** The community as a whole decides whether something is useful or not. And there is room for disagreement.

Your proposal means that if *one* user upvotes, every user downvoting looses reputation. This just doesn't make sense and would harm voting on the site. (People could retract their legit downvote if one 'friend' voter upvotes, in order too keep their reputation).

> Reputation change from votes is capped at 5 per question

This doesn't only harm bad questions. It harms good questions too. So you propose only the first upvote matters. Why? The reputation cap (+200) is enough.

> Whenever you down-vote a question, you also lose one reputation.
>   Honestly the reasons for down-voting are most often the same so why make the distinction.

Well, there was a time downvoting a question costed reputation too. This was [removed to encourage moderating](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251610/839601) though voting on questions (users were hesitating to downvote for the loss of reputation).

Comment: My this answer is hard to follow with all the updates. I completely agree on the second point. The reputation change for those asking / answering should not be affected. I reworded that part to better reflect that. However I believe if people retract their votes based on reputation gain, perhaps the votes shouldn't have been cast in the first place? (Which affects my whole argument poorly as well, but regardless I prefer larger affects from voting over only negative affects on the voter)

Comment: As for your first point, if you down-vote, you pay in reputation to indicate that you disagree. However if another person agrees, you're disagreeing with two people, shouldn't this be reflected somehow? Currently the system seems like a lot of singular voices each affecting one person but not each other. Disagreement is fine, and there should be room for that, but disagreement without proper discourse usually doesn't achieve much.

Comment: @Reaces: What matters, and in fact the **only thing that matters** is your perception of the quality of the answer, regardless of what you think of the poster, regardless of what others think of the answer. Should citizens be penalized in a presidential election because they vote against the majority? No, of course not, and the same holds here. Your suggestion would bastardize this process with no benefit to this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I very much dislike the comparison to an election. There are no candidates here, and the scale is much smaller. The goal is to educate and help, while in an election there is a significant impact on your life and a much larger scope. Also elections tend to have enforced changes follow them, the votes on a question won't change your code or your behavior if you don't want them to. I also think "bastardize this process with no benefit to this site" is very harsh wording for something quite small.

Comment: @Reaces: the goal is the same though: to get the community's opinion on something. Your suggestion puts a skewing force on this vote that is not good and reinforces a herd mentality, something is definitely not needed. If you believe your suggestion is good, then should the converse also be true? Should we penalize up-voters if the majority down-vote the question? Extrapolation of your reasoning suggests that we should.

Comment: @Reaces: Regardless, our discussion on this subject is moot. You have every right to bring your suggestion to this community, but it is being voted down by the meta community and will thus will not be implemented.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I actually think the discussion is a large part of what makes a suggestion have a positive impact. Again: educating the person asking the question. I also agree that it shouldn't be implemented, after reading the comments and answer (as I accepted the answer above ;)) But I still think reasoning as to why should be discussed. For example, up-votes are currently neither beneficial nor detrimental for the person voting, so I don't see how my suggestion about adding a skewed scale relates. I'm not talking about adding penalty, I'm talking about adding a scale.