# Why do you lose reputation for down voting an answer on your own post?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I see that you lose a reputation point for downvoting an answer on a post. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not) explains why. It makes sense to me. It also looks like the most popular post on this topic.

The accepted answer on this post says the following:

> Answers are different. When I'm posting an answer to a question, I am
>   competing with other answerers for the precious repz, so there should
>   be a cost for me to downvote their answers.

What I am trying to understand is, why do I lose reputation points for down voting an answer on my own post. In this case I am not competing with others for reputation. Can someone explain to me rationale behind doing this?

Comment: If your question attracted an unhelpful answer, then that's perhaps attributable to your question. So why should the downvote be free? Why should you be put in advantage over bystanders when evaluating answer usefulness?

Comment: How can you attribute a bad answer to the quality of a question. If the question is bad then it will anyways get downvoted.

Comment: @Twister if you get an answer you downvote because it's not answering your exact problem, it could be because your problem statement was unclear? (this is just one example).

Comment: @Patrice there already is a builtin feature to handle unclear questions or questions of low quality. Your question  either gets downvoted (in which case you have to forfeit rep points) or folks use comments to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Patrice All i am saying is this does not sufficiently explain why this is being done

Comment: It's being done for the same reason all downvotes on answers cost rep. There is no specific reason why it isn't different for answers on your own question because no differentiation between the two scenarios have been made before. If you think they SHOULD be different, you should start a discussion on THAT topic in the form of a feature request.

Comment: I think it's kinda bad form to downvote people who answered your question.  Unless they're idiots.  I prefer to leave comments as to why their answers were unsatisfactory.  The wolves will smell the blood and come running.

Comment: @Will you aren't downvoting *"people"*, you're downvoting content. (or, if you are downvoting (or upvoting) people, you're using your votes incorrectly)

Comment: @Will I respectfully disagree :)

Comment: @KevinB well, no sheet.  Thanks for correcting me!  Because I don't know how this place works.  Like it being my choice not to downvote an answer even if it isn't correct.  Or like how leaving a comment telling people why their answer is incorrect is perfectly fine.  Or how I can downvote an answer to my questions, even though I think (personally, not site-rules) that's bad form, because the answer is so terrible it needs to go away.  So, thank you for allowing me to pour a bucket of sarcasm in this comment.  Have a drink on me tonight :)

Comment: @Will For some reason (please correct me if I am wrong) you think downvoting an answer on your own post , is being rude. Its not. Well some answers are just plain incorrect , or are too vague. Downvotes on such answers indicated that the answer just does not meet minimum standards and  directs other individuals who read your post to ignore them.

Comment: _"In this case I am not competing with others for reputation"_ You might be.

Comment: @Twister downvotes should go along with a comment as to why you didn't think that answer was helpful. If I answer a question and I get downvoted without explanation, I'm not going to waste my time trying to figure out why, and how I can improve my answer. If I knew it was the OP who was downvoting that answer without comment, I'm definitely not going to take the time to try and solve their problem, because they didn't take the time to work with me. If the OP comments on my answer and says "I'm actually looking for something like this, can we do it?" I will work with them.

Comment: I must admit losing rep for downvoting on your own question does seem a bit odd, especially since you are the asker, you should be able to downvote answers that are unhelpful without a penalty. As you say, there is a perfectly valid reason to allow on any other question but your own does seem a bit odd

Comment: So according to you downvotes should be free on all answers as long as you haven't (and don't) post a competing one to the same question?

Comment: @Sammaye: Just like the OP, you have failed to provide any indication as to _why_ it's "odd" just because the potential downvoter happens to have written the original question. What's so special about their downvoting ability, in that case?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what I would consider special is that they asked the question, as such losing rep on down voting an answer is like us saying to them "because this answer does not fulfil your question we are punishing you"

Comment: @Sammaye: You're still not explaining why it's special that "they asked the question", just repeating it over and over as an assertion. The OP is literally not being "punished" any more than they would be if they downvoted an answer on someone else's question. So what makes you think there is any connection to their own question here? There may be a wider debate here on why one should lose rep _at all_ when downvoting, but I don't see that there's anything special about it when the answer is on your own question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit think of it this way: if you came over to me and asked for help on a problem and I gave an answer that didn't help and when you went to say it wasn't unhelpful you instead got told off for saying it didn't help you wouldn't feel too pleased would you? You might instead proclaim that you understand the problem and that I did not. If you down vote an answer on someone else's question then it is a completely different mentality. It is the case of specifically down voting on your own questions. That is the difference here: ownership.

Comment: @Sammaye: It sounds like you are voting for different reasons on your own questions than you do on other people's (and that this the root of your expectation). You shouldn't!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, you are voting for the same reason, correctness in relation to the question at hand. It is merely the context in which the vote takes place

Comment: Sorry still not seeing why there should be a special rule just because you wrote the question.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Simply put, you lose reputation for [downvoting any answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down); it doesn't matter where that answer is.

You may not be competing with anyone else when downvoting, but you are objectively evaluating the quality of the answer at that point.  If you feel strongly enough that the answer isn't useful, isn't correct, or just isn't good, then the idea is that you're willing to spend 1 reputation to demonstrate it.  Again, it doesn't matter where the answer came from.

Comment: Should the forum not differentiate between a post owner downvoting an answer and a regular user downvoting an answer ?

Comment: @Twister why should it?

Comment: @Patrice For the very same reason you give the authority to the post owner to mark an answer accepted. The post owner is in a better position to access the quality of the answer  i.e say if the answer helped him resolve the issue or understand a concept better.

Comment: @Twister:  that's what accepting an answer does. If an answer does help them out the best, the OP has the option to accept that answer.  This, of course, doesn't mean that the community won't disagree with the answer (which it has done in the past).  Ironically, accepting one answer gives you enough reputation to downvote *two* answers.

Comment: @Twister The owner of the question is not in a better position to assess the **quality** of an answer than anyone else who visits the question. The owner of the question instead is in the best position to decide whether or not it solves their problem.

Comment: @Twister I was about to reply, but I think Makoto and Kevin B have the gist of what I was about to answer. There is no reason why it would be different.

Comment: @Makoto Yup,  there are posts out there which have answers with comparatively low upvotes.

Comment: @Twister:  Yes, [there's even a badge for those scenarios](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist).

Comment: That badge is very elusive. every time i think i'm getting close to it the accepted answer gets 1 more upvote!

Comment: I would replace word "spend" with "invest"

Comment: Why doesn't this same logic apply to upvotes?

Answer (score 9):

Supposing, for the sake of answering your question as posed, that the quoted reason:

> I am competing with other answerers for the precious repz, so there
>   should be a cost for me to downvote

is indeed the reason.

Then there is no difference between your own questions and other questions because **you can answer your own questions**. So you *are* competing for the precious repz.

Now, you might say, "but I'm not planning to answer my own questions. So I'm not competing. Stick that in your pipe and smoke it". This is fair, but it still doesn't create a difference between your questions and other people's questions, since there are many questions that you did not ask, that you might like to downvote answers on, but have no intention of answering yourself. It only points to the need to slightly reword the quoted reason. It's not that you *are* competing with all the answers you downvote, it's that you might be competing already and even if not you could compete in future.

This still doesn't really justify the quoted reason. After all, the system could charge you a point for a downvote only if you've answered the question already, or when you answer a question for the first time it could immediately charge you one point per downvote you've previously made. This would satisfy the quoted reason (charging you for downvoting your competitors), *without* charging you in the case where you are not competing and therefore the reason for the charge does not apply. Because that's possible but isn't how it works, I don't believe that the quoted reason is all there is to it. But that doubt still doesn't lead to the conclusion that you should not be charged for downvoting answers to your own questions. It leads to the conclusion that you should not be charged for downvoting answers to questions you don't answer, irrespective of whether you asked them or not.

Comment: +1 for the "Stick that in your pipe and smoke it"

Comment: But you DO NOT get rep for answering your own questions, so that entire argument is invalid, only up votes count, not accepts when answering your own questions

Comment: @Sammaye: And you aren't vieing for upvotes from the same people in the same question?

Comment: @Deduplicator yeah but that's not up to you, there's no route for abuse that isn't visible to the bot

Comment: @Deduplicator Basically should someone be punished for putting a genuinely awesome answer to their own question that attracts up votes? Such an action should go unnoticed on this site imo it is part of the site

Comment: @Sammaye: Sorry, how are they punished? They just don't get any extra advantage (free rep and a place in the spot-light by self-acceptance). And they aren't getting any waiver to rep-investment for downvoting annulled.

Comment: @Deduplicator they are not directly punished but if you use the logic that they are punished for downvoting other answers then it does seem as though they are punished for placing that awesome answer. I guess it just seems from the other answers that is all about handicapping the user to make abuse harder but it seems there isn't rally anymore room than there is atm

Answer (score 3):

Your argument seems to be that the only reason for downvotes costing rep is to stop people from abusing it to win at rep.  So it's not needed in a case where it wouldn't help you win at rep.  However, **making the game of winning at rep "fair" is not the primary goal of many of the site's rules.**

Having your answer down-voted doesn't feel good, if you did actually put effort into it and try to be helpful.  Getting downvoted feels a lot worse than simply not getting upvoted.  This will turn some people away that could have contributed useful answers to other questions.

Giving the asker free downvotes on answers to their question would to some degree encourage them to take advantage of the ability.  Answers would be downvoted that wouldn't have been if the cost had still been there.  But the important point is that these downvotes are unlikely to make the site better, compared to leaving a comment on an answer that's not bad enough to want to lose 1 rep downvoting.

Since there's only one asker per question, this is only at most a -1 difference.  So again, unlikely to make the site better.

Comment: _"making the game of winning at rep "fair" is not the primary goal of many of the site's rules"_ -- IMHO, this is really the most useful part of this answer, and should be the lead. That some people might not "feel good" having their answer down-voted is (should be) irrelevant; this has nothing to do with why it costs a point to down-vote an answer.

Comment: Actually, I think the "feels good" factor is important.  Even infrequently being told that someone thought the time you spent on writing an answer actually made the site worse would turn some people off from using the site.  The community would be poorer as a result (if the answers weren't actually bad, but just someone didn't like them, and was able to downvote them without any rep cost.)  I agree with your point, though, and moved up the "winning at rep" paragraph.

Comment: The problem is abuse exists now, I mean -1 rep is almost free for me I could easily abuse it, anyone with more than 100 rep could easily abuse downvoting. What stops the abuse is not the cost but bots that trawl the site looking for voting irregularlities

Answer (score -2):

Most people seem to be confused here.

**YOU DO NOT GET REP FROM ACCEPTING YOUR OWN ANSWER ONLY FROM UP VOTES FROM OTHERS**

In fact I am not sure if you even get the +2 rep for accepting an answer, cannot quite remember.

As such the whole case about competing for rep blah-de-blah is invalid. If you answer you own question you do so without any rep gain, as a person who has answered many of my own questions I know.

I actually agree, as the asker you know which answers help and which do not so why should you get punished for stating that an answer is unhelpful by downvoting it?

I know "punished" is a harsh word but many do see any rep loss as exactly that: being punished. With this in mind you are punishing an asker in their own question because they decided that an answerer did not help them and provided an unhelpful answer.

Not only that but if you genuinely provide an unhelpful answer you will most likely suffer much worse at the hands of the rest of the community as they pass their downvotes so I do not see this making people leave anymore than our current rules.

So I am actually with you on this one, I would see this change come to pass, especially for newbies asking questions.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this implies you aren't competing for rep. You still get rep from upvotes, and if your +0 answer is up there next to a -1 answer, you're probably going to get more upvotes due to people piling on and following the initial downvote with more.

Comment: Considering *how* many new users upvote, I'm not convinced removing the rep-investment of answer-downvotes for the asker is actually such a good idea. Or at least, not a better idea than for anyone else.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I personally don't see that. I have had other answerers on questions I answered do the same and were sent to school by the community

Comment: @ChrisHayes remember I can downvote your answer if I wanna sabotage you for my own answer and say there was a problem with your answer and the mods couldn't do anything

Comment: @Deduplicator maybe, personally I see it as not causing any damage considering the current rules and the ease of seeing vote fraud. It might ease the asker to not be punished cos that's the problem, you are punishing the asker for them thinking an answer doesn't help them

Comment: I can only even potentially see any sort of reasoning behind removing the rep loss in the case that the asker does not lose rep if they haven't posted their own answer to the question. At the same time, if they later post an answer to the question, the loss of rep would need to retroactively kick in and cause the asker to lose a point per downvote, to prevent them downvoting an answer they posting the same thing reworded without punishment. But even then, I really can't see why it would even be remotely worth it to go to all this trouble to make another special case for the OP.

Comment: @Kendra it could be seen as too much effort, a feature for when no others exist, I'll give you that