# Why "vote down an answer" if penalized for doing so?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, voting

According to the "Reputation & Moderation" portion of the "Help Center",

> You lose reputation when:
>
> your question is voted down: −2
> your answer is voted down: −2
> you vote down an answer: −1
> you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

Why might anyone choose to "vote down an answer" if they are penalized? The act seems almost counter intuitive. Is there any benefit to the user in doing so?

My question is unique for I am not comparing this action that causes this penalty to a similar action or situation, such as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not). I am particulary interested in why a user would perform an action that could lead to this penalty.

Comment: No, there is no direct benefit for the user, but 1. the penalty will hurt less and less as you gain reputation and 2. many people develop a sense of protectiveness of their community and will feel compelled to downvote stuff that is bad.

Comment: Also, there's the issue of tactical downvoting: downvoting the answers of others when you answer a question, to make your answer rise to the top. The fact that downvotes cost reputation makes this behavior less beneficial.

Comment: There's a benefit for the community, isn't that good enough?

Comment: Yes I'd say that is a key point, a motive for the user, @ivarni. I am particulary intrested in the effect on the user.

Comment: Possibly though I would consider that question to be in the style of a comparison, @honk.

Comment: after  few times you will understand that this website is not a competition website when the winner is the one who has high REP .. it's a community website where we should act by upvoting and downvoting to keep good ressources... so no matter if you loose your rep, all what matter is that you do correct downvoting and upvoting

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in those cases where down votes cause the post to be deleted (either by the OP or by the system) the *penalty* is undone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Once you have 35K rep (at which you get the maximum number of delete votes), there's nothing else much to do with your rep so downvoting really costs nothing after that.
- You can't [vote to delete an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) unless it is negatively scored. There's a delete queue so putting answers in that by voting to delete often means they get deleted providing other 20K users agree with you.
- If the answer is deleted you get the rep back. Non-answers such as "I have this problem too" are almost always deleted so the rep loss there is temporary.

Comment: +1, especially for (3). For non-answers I often just flag as "not an answer".