# Downvoting Articles should not cost reputation

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, collectives, articles

Downvoting Articles in Collectives costs 1 reputation point, similarly like downvoting regular answers.

According to [Why does downvoting an answer cost reputation while questions not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not) downvoting answers costs reputation to prevent voting abuse from other answerers.

Since Articles (for now) don't have competing answers, we should be able to judge their quality without paying the price in reputation.

Comment: I guess the implementation is: `if (Post.PostTypeId != PostTypes.Question) { User.Reputation = User.Reputation - 1; }`

Comment: Meh, IMO they should remove reputation from them _entirely_. With a limited number of people that can post them and high traffic to the feature right now, essentially every article is a bountied post, there's no reason for someone not to post a dozen FAQs. They're also at reduced risk of being downvoted simply because we currently have to explain ourselves.

Comment: @Nick Removing reputation for them in their current form, yes. Remove voting, no.  Also, you can click skip when asked for the feedback and your vote will be applied.

Answer (score 64):

Yes, but let's go one step further:

**Articles should have no influence on reputation at all.**

The failed SO documentation project had a lot of issues, and quite a few of those were due to the fact that you could earn rep for writing documentation. That was a bad incentive for docs, and seems to be a bad incentive for articles as well. Keep the voting, that part's useful (or at least not harmful), just don't attach reputation to article votes.

For the moment only recognized users can post articles, but the plan for Collectives is that admins review articles submitted by normal members. Once the submission process is opened to regular users, these admins will have enough work to do with spotting plagiarized articles (e.g. using content copypasted from official docs or random blog posts, or even from other articles) as well as filtering out low-quality content *without* there being a reputation incentive for writing an article.

If I'm completely wrong about this and nobody (including recognized users) can be bothered to write an article if they don't get imaginary internet points for doing so, well, you can still add it back in. But it would seem like the best idea to start without a rep incentive and only add it if it turns out that it's required.

Comment: "If I'm completely wrong about this and nobody (including recognized users) can be bothered to write an article if they don't get imaginary internet points for doing so, well, you can still add it back in" - ha ha :) Boy that'll give some quality articles if it is driven by imaginary internet points ;) No that would pretty much declare the idea a failure. Fully agree this should be detached from reputation.

Comment: Rep was not really one of the problems for Documentation. They just didn't test it out, didn't seek feedback before launch or implement feedback after launch, and didn't commit resources to it.

Comment: @TylerH a lot of spam posts and edits (which IIRC gave the editor rep from any future upvotes to a docs post) were certainly a big problem of documentation. Of course there might be other reasons for those, but I'm sure rep was a big factor. People _copied already existing SO documentation articles word for word_, I can't really think of any other motivation for this than to gain reputation.

Comment: @l4mpi I mean, to get the documentation out from behind a horrible, ever-changing UI and URL scheme *might* have been a motivation other than rep gain (*ahem*MS Docs*ahem*) ;-)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm not talking about copying existing _vendor_ documentation to SO.docs (which also happened, and was also bad in most cases), I'm talking about copying an SO.docs post written by somebody else to create a new SO.docs post.